# Automatic left and right commands

Tags: math-mode, brackets

Is it possible to automatically "add" `\left` and `\right` commands in front of all brackets? The source code should be left intact, but LaTeX should interpret every pair of brackets as if they were preceded by such commands. This is because adding `\left` and `\right` commands is time consuming and makes source code longer and less readable. I considered defining new commands such as `\lb` and `\rb` for `\left(` and `\right)`, but it doesn't seem very elegant to me: what if I also want to add square brackets for example?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I strongly advise against automatically replacing `(` and `)` with `\left(` and `right)` since it can cause spacing problems. For details see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58641).

Comment: Somewhat related question: [math mode - automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 44):

The `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) is useful. For example defining an absolute value macro;

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

gives also a starred version with `\left` and `\right`

```
\abs*{\frac{a}{b}}
```

and the unstarred version takes an optional argument that can be `\big`, `\Big`, etc

```
\abs[\Bigg]{\frac{a}{b}}
```

Comment: I'd like to congratulate you for understanding what the user wants!!! This "automatic" left/right discussion survives like *forever*, because when the user says s/he wants automatic left/right, what s/he actually means is that the user should not be supposed to choose sizes manually, or decide when to use or not "left/right" based on its broken implementation "side effects". TeX people keep answering the "written question", without considering what the OP really wants. They keep saying "don't do it", without taking into consideration the user needs... :-(

Answer (score 26):

Adding `\left` and `\right` to all delimiters is difficult and likely not to yield the desired result in many places.

The [`nath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nath) package aims at making `\left` and `\right` obsolete. From the readme:

> delimiters adapt their size to the material enclosed, rendering `\left` and `\right` almost obsolete.

Comment: nath has to many incompatibilities, [Incompatibilities with and alternatives to nath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104532/incompatibilities-with-and-alternatives-to-nath)

Comment: And `nath` seems obsolete (no newer project announcement than in 2003).

Answer (score 22):

**Edit:** *I'm leaving this answer up for “academic purposes” but, consider [Lev Bishop's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands/1765#1765) answer for an easier solution than mine.*

---

Over the years I've evolved my own solution which I think turned out quite nice. It gives you a command which you can call like

```
\newdelimcommand{parens}{(}{)}
```

which in turn will define for you a `\parens` command which you can then use as `\parens{thing}` to produce something like `(thing)` where, moreover, the parenthesis automatically resize. In fact you can use the command in three different ways

```
\parens{thing}       % automatic resize
\parens*{thing}      % no resize
\parens[big]{thing}  % use the specified size
```

For the latter option you can use `auto` (the default), `base` (no resize), or one of the sizes: `big`, `Big`, `bigg`, `Bigg`.

Furthermore, inside of `thing` you can use the commands `\ldelim`, `\rdelim`, and `\mdelim` to create even more delimiters with the appropriate size selected by the given options. This allows, for example, to use `\mdelim` to automagically resize a “middle” bar. (See example at the end of the code).

For this to work you have to drop the following code in a .sty file and include it in your main .tex file with `\usepackage`.

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

% delim sizing options
\let\delim@autol\left  \let\delim@autor\right \let\delim@autom\middle
\let\delim@basel\relax \let\delim@baser\relax \let\delim@basem\relax
\let\delim@bigl\bigl   \let\delim@bigr\bigr   \let\delim@bigm\big
\let\delim@Bigl\Bigl   \let\delim@Bigr\Bigr   \let\delim@Bigm\Big
\let\delim@biggl\biggl \let\delim@biggr\biggr \let\delim@biggm\bigg
\let\delim@Biggl\Biggl \let\delim@Biggr\Biggr \let\delim@Biggm\Bigg

% default definitions
\newcommand\ldelim{\relax}
\newcommand\rdelim{\relax}
\newcommand\mdelim{\relax}

% the actual command
\newcommand\delim@command[4]{{%   #1 size #2 ldelim #3 rdelim #4 content
  \def\ldelim{\csname delim@#1l\endcsname}%
  \def\rdelim{\csname delim@#1r\endcsname}%
  \def\mdelim{\csname delim@#1m\endcsname}%
  \ldelim#2#4\rdelim#3}}

% a factory to define new delimiter commands
\newcommand{\newdelimcommand}[3]{% #1 name #2 ldelim #3 rdelim
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname delim@#1@st\endcsname[1]{% ##1 content
    \delim@command{base}{#2}{#3}{##1}}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname delim@#1@ns\endcsname[2][auto]{%
    % ##1 size ##2 content
    \delim@command{##1}{#2}{#3}{##2}}%
  \expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \@ifstar{\csname delim@#1@st\endcsname}{\csname delim@#1@ns\endcsname}%
  }%
}

% syntactically named delimiters
\newdelimcommand{braces}{\lbrace}{\rbrace}
\newdelimcommand{angles}{\langle}{\rangle}
\newdelimcommand{verts}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newdelimcommand{Verts}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newdelimcommand{brackets}{[}{]}

% semantically named delimiters
\newcommand{\set}{\braces}
\newcommand{\abs}{\verts}
\newcommand{\size}{\verts}
\newcommand{\norm}{\Verts}
\newcommand{\tuple}{\angles}

% Automagic `such that' for set comprehension. Inside an automagic
% delimiter command, the vertical bar will resize appropriately
% Example:
%   \set{ x \in W \st x > 0 }
\newcommand{\st}{\;\mdelim\vert\;}
```

I've been thinking to eventually release this (and other bits of code) as a proper style file. But for the time being here it is for you to copy&paste. :)

Comment: This looks very much like `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools), except that the meaning of starred and unstarred is reversed.

Comment: Reading [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91482/how-to-avoid-this-undesired-horizontal-space) I wondered if it was possible to make use of `\mleft` and `\mright` in this code. I prefer this over `mathtools` because *the meaning of starred and unstarred is reversed* and because the manual input is easier (`[bigg]` vs. `[\bigg]`). Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you could just drop `\mleft` instead of `\left`, etc. But probably you want it to sometimes use `\left` and sometimes `\mleft`, right? Then you have to come up with an interface that allows you to select between the two.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro no, I always would like to use `\mleft`. I tried loading `\usepackage{mleftright}\mleftright`, where the latter command changes the meaning of `\left` to `\mleft`, before your code. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I've just tried it now and it does seem to compile fine without problems. Are you getting some errors or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but now looking at my code (after more than two years!) all those `\let`'s at the beginning should have been `\def`'s.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro the unexpected behavior I get is that it still gives me the bad spacing: `\inf\set{X_n}` from your code and `\inf\braces*{X_n}` where braces is defined with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` don't give the same result (even changing `\left` to `\mleft`, etc.), the `\braces` one gives correct spacing. May be I should ask how to make a command defined by mathtools work as yours. And sorry, I know this was about two years ago :) Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

To make auto-sized bracketing as painless and concise as possible, here's what I do:

```
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\autobracket{(}{)}
\newcommand{\br}[1]{\autobracket*{#1}}
```

Example:

```
$$\br{\frac{1}{2}} + \br{1} - \br{\frac{\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)}{\sqrt[2]{\frac{1}{2}}}}$$
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I use the following newcommands:

```
\newcommand{\of}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\off}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\offf}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
```

Hence, in the text, `f\of{x}` will appear as `f(x)`, `M\ast\offf{g\off{x}+h\off{x}}` will appear as `M*{g[x]+h[x]}`, etc. with the `\left` and `\right` commands automatically built-in.

Comment: you might find that `\mathopen{}\left(`, etc., gives you better spacing (but that might be a personal preference).

Answer (score 3):

There is another possibility to do it, if the automatic size should be the default ([as here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/swap-definition-of-starred-and-non-starred-command)) and explicit sizes should be easier to remember (numbers 0 till 4 instead of exotic names)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Enable the new LaTeX 3 commands.
\usepackage{xparse}

% Provide the \alias command substituting the \let command by working with optional arguments.
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\alias}{\LetLtxMacro}

% Define a clear and useful programming interface. You should define \new, \renew and \provide similarly and use the correct one below.
\alias{\declare}{\DeclareDocumentCommand}

% Fix the spacing around \left and \right: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right
\alias{\leftOld}{\left}
\alias{\rightOld}{\right}
\declare{\left}{}{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\leftOld}
\declare{\right}{}{\aftergroup\egroup\rightOld}

% Usage: \newdelimited{functionName}{left delimiter}{right delimiter}
% Example: \newdelimited{parens}{(}{)}
%
% Usage of inner command: \functionName[explicit size]{delimited content}
% An auto sized delimiter is used, if no explicit size is given. Explicit sizes range from 0 (small) to 4 (huge)
% Examples: \parens{x}, \parens{\frac{x}{y}}, \parens[3]{x}, \parens[0]{\frac{x}{y}}
%
\declare{\newdelimited}{mmm}{%
    \declare{#1}{om}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{##1}{%
            \left#2 ##2 \right#3%
        }{%
            % Use the amsmath delimiter sizes to have proper scaling all the time.
            \ifcase##1\relax%
                #2 ##2 #3%
            \or \bigl#2 ##2 \bigr#3%
            \or \Bigl#2 ##2 \Bigr#3%
            \or \biggl#2 ##2 \biggr#3%
            \or \Biggl#2 ##2 \Biggr#3%
            \else \PackageError{newdelimited}{Only optional values 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 are supported.}%
            \fi%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \newdelimited{\parens}{(}{)}
    $\parens{x}, \parens{\frac{M}{W}}, \parens[3]{x}, \parens[0]{\frac{M}{W}}$
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it's easy to do *exactly* what you say, but you might not really want that; see the caveat below.

```
\let\lparen=(\let\rparen=)
\catcode`(=\active\catcode`)=\active
\def({\left\lparen}\def){\right\rparen}
```

The catch:  There are some obvious disadvantages to this, such as that parentheses now only work in math mode; any text-mode or un-stretchy parentheses have to be entered as `\lparen\rparen`.  You may be willing to do this in your own code, but you'll have to be quite careful about any external packages you include.  (If you were *really* dedicated, you could have something like a `\stretchparens` / `\plainparens` pair to turn this behaviour on and off.)

I wonder if those wiser than I could comment on subtler disadvantages?

Comment: Parentheses are widely used in text, so this approach is not recommendable; rather make the parentheses *math active* (mathcode `"8000`). My opinion is that *automatically* providing `\left` and `\right` is *A Bad Thing*.

Answer (score 2):

I always use some commands. For example:

```
\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\lange #1 \right\rangle}%      ⟨⟩
\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%     {}
\newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%     []
\newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%                   ()
\newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%                                
\newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{{\partial^{#1}#2 \over \partial {#3}^{#1}}}%
```

It works like this:

- `\pars{\Huge A}`
- `\partiald[3]{y\pars{x,t}}{t}`
- `A\\+`
- etc.

You can leave them in a file (for example `myMacros.tex`) and use `\input` in the main document: `\input{pathToFile/myMacros.tex}`.

Answer (score 1):

Why has no one metioned `\qty`?
It comes in physics package

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\qty{curly braces}\\
\qty(parenthesis)\\
\qty|Vertical bars|
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```