# The trestle problem: how to avoid >=< in the output

Tags: math-mode, symbols, spacing

TeX puts no space between `\mathrel` characters, so one can type := to make a definition.
But careless authors often type stuff like

```
< a, b > = < c, d >
```

to indicate that two scalar products are equal, and get the central three characters stuck together with no space around the equality sign. (I do tell them to use `\langle` and `\rangle`, fat lot of good it does.) Is there any clever way to override the `\mathrel` convention, at least in this instance, so that the equality sign is separated from the others, but remains a math relation character?

Comment: I feel your pain :{

Comment: What is your relation to these authors?  Are you writing a package, or editing a publication?

Comment: OT: Instead of `:=` one should really use `\coloneqq` from `mathtools` because the output of `\coloneqq` is vertically symmetric.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to store the list of all `<` and `>` appearing in the document inside the aux file, and use it in the second run to decide what should be `<` and `>`, and what should be `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle`.

The solution is a bit long, sorry. See the comments inline.

```
\makeatletter
% We could probably add some customization here.
% 
% < and > as a relation or as a delimiter
\mathchardef\lt@relation=\mathcode`\<
\mathchardef\ltgt@bar@relation=\mathcode`\|
\mathchardef\gt@relation=\mathcode`\>
% Note: \ltgtstep and \ltgtunstep are needed because of the 
% \left and \right. Also note that their placement (inside the group)
% is critical.
\def\lt@delimiter{\left\langle\ltgtstep}
\def\ltgt@bar@delimiter{\middle|}
\def\gt@delimiter{\ltgtunstep\right\rangle}
% < and > revert to the relation symbol if the .aux 
% disagrees with what we see in the current run.
\let\lt@error@relation\lt@relation
\let\ltgt@bar@error@relation\ltgt@bar@relation
\let\gt@error@relation\gt@relation
\let\lt@error@delimiter\lt@relation
\let\ltgt@bar@error@delimiter\ltgt@bar@relation
\let\gt@error@delimiter\gt@relation


% As in other solutions, we make < and > active in math mode.
% The corresponding control sequences have been defined above.
\begingroup
  \catcode`\<=\active
  \catcode`\|=\active
  \catcode`\>=\active
  \gdef<{\lt@active}
  \gdef|{\ltgt@bar@active}
  \gdef>{\gt@active}
\endgroup
\mathcode`\<="8000
\mathcode`\|="8000
\mathcode`\>="8000

% ===================

% The above commands will be called via 
%   \csname lt@\ltgt@error@\ltgt@type\endcsname
% where \ltgt@error@ is {} by default and can be {error@}, and
% where \ltgt@type is {relation} or {delimiter}.
\gdef\ltgt@error@{}
\def\ltgt@type{relation}


% \ltgt@list will hold our list of "<", ">", "|". Each time we append,
% we check that the symbol agrees with the corresponding one from the
% .aux file. If not, we fall back on the error mode.
\gdef\ltgt@list{}
\def\ltgt@append#1{%
  \xdef\ltgt@list{\ltgt@list#1}%
  \ltgt@prev@pop%
  \unless\ifx\ltgt@prev@head#1%
  \gdef\ltgt@error@{error@}%
  \fi%
}
% We pop the list from the .aux file as we construct the new list.
\def\ltgt@prev@pop{\expandafter\ltgt@prev@pop@aux\ltgtprevlist\relax\relax}
\def\ltgt@prev@pop@aux#1#2\relax{%
  \xdef\ltgtprevlist{#2}%
  \ifx#1\relax%
  \global\let\ltgt@prev@head\relax%
  \else%
  \global\let\ltgt@prev@head#1%
  \fi}

% To take care of grouping
\def\ltgt@append@open{%
  \loop
  \ifnum\ltgt@depth<\currentgrouplevel
  \ltgt@append{(}%
  \global\advance \ltgt@depth by 1\relax
  \def\ltgt@type{relation}%
  \repeat
}
\def\ltgt@append@close{%
  \loop
  \ifnum\ltgt@depth>\currentgrouplevel
  \ltgt@append{)}%
  \global\advance \ltgt@depth by -1\relax
  \aftergroup\ltgt@append@close
  \repeat}


% We will later \let<\lt@active and \let>\gt@active. For now, we just
% define these commands. Each has two pieces: first fill the \ltgt@list,
% putting many "|" to ensure that different groups are really separated
% by at least one "|". Second, typeset the correct symbol depending on
% what can be read from the prevlist (extracted from the .aux file).
\newcount\ltgt@depth
\def\ltgtstep{\global\advance\ltgt@depth by 1\relax}
\def\ltgtunstep{\global\advance\ltgt@depth by -1\relax}
\def\ltgt@openclose{%
  \aftergroup\ltgt@append@close%
  \unless\ifnum\ltgt@depth=\currentgrouplevel%
  %\global\ltgt@depth\currentgrouplevel%
  \ltgt@append@open%
  \fi%
}
\def\lt@active{%
  % fill the list
  \ltgt@openclose%
  \ltgt@append{<}%
  % typeset
  \ltgt@ifnextgt@TF{\def\ltgt@type{delimiter}}{\def\ltgt@type{relation}}%
  \csname lt@\ltgt@error@\ltgt@type\endcsname%
}
\def\ltgt@bar@active{%
  % fill the list
  \ltgt@openclose%
  \ltgt@append{|}%
  % typeset
  \csname ltgt@bar@\ltgt@error@\ltgt@type\endcsname%
}
\def\gt@active{%
  % fill the list
  \ltgt@openclose%
  \ltgt@append{>}% 
  % typeset
  \csname gt@\ltgt@error@\ltgt@type\endcsname%
  \def\ltgt@type{relation}%
}


% When we see a <, we use \ltgt@ifnextgt@TF{.t.}{.f.} to test if the
% head of the prevlist is a >. If so, we execute {.t.}, otherwise {.f.}.
\newcount\ltgt@ifnextgt@count
\def\ltgt@ifnextgt@TF{%
  \global\ltgt@ifnextgt@count0\relax%
  \expandafter\ltgt@ifnextgt@readone\ltgtprevlist\relax\relax%
  \expandafter\ltgt@ifnextgt@aux\ltgtprevlist\relax%
}
\def\ltgt@ifnextgt@readone#1{%
  %\ltgt@ifnextgt@count
  %\@ltgt@ifnextgt@false%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \expandafter\ltgt@ifnextgt@throw@FT
  \fi
  \ifx#1(%
  \global\advance\ltgt@ifnextgt@count by 1\relax
  \fi
  \ifx#1)%
  \global\advance\ltgt@ifnextgt@count by -1\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum\ltgt@ifnextgt@count<0\relax % no ">" can be found.
  \expandafter\ltgt@ifnextgt@throw@FT
  \fi
  \ifnum\ltgt@ifnextgt@count=0\relax
    \ifx#1<\relax % the first relevant character is not ">"
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ltgt@ifnextgt@throw@FT
    \else
      \ifx#1>\relax % ">" was found!
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ltgt@ifnextgt@throw@TF
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \ltgt@ifnextgt@readone
}
\def\ltgt@ifnextgt@throw@FT#1#{\ltgt@use@FT}
\def\ltgt@ifnextgt@throw@TF#1#{\ltgt@use@TF}


\def\ltgt@ifnextgt@aux#1#2#{% arg #2 delimited by brace, thrown away.
  \ifx#1>%
  \expandafter\ltgt@use@FTF%
  \else%
  \ifx#1|%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ltgt@use@T%
  \else%
  % \ifx#1(%)
  % \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  % \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ltgt@use@FFT%
  \fi%
  \fi%
  {\ltgt@ifnextgt@aux#2}%
}

\long\def\ltgt@use@T#1{#1}
\long\def\ltgt@use@TF#1#2{#1}
\long\def\ltgt@use@FT#1#2{#2}
\long\def\ltgt@use@FTF#1#2#3{#2}
\long\def\ltgt@use@FFT#1#2#3{#3}


% We put the definition of the relevant list in the .aux file at the end
% of the run. This file is read at \begin{document}.
\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\gdef\noexpand\ltgtprevlist{\ltgt@list}}}
% 
% To ensure that \ltgtprevlist is defined in the first run, we do
\let\ltgtprevlist\relax



% Embedding the test example in the package itself (bad idea, but eh...)
\unless\ifx\documentclass\@twoclasseserror

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The middle delimiter now works: $<a^2|x_{\sum_{i>j_1}i}>$, and nesting as well:
\[
<\frac{<u|v>+<v_1|v_2>}{<v_1|v>} v_1|v > = <u|v> + <v_1|v_2>,
\qquad {i<j}, {k>l}. % Note the use of braces to prevent seeing <j,k>. 
\]
How come the end didn't become $i<j, k>l$? because I enclosed each 
inequality in braces. Another case where this can be useful is to get
$<{<a,b>} a,b> = <a,b>^2$.

One more test:
\[
< {\sum |\lambda_i| v_i}| v > = 0
\]

\end{document}

\fi
```

Comment: Can I just clarify what this does? Is the idea that every time you hit `<` in the input, if the *next* `<` or `>` in the same math environment is the latter then the `<...>` form is used, otherwise the regular one? That's an amazing hack `:)`

Comment: @Will: thanks `:)`, it took me a while to get it straight. Replace "the same math environment" by "the same group", and what you said is right (try `\sum_{i<j}^{k>l}`). Using `\aftergroup` and checking for eTeX's `\currentgrouplevel`, I put (many) `|` between each group. `<` and `>` only match if there is nothing in between. To support nesting, we would need to replace `|` by `{` and `}`, and be careful with the number of braces. I'm too lazy for that tonight.

Comment: Splendid! though it goes well beyond the "clever kludge" I asked for. I worried about the `|` separator for a moment, but then checked that poor man's Dirac notation like `$<\alpha x|\alpha y> = |\alpha|^2 <x|y>$` does not confuse the procedure.

Comment: @jvarilly: the `|` is chosen arbitrarily. I guess it wouldn't be hard to also support Dirac's notation (with eTeX's `\middle`). I'll try to find some time this week.

Comment: @Bruno: No hurry with Dirac notation. For the middle separator I prefer `\mathbin\vert` so eTeX is not needed. Thanks again.

Comment: @jvarilly: for the sake of having a clean result, I took care of nesting and the middle delimiter. You can always disable it or change what it produces by changing the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 12):

Some authors really want to distinguish the `<...>` operator from `\langle...\rangle`. In this case, you can get the spacing right that way:

```
\newcommand*\diam [1] {\mathopen< #1 \mathclose>}
\newcommand*\scal [1] {\langle #1 \rangle}
% usage: \( \diam{\phi} = \diam{\psi} \neq \scal{\phi, \psi} \)
```

I'm surprised nobody mentioned that before.

Answer (score 10):

If you can get them to use any macros for this, then something like

```
\newcommand*\sp[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}
```

might be the way to go. (Okay, maybe not `\sp` since that's `\let` to `^`, but something to indicate the scalar product.)

Since you probably don't want to have less than and greater than in your final output and your coauthors aren't likely to change, then you might have to simply take a final pass through and fix their little mistakes. This is what I do.

Comment: I've used `\ip` for inner product.

Comment: Maybe try `\def\tuple<#1,#2>{\langle#1,#2\rangle}`?  A nice thing about this macro is that it generalises: it is just as natural to use it with more than two arguments, e.g., `\tuple<1,2,3>`.

Comment: This is what I actually use when writing my own documents. If I want Dirac notation, I can change the comma in the definition to \mathbin{|}, too. But what I was looking for was a clever kludge to put in the preamble of other people's source code, without having to rewrite the document.

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if

```
\mathchardef\lt=\mathcode`\<
\mathchardef\gt=\mathcode`\>
{\catcode`\<=\active
 \catcode`\>=\active
 \global\let<=\langle
 \global\let>=\rangle}
\mathcode`\<="8000
\mathcode`\>="8000
```

is too drastic? Now you can type stuff like `<u,v>\gt0`. (It probably *is* too drastic, but I couldn't resist the joke.)

Comment: I like it :) Alternatively, could you just assign a different mathcode to < and > ?

Comment: No, for mathcodes are 15 bit numbers, while `\langle` and `\rangle` are `\delimiter` commands with 27 bit arguments.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking straight—here's what I sort-of meant:  \mathchardef\lt=\mathcode\`\<
\mathchardef\gt=\mathcode\`\>
\DeclareMathDelimiter{<} {\mathopen}{symbols}{"68}{largesymbols}{"0A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{>} {\mathclose}{symbols}{"69}{largesymbols}{"0B}

Comment: Nice joke. Of course, having now to convince your (co)authors to use `\lt` and `\gt` instead of `<` and `>` doesn't really simplify the problem ...

Comment: Actually, it's not far from what I'd like. With some

Comment: Actually, it's not far from what I'd like. With some \futurelet look-ahead from < for the next comma and > character, it would probably be able to filter out genuine uses of a greater-than symbol.

Comment: @Hendrik @Harald @jvarilly: this thread was a basis for my answer below. I just added a check of whether the `<` means `\gt` or `\left\langle`, using the .aux file.

Answer (score 6):

Even better, from [this answer from Lev Bishop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands/1765#1765) on a relevant question, using [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) you could define:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ip{\langle}{\rangle}
```

And then use `\ip{a,b}` for your inner products. The great thing is that you also get for free a starred version `\ip*{a,b}` which will automagically resize the delimiters as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best thing to do is to offer them a macro (package) that makes typing easier.

Now I am a very lazy typist, so I would do something like this:

```
\def\<#1>{\langle #1\rangle}
$\<a,b> = \<c,d>$
```

but probably `\<` is already used for somethingelse in LaTeX?

In LuaTeX, you can actually change the internal math spacing table, like this:

```
\Umathrelrelspacing\textstyle=\thickmuskip
\Umathrelrelspacing\displaystyle=\thickmuskip
```

but as you probably cannot use LuaTeX and it has side-effects for predefined relations like `:=`, I doubt that will help you.

Comment: `\<` is used in the `tabbing` environment.

Comment: @Charles Stewart: I don't think that's a problem. Simple testing seems to indicate that \< is only defined inside the tabbing environment. So unless one is trying to use \<a,b> inside a tabbing, I think this would work. I didn't test it though.

Comment: @TH. *unless one is trying to use \<a,b> inside a tabbing* - which doesn't strike me as all that unlikely.  You could use something like `\everymath` to scope the definition, but that's kind of tricky to make stable.

Comment: @Charles Stewart: I thought about \everymath, but I couldn't recall the exact semantics. I assume \everymath{foo} \everymath{bar} is the same as just \everymath{bar} in which case you'd need to ensure that \everymath isn't used elsewhere, or else redefine \everymath...but it'd be tricky to get it right in all cases.

Comment: @TH.  Unless you are the class author, or you code against a particular class, there is no way to be right with confidence: any assignment to the token list might be undone elsewhere.  By no coincidence, I've asked a question about this, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/will-latex3-have-proper-support-for-hooks-does-luatex

Comment: You could probably do something like `\let\oldeverymath\everymath \def\everymath#1{\oldeverymath{#1\def\<##1>{\langle##1\rangle}}}` Probably not worth doing so though.

Comment: Ugh, it won't let me edit the comment. I meant `\let\oldeverymath\everymath \def\everymath#1{\oldeverymath{\def\<##1>{\langle##1\rangle}}#1} \everymath{}`

Answer (score 1):

What about using a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) replace in an editor?

```
s/<\([^<]*\),\([^>]*\)>/\\langle\1,\2\\rangle/g
```

This converts `< a, b > = < c, d >` to `\langle a, b \rangle = \langle c, d \rangle`.

There are bound to be exceptions, without a better regexp that could detect things like whether the string was in a math/displaymath mode.  But used interactively (that is, manually confirming each replacement) this could make the job easier.

Comment: +1, I think that fixing the source is generally more robust than putting workarounds in the Tex macros.  But it's not obvious from the qn that this would work for the qner.  It's maybe worth tweaking the regex to make sure the < and > aren't in occurences of \< and \>, say in a tabbing environment.

Comment: @Charles Good point.  But I have reached the limits of the regular expressions I can write in five minutes. :-P  Once you get into the lookaheads/lookbehinds I start to get confused.

Comment: You don't need anything outside the traditional regular language: I think using `[^\]<\([^<]*\),\([^>]*\)[^\>]>` as the pattern should work, since it is outside \1 and \2 in the replacement text. Note, in sed, this won't match "<" at the beginning of the line.

Comment: What does the [^] at the beginning match against?  Or is there a missing &lt; or backslash?  I had thought about matching for "not a backslash" at the beginning but ran into your caveat: you want to match for "a &lt; not preceded by a backslash" instead of "a &lt; preceded by something not a backslash".  But I think we're going off on a tangent...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why no one proposed this, but the first idea that came to my mind is to break the mathrel apart:

```
< a, b > {=} < c, d >
```

This seems to just do the trick.

Comment: Because semantically it's all wrong but (more importantly?) it looks ugly. Compare the output using `<` and `\langle` on a document.

Comment: I know, but the same can be said about the original expression, and the question was neither about semantics nor about making it look better.

Comment: But if you're going to fix the source, why choose such an inferior fix?