# Will LaTeX3 have proper support for hooks? Does LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, latex3, token-lists, expl3

Tex has powerful support for extensions triggered by events happen in generating output, by running one of six token lists appropriately:

```
 \everycr \everydisplay \everyhbox \everymath \everypar \everyvbox
```

They're used with effect in such places as Latex classes, but they are much less useful than they could be, because the `\everyfoo={\t\o ks}` assignment simply wipes the current value, making it rather tricky to use them by authors of packages and documents.  Emacs' Elisp has a widely understood technology for registering and deregistering code to run at events, namely hooks.

The LaTeX3 Project's `expl3` library offers supports for managing token lists, and LuaTeX augments TeX's event handling mechanism with a set of Lua callbacks.  Are these the beginning of proper support for event-driven TeX code, as usable as hooks?  Is this a priority for developers on these projects?

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged 'token-registers' not 'token-lists'?

Comment: @Joseph: I think token list is the more general concept.  Looking at *The TeXbook*: Knuth (p212) actually calls `\everycr`, &c, "token list parameters", to contrast them with \toks0..., which he calls "token list registers".

Comment: I wonder if the more usual 'toks' might be better in any case!

Comment: @Joseph: Not intuitive to me - that seems to me to be about `\toks0`... and not `\everycr`, &c.

Comment: My point is that `\everycr` works like any other token register, for example the `\everycr{tokens}` business. Perhaps this is because I'm a TeX programmer, and so used to having to think in terms of toks and macros as the two ways to store tokens in TeX.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you read the TeX program it's quite explicit that Knuth wrote it expecting people to add hooks / extensions for it, and he has often expressed surprise that TeX users chose to do complicated stuff in the macro layer instead of simply making a new version of the program. But I guess most people don't like the idea of editing the TeX program… except that the authors of e-TeX, pdfTeX and XeTeX did. Wish more did it though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LuaTeX does not offer these hooks out of the box, but you can make them yourself. The LuaLaTeX people do this (thanks!). See http://github.com/mpg/luatexbase (and there: `luatexbase-mcb.dtx`).

Comment: This is great: it does exactly what I think it should! Is there similar code for Context?

Comment: ConTeXt has had support for token list hooks since (almost) day one, even in traditional TeX engines. And yes, it also has callback support in LuaTeX, and that has been there for a while already as well.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that the callbacks behave as emacs hooks, where you can say "add this function to the beginning / end of the callback and remove this and that function".

Comment: @Patrick: LuaTeX itself doesn't provide such functionality, but it is precisely the goal of luatexbase-mcb (mcb means "multiple callback") to provide it. It allows to register many functions in most callbacks, with a priority system.

Comment: @mpg, this is what I tried to express... I really like this interface, nice job!

Comment: @Patrick btw, this is Élie Roux's job (largely inspired by ConTeXt).

Answer (score 9):

Sure, it would be great if LaTeX3 provided hooks for this sort of thing—not using the primitives directly, but rather providing an interface to a reliable way to use these token registers.

Unfortunately, ripping out the current LaTeX2e machinery for, say, giving a good way to access `\everypar` simply isn't possible without breaking backwards compatibility with lots and lots of current packages. Experimental LaTeX3 packages such as `galley` are written to start thinking about these ideas, but we're quite a way away from anything that can be used for general purposes.

Comment: So you see Latex3 supporting both class files written the Latex2e way, and the new, improved Latex3 way.  Will there be some mechanism for package writers to see what the class supports, like, say, a `hookable-events` flag?

Comment: Will is referring to 'l3in2e', _i.e._ loading bits of LaTeX3 as LaTeX2e packages. The deal with these is that they should not interfere with anything else, so for example you can load `expl3` and it will not alter the behaviour of other packages. A LaTeX3-only kernel is a different matter.

Comment: I should also add that in LaTeX3 we'll probably use macros for the storage, not token registers. See `l3tl` for how this is done (we use an e-TeX approach to allow us to store everything safely).

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the LaTeX3 side of things, I guess this is a place where I'd expect to provide a different input syntax to LaTeX2e. As the question points out, the current implementation uses the token register syntax

```
\everyfoo{tokens}
```

which overwrites whatever was in `\everyfoo` unless you do

```
\everyfoo\expandafter{\the\everyfoo tokens}
```

which is not exactly obvious. So a better approach would be something like the current `\AtBeginDocument`, something like:

```
\AtEveryFoo{tokens}
```

where this is additive. The implementation of such an approach would be easy enough.

**Proof of concept** A short piece of concept code that might be an approach for LaTeX3. The idea here is that the TeX primitive is only used by the kernel, with two separate hooks provided. First, settings that the kernel needs are applied, then ones from programmers and finally those from the user. In the demo I've only considered the `\everymath` concept. I've provided an interface for the user to both add to and clear the list, plus an alias to the LaTeX2e `\everymath` interface. (In a pure LaTeX3 approach I'd drop this TeX-like interface, or at least mark it depreciated.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\tl_new:N \l_every_math_programmers_tl
\tl_new:N \l_every_math_users_tl
\toks_set:Nn \tex_everymath:D {
  \check@mathfonts % LaTeX2e's requirement
  \tl_use:N \l_every_math_programmers_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_every_math_users_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand \InsertForEvery { m +m } {
  \tl_put_right:cn { l_every_ #1 _users_tl } {#2}  
}
\NewDocumentCommand \ClearForEvery { m } {
  \tl_clear:c { l_every_ #1 _users_tl }
}
\RenewDocumentCommand \everymath { +m } { \InsertForEvery { math } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\InsertForEvery{math}{\mathrm{Look!\,}}
\( y = mx +  c \)

\ClearForEvery{math}
\( y = mx +  c \)

\end{document}
```

I should add that a real implementation would need error-checking and so on.

Comment: This would be an improvement.  Both Elisp hooks and the `luatexbase-mcb.sty` Patrick mentioned go beyond this and allow you to both register and deregister handlers - neither being done in Tex, though.  You'd need a syntax like `\AtEveryFooDo{\handle}{handler tokens}` and `\AtEveryFooDont{\handle}`.

Comment: I take it that `\AtEveryFooDont{\handle}` would be equivalent to the current `\everyfoo{}`? (I can write up a properly written-up piece of proof-of-concept code if you like. Might be one for the LaTeX-L list, as it could be considered a bit specialist for here at the moment.)

Comment: I enjoyed taking the time to get a feel for how Latex3 is to be coded against.  So your code has three handlers: the baked in Latex2e requirement, a `math_programmers` layer, which I guess is for classes, and a `math_users` layer, which gives authors a chance to hack.  The syntax I suggested was meant to allow for arbitrarily many layers, each layer's handle being tagged by a handle, allowing the layer to be reset.  Your code gives clear precedence between the layers, a free for all on my suggestion, but it doesn't help package writers avoid stepping on each others' toes.

Comment: I did say 'proof of concept'. For programmers, you might provide a specific function or document that you should use `\tl_put_right:Nn` to add to `\l_every_math_programmers_tl`. Ultimately you can _always_ mess things up as a programmer :-)

Comment: (Just to note that `\tl_put_right:Nn` is essentially the same as `\tl_put_right:cn` but expects a control sequence rather than a csname as the frist argument.)