# Data structures for TeX

Tags: packages, programming

I often find myself wanting to use standard data structures in TeX. For example, lists or maps. Each time this need comes up, I reinvent the wheel. For some reason, I find myself using stacks fairly frequently.

Is there a standard package (either plain TeX or LaTeX) that offers a convenient interface to data structures? They would be most useful if the structures could be combined so that you could have lists of maps, for example.

Comment: Generate your TeX from the language of your choice giving you all the facilities of whatever language you choose and letting you leverage off your existing knowledge of that language.

Comment: Amen, brother (or sister).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One of the ideas of [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) is to provide a number of standard programming tools, and data structures are included in this. Currently, the structured data types available are sequences, stacks and property lists. Sequences and stacks have the same underlying structure: they are different ways of looking at the same thing. So we might have

```
\seq_new:N \l_my_seq
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_my_seq { Some-tokens } % Sequence-like access
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { More-tokens } % Stack-like access, puts to left
```

Property lists are a  key-value type data type

```
\prop_new:N \l_my_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {  key-name } { value }
```

Property lists are 'unordered', whereas sequences/stacks are ordered. In both cases there are functions available to map to each item in the stored data, for example `\seq_map_function:NN`.

New data types can be added to `expl3` as needed: this depends on the requirements of the LaTeX3 Project but also of others. (Note of course that I'm on the LaTeX3 Project!)

An alternative set of packages providing some similar ideas to `expl3` including a number of data-related structures is the combination of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and [`etextools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools). These two packages provide functions for mapping to lists and so on.

You might also look at the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package, which can be used to construct tables in LaTeX and access the data in a database-like fashion.

One other note. LuaTeX provides access to the native Lua data storage methods, which if you are doing a LuaTeX-only project would of course be the first place to look.

Comment: I've never looked at `expl3`, the naming has been off-putting. I take it it makes `_` have catcode 11, same with `:`? Or I guess it could `\def\seq_#1:{...}`. At any rate, I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: You get used to the naming :) Yep, inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`...`\ExplSyntaxOff` colon and underscore have catcode 11.

Comment: As Will says, the naming uses different 'letters' to traditional TeX. It's no more or less logical than using `@` as a letter, really, and fits more with what a lot of other languages do. (Plus avoids the business where `@` is used in a more-or-less random way in names.)

Comment: I do dislike how m@cros in LaTeX st@rt @cquiring m@re @nd m@r@ '@'s. And then, at the end of some words@, there are@ one@@ or@@ more@@@ '@'s.

Comment: Exactly. For `expl3` we've tried to have descriptive names where possible, then `aux` or `aux_i`, `aux_ii`, _etc_. when there is no real description other than 'an auxiliary function'.

Comment: Looking at the latex3 syntax I am really happy that I don't have to program in that language. It make LaTeX even more arcane.

Comment: Feel free to suggest an alternative :-) (I'd point out that I wasn't involved in the basic decisions on catcodes: they all predate my involvement by many years.)

Comment: Go to a good programmer who has not seen any TeX code before and show her things like `\prop_put:Nnn` and ask what this does. If she can answer it without asking back, the language (API) is good. If she can't, then rethink the language. Source code must be readable without having to translate everything in your head. Why? The more complex the translation process is, the more expensive is the code to maintain. And the less likely it is that someone actually uses that language. -- So my advise is to drop as much of the input language as you can and switch something more sensible, such as Lua.:)

Comment: But that won't work on XeTeX or pdfTeX: there are some requirements for LaTeX3, and one of them is 'we can only *require* TeX82 + e-TeX extensions'. I'd also point out that each language takes some learning, so for me something like `\prop_put:Nnn` is clear whereas Lua constructs are not. But then I'm not used to doing a lot of Lua work, so that's hardly surprising.

Comment: (As an aside, even the e-TeX extensions may be a requirement too much. At least in chemistry publishing circles the extensions are not available on the publishers servers.)

Comment: (As a second aside, I'd point out that the requirements for LaTeX3 are a team decision and that individual members of the team may have varying views on them!)

Comment: I am not sure how much I'd care about design decisions I have made 15 years ago.

Comment: Well, while LaTeX2e was released in 1994 the first ideas for expl3 were I believe worked through in 1991/1992, so it's a bit more than 15 years :-) Seriously, one thing that seems pretty clear is that the basic LaTeX document structure is another requirement, and that goes back to Lamport's original work in the 1980s.

Comment: @Patrick, you're comparing apples to oranges. Show me *anyone* to whom TeX/LaTeX is unfamiliar who doesn't think TeX/LaTeX programming is complete madness. Restricting *your*self to LuaTeX is fine but we simply cannot do that.

Comment: @Will: That's why I've put a smiley behind the sentence.

Answer (score 10):

I recently discovered the package `arrayjobx` (nee arrayjob) which has transformed my TeX usage.  Linked lists and indexed references are very simple to do.  Arrays combined with `fp` have allowed me to manage numerical data in TeX for display.  Reading the code for `arrayjobx` was also very enlightening.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\def\trimspace#1{\trim@spaces@in{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newarray\MyData

\readarray{MyData}{%
Years       & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 &%
Revenues    & 1034 & 1226 & 1445 & 1503 & 1992 &%
Costs       & 668  & 706  & 813  & 946  & 1010  }
\dataheight=6

\def\returnHeading(#1){\checkMyData(#1,1)\trimspace\cachedata \cachedata}
\def\returnYear(#1){\checkMyData(1,#1)\trimspace\cachedata \cachedata}
\def\returnData(#1){\expandafter\checkMyData(#1)\trimspace\cachedata \cachedata}


\def\mycolumn{3}
\def\myrow{2}

Our expected \returnHeading(\myrow) in \returnYear(\mycolumn) were 
\$\returnData(\myrow,\mycolumn).

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, I am not familiar with the packages mentioned in other answers.  Maybe they render arrayjob obsolete.

Comment: I remember briefly looking through this package earlier this year. It seems pretty nice; expl3 doesn't have any multi-dimensional data structures by default (yet?).

Comment: Brandon there is an update. It is a very good package, but use arrayjobx, which is the latest version. Previous one has conflicts with amsmaths

Comment: Thank you!  I used your solution to make access to the periodic table of the elements easy including showing the ionic charge automatically.  For instance "\ion 1" is converted to $H^{1+}$.

\newcommand{\ion}[1]{
 $\checkElement(#1,2)\trimspace\cachedata \cachedata
 ^{\checkElement(#1,4)\trimspace\cachedata \cachedata}$
}

Can you explain your use of \cachedata \cachedata?

Comment: @jlettvin, The \trimspace command is defined at the preamble using a macro from the trimspaces package - \trim@spaces@in - which redefines a macro to be its own contents, except with whitespace trimmed. So \trimspace\cachedata redefines \cachedata to exclude leading and trailing whitespace. Then the second \cachedata returns the (now-trimmed) result.

Otherwise you could wind up with spurious spaces in your cache data.

Answer (score 7):

Did no one mention the bridges to Lua in Luatex?  Well, Patrick did, oblliquely.

1. Luatex itself provides a number of low-level primitives to the Lua half of the implementation, most importantly the `\directlua` command.  Using this level is a bit fiddly.
2. Context 4 has, unsurprisingly, nice support for Lua.  For example, `\startluacode ... \endluacode` allows Lua to be naturally embedded in Context documents.  This is important, because Context uses Lua to manage the whole compilation process.
3. There's high-level Lua infrastructure for Latex appearing, codename Lualatex, with the obligatory `\LuaLaTeX` macro, and similarly nice environments for embedding code.  There's not much in Texlive 2009, and I've not made the jump to 2010 yet, but the document about supporting Luatex's hook in Latex, which [Patrick pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/will-latex3-have-proper-support-for-hooks-does-luatex/2017#2017) to me, looks appetising.
4. There's some Luatex support for Plain Tex, codename Luatextras.

Lua has a nice, efficient, minimalist approach to datastructures, based on its notion of tables, that fuses lists and associative arrays, and is used together with its novel approach to lightweight closures as its basis for a prototype-based object system.

It's good, take a look.

Comment: I'm fairly familiar with Lua and I don't really like its "everything is a table" approach and setting values in meta tables to control behavior is not a lot of fun. It's also anything but efficient. Maybe in comparison to TeX...

Comment: @TH. can you elaborate on "It's also anything but efficient"? What efficiency do you mean?

Comment: @Patrick: I mean that it is slow. Very slow. Maybe LuaTeX uses a JIT so it's faster, I'm not sure.

Comment: Either my memory is faulty (very possible) or Lua has gotten a lot faster. I just looked at some of the not-terribly-meaningful-but-we-all-use-them-anyway benchmarks that compare programming languages, and for a scripting language, Lua isn't bad. Looks like I need to reevaluate. (I still dislike meta tables though.)

Comment: @TH.: Luatex uses the interpreter, not Lua JIT.  The efficiency I meant is overall: it's at the fast end of dynamically-typed interpreters and it's very space efficient, which is more important, I think, in the context of Luatex.  Cf. http://www.mail-archive.com/dev-luatex@ntg.nl/msg00725.html.  Tex is efficient, very efficient for a macro-expansion language.

Answer (score 3):

I remember seeing some time ago in this site a link to [lambda-lists](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/lambda) aka *[lists in TeX's mouth](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb11-2/tb28jeffrey.pdf)* by Alan Jeffrey. I haven't yet tried it out, though, but it sure seemed nice and functional.