# Kiviat diagram with axis labeled and different sizes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-kiviat

I am trying to use the package tkz-kiviat to draw a kiviat. The following example produces the image below:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=1.25,label distance=.5cm,
        radial  = 5,
        gap     = 1,  
        lattice = 5]{McCabe,LOC,Live Variables,Halstead N,Variablenspanne}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=none,
               fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](3,3.5,3,3.5,3)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=darkgray,
               fill=green!20,opacity=.5](0.5,1,0.5,0.75,1) 
\tkzKiviatLine[ultra thick,mark=ball,
                 mark size=4pt,color =Maroon](2,3.75,1,1.5,2)    
\tkzKiviatGrad[prefix=,unity=100,suffix=\ \texteuro](1)  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Kiviat produced with the code above]

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to have axes with different sizes? In the previous example, all the axes go from 0 to 5. I would like to have one axis from 0 to 3, other from 0 to 2, and so on.
2. Is it possible to label the axes with enumerated values? In the previous example, instead of having 100€, 200€, etc. I would like to have Axis1: Active, Passive. Axis2: Earth, Venus, Sun, ...

Is this possible with this pacakge? Do I need to use another one?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! No need to end your post with a 'Thank you'. It is our way of keeping things concise. If you want to thank someone, upvote (and accept) his/her answer. :)

Comment: Different axis lengths damage the visual info that Kiviat charts offer. You won't be able to compare the emphasis on different parts of the chart.

Comment: I agree, but I have different axes with different sizes. How can I compare the information if it is not with a "kiviat approach"? If you have other solutions, they are more than welcome. I think having a kiviat with different axes is not that bad for my particular case.

Comment: You can still scale the intervals such that they look equal maybe? Can you include in the question what the precise application is?

Comment: Probably scaling is a good idea, once we know how to use different sizes for each axes. So the shape of the kiviat diagram can be uniform / regular (hexagon, pentagon, etc.) The exact application is a taxonomy classification. Different systems are classified into this taxonomy. As I have more than three axis, I thought of kiviat diagrams. However, my axis have all not an equal "size", i.e., number of values a system can have for a given axes.

Comment: I think in such type of diagram, the area under the curve is supposed to represent some kind of 'quality', so one would use it for non-nominal scales, and I don't know if your scales have some kind of order. How about drawing nodes with `TikZ` instead? You could vary the shape and draw/fill/font color, single/double outlines etc.

Answer (score 5):

An example for my alternate approach with `TikZ` nodes:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\myshape}{circle}
\newcommand{\myfillcolor}{white}
\newcommand{\mydrawcolor}{black}
\newcommand{\myfontcolor}{black}
\newcommand{\mynodecontent}{black}

\newcommand{\multiscale}[2]{% mode, planet
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{passive}}{\renewcommand{\mydrawcolor}{green!70!blue}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{active}}{\renewcommand{\mydrawcolor}{red!80!yellow}}{}
% ---------
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Mercury}}{\renewcommand{\myfillcolor}{black!75}\renewcommand{\mynodecontent}{\mercury}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Venus}}{\renewcommand{\myfillcolor}{black!50}\renewcommand{\mynodecontent}{\venus}}{}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{Earth}}{\renewcommand{\myfillcolor}{black!25}\renewcommand{\mynodecontent}{\earth}}{}
\node[color=-\mydrawcolor,draw=\mydrawcolor,fill=\myfillcolor,circle,ultra thick,minimum size=1cm] {\textbf{\mynodecontent}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\multiscale{passive}{Mercury}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\multiscale{passive}{Venus}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\multiscale{passive}{Earth}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\multiscale{active}{Mercury}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\multiscale{active}{Venus}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\multiscale{active}{Earth}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, `passive` is green frame, `active` is red frame, and the planets become lighter gray outwards from the sun. Of course, you'd have to provide a nice key for explanation.

---

**Edit 1:** I've had a look at the documentation of `tkz-kiviat` and as far as I can see it is not possible. I made a little concept how it *might* work, but it need horribly much manual tweaking. Also, i have no idea about text labels as `pgfmath` can only extract numbers from array like structures. Probably you can also ask **Altermundus**, the author of `tkz-kiviat` [and also a user on this site.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/altermundus)

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\kivaxisnumbers}{3}
\newcommand{\kivcategorycounts}{{2,3,4}}
\newcommand{\kivkumulativecategorycounts}{{0,2,5}}
\newcommand{\kivcategorynames}{{1,2,10,20,30,100,200,300,400}}
\newcommand{\kivlcmcatcount}{12}

\newcommand{\kivlattice}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisangle}{360/\kivaxisnumbers}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivlcmcatcount}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{6/\kivlcmcatcount}
            \draw[help lines] (\kivaxisangle*\x:\y*\kivaxisstep) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x+\kivaxisangle:\y*\kivaxisstep);
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {   \draw[->] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:6cm);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxissteps}{\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{6/\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivaxissteps}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivhelper}{\kivkumulativecategorycounts[\x-1]}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\kivlabelname}{\kivcategorynames[\kivhelper+\y-1]}
            \node[circle,fill=black,label=\x*\kivaxisangle+90:\kivlabelname,inner sep=1pt] at (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivaxisstep*\y) {};
        }
    }

}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\kivlattice
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 2:** For adding some data (in percentages of the axes):

```
\newcommand{\kivdatapoints}{}

\newcommand{\kivdata}[2]{% values in percentages of max, color
    \renewcommand{\kivdatapoints}{{#1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisangle}{360/\kivaxisnumbers}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivcoordinate}{\kivdatapoints[0]*6}
    \fill[opacity=0.2,#2] (\kivaxisangle:\kivcoordinate) 
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
        {   %\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivcoordinate}{\kivdatapoints[\x-1]*6}
            -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivdatapoints[\x-1]*6) 
        }
    -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\kivlattice
\kivdata{0.2,0.9,0.6}{red}
\kivdata{0.7,0.1,0.8}{green}
\kivdata{0.4,0.35,0.3}{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 3:** Thanks to *Brandon Kuczenski's* answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/data-structures-for-tex), I was able to add text labels to the axes:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\def\trimspace#1{\trim@spaces@in{#1}}
\makeatother

\newarray\kivaxisitemlabels
\readarray{kivaxisitemlabels}{%
Decision  & Yes    & No     &        &       &
Color     & Red    & Blue   & Yellow &       &
Direction & North  & East   & South  & West  &
Taste     & Sour   & Salty  & Bitter & Sweet &
World     & Normal & Nether & End    &       }
\dataheight=5

\newcommand{\kivcurrentlabel}[2]{\checkkivaxisitemlabels(#1,#2)\trimspace\cachedata \cachedata}

\newcommand{\kivaxisnumbers}{5}
\newcommand{\kivcategorycounts}{{2,3,4,4,3}}
\newcommand{\kivkumulativecategorycounts}{{0,2,5,9,13}}
%\newcommand{\kivcategorynames}{{1,2,10,20,30,100,200,300,400}}
\newcommand{\kivlcmcatcount}{12}

\newcommand{\kivlattice}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisangle}{360/\kivaxisnumbers}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivlcmcatcount}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{6/\kivlcmcatcount}
            \draw[help lines] (\kivaxisangle*\x:\y*\kivaxisstep) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x+\kivaxisangle:\y*\kivaxisstep);
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {   \draw[->] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:6cm);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxissteps}{\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{6/\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivaxissteps}
        {   %\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivhelper}{\kivkumulativecategorycounts[\x-1]}
            %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\kivlabelname}{\kivcategorynames[\kivhelper+\y-1]}
            %\node[circle,fill=black,label=\x*\kivaxisangle+90:\kivlabelname,inner sep=1pt] at (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivaxisstep*\y) {};
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\kivlabelnumber}{\y+1}            
            \node[circle,fill=black,label=\x*\kivaxisangle+90:\kivcurrentlabel{\x}{\kivlabelnumber},inner sep=1pt] at (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivaxisstep*\y) {};
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\kivdatapoints}{}

\newcommand{\kivdata}[2]{% values in percentages of max, color
    \renewcommand{\kivdatapoints}{{#1}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisangle}{360/\kivaxisnumbers}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivcoordinate}{\kivdatapoints[0]*6}
    \fill[opacity=0.2,#2] (\kivaxisangle:\kivcoordinate) 
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
        {   %\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivcoordinate}{\kivdatapoints[\x-1]*6}
            -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivdatapoints[\x-1]*6) 
        }
    -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\kivlattice
\kivdata{0.2,0.9,0.6,0.5,0.5}{red}
\kivdata{0.7,0.1,0.8,0.6,.2}{green}
\kivdata{0.4,0.35,0.3,0.25,0.2}{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: In my comment, I said that a Kiviat diagram might not be a good choice for his axes, so I provided a different approach. So no, I did not provide an answer solving his problem with Kiviat diagrams, but instead displaying the desired information in an alternative way.

Comment: @Tobi: No need, it's a legitimate question.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good idea. However I have 9 axis so this kind of diagrams will take to much place and they become difficult to compare visually between them. What is good with kiviats is that the shape you see relates all the aspects at once, so you can overlap the items you are studying by overlapping their kiviat diagrams.

Comment: Whoha, agreed, it fails for nine. I saw the five axes in your example, and that's the maximum I would do with nodes (shape, content, draw/fill/font color), so I guess I'll have a look in tkz-kiviat after all ;)

Comment: Thank you very much anyway Tom. I am looking at the implementation of the tkz-kiviat package. I don't know if I will be able to come up with a modification of it. If yes, I will put it here, but it seems to dark for my current understanding of latex.

Comment: what if you don't want to fill and you just want only the line instead?

Answer (score 0):

I created tkz-kiviat to draw only kiviat diagram . i'm not a great expert with kiviat diagram but in your case, you don't get a kiviat diagram with your requests.

1) You need to use **quantitative** variables represented on axes starting from the same point.

2) The data length of a spoke is proportional to the magnitude of the variable for the data point relative to the maximum magnitude of the variable across all data points.

With the actual tkz-kiviat, the only possibility to modify axes, is to use percent with lattice=10. It's the better method to compare the values (kiviat diagram are used  for this) and to compare areas. Only numeric values are used and authorized.

Comment: Thank you Altermundus. What I wanted is the kiviat drawn by Tom with qualitative values in the axes, with a different number of values by axis.