# Swap definition of starred and non-starred command

Tags: macros, math-operators, starred-version

I don't like the fact that I am required to use `\abs*` when I want the vertical line of the absolute value to automatically re-size. I pretty much always want it to re-size, so would like to swap the definition of the two commands, but not sure how to do that. My attempt below is commented out as it does not compile.

I can't think of a case where I'd want to use the version that does not resize, but in case some corner case arises in the future I don't want to loose that. Or, is there a good reason to not to do this swap, and  go and change all occurrences of `\abs` to `\abs*`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

%\let\oldabs{\abs}%
%\let\oldabs*{\abs*}%
%\let\abs{oldabs*}%
%\let\abs*{\oldabs}%

\begin{document}
Not sure why this is the default behavior, but it is:
\[\abs{\frac{1}{2}}\]

Would prefer to get this behavior using \textbackslash{abs},
instead of having to use \textbackslash{abs*}.
\[\abs*{\frac{1}{2}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: An old thread, but since it shows up every now and then, I don't think you really want to automatically resize `\abs{\hat{T}}` [like this (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnEBB.png)

Comment: @egreg: Totally agree. At the time it seemed like a good idea, but in hindsight it wasn't. However, the tricks one learns, even when it isn't really a good idea to do it, do come in handy sometimes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can redefine `\abs` to call the opposite version of the original command:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
\makeatother
```

(The reason that your commented try doesn't work is that technically the `*` is not part of the macro name, but is read by the macro itself using `\@ifstar`, `\@ifnextchar` or similar commands.)

Comment: Very nice trick! Will have it in mind.

Comment: So you suggest redefining every command manually? :-O

Comment: Don't do this: the output for the seemingly innocuous `$\abs{T}+\abs{\hat{T}}$` would be [like this (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnEBB.png)

Answer (score 8):

simply define `\abs` with `\def` if you do not want to use the star version.

```
\def\abs#1{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, I think the reason I had used `DeclarePairedDelimiter` was that would get the correct math spacing.

Comment: @Peter: You're right. `\left` and `\right` cause some extra spaces but one may fix this adding `\mathopen{}` and `\mathclose{}`, [see here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/7160). However, I experienced that `\left` and `\right` sometimes tend to scale `|`, `(`, `[` etc. a bit too large. This is why I prefer the use of `\DeclarePairedDelimiterY`, [see my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/swap-definition-of-starred-and-non-starred-command/25337#25337), as it allows rescaling by just specifying its optional argument.

Comment: @wueaul: that depends to the setting of `\delimitershortfall` or `\delimiterfactor`

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and wrote a work-around for this: a macro `\DeclarePairedDelimiterY`, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25328/use-csname-endcsname-to-compute-the-starred-version-of-some-command). But note you have to replace the line

```
{\csname#1Temp*\endcsname{##2}}%
```

with

```
{\csname#1Temp\endcsname*{##2}}%
```

Then you can define `\abs` by

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterY{abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

where the backslash of `\abs` is omitted. Then:

- `\abs{x}` expands to `\left\lvert x\right\rvert`
- `\abs[normal]{x}` expands to `\lvert x\rvert`
- `\abs[big]{x}` expands to `\bigl\lvert x\bigr\rvert`
- `\abs[Big]{x}` expands to `\Bigl\lvert x\Bigr\rvert`
- `\abs[bigg]{x}` expands to `\biggl\lvert x\biggr\rvert`
- `\abs[Bigg]{x}` expands to `\Biggl\lvert x\Biggr\rvert`

In contrast to the original `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command, you leave out the backslash of `\big`, `\Big` etc.

(Unluckily I didn't find your question prior to posting my own one...)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the internal definition

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\makeatletter
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\renewcommand*\DeclarePairedDelimiter[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{
    \@namedef{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star:}##1
        {\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left#2 ##1 \aftergroup\egroup\right #3}%
    \@xp\@xp\@xp
      \newcommand
        \@xp\csname MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar:\endcsname
        [2][\\@gobble]
        {
          \mathopen{\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 l} #2} ##2
          \mathclose{\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 r} #3}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{
      \@ifstar
        {\@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar:}}
        {\@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star:}}
    }
  }
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Not sure why this is the default behavior, but it is:
\[\abs{\frac{1}{2}}\]

Would prefer to get this behavior using \textbackslash{abs},
instead of having to use \textbackslash{abs*}.
\[\abs*{\frac{1}{2}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23483/510) question.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the internal definition

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\avg}{\langle}{\rangle}

\newcommand\swapifbranches[3]{#1{#3}{#2}}
\makeatletter
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\patchcmd{\DeclarePairedDelimiter}{\@ifstar}{\swapifbranches\@ifstar}{}{}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\mean}{\langle}{\rangle}


\begin{document}

$\avg{\displaystyle\sum_0^1}$  $\avg*{\displaystyle\sum_0^1}$

$\mean{\displaystyle\sum_0^1}$ $\mean*{\displaystyle\sum_0^1}$

\end{document}
```

[image: the result]

Comment: Isn't that going to change _all_ subseuent macros that use the start option? I only want to change `\abs`, not all macros that have a starred variant?

Comment: @PeterGrill it will patch the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro in such a way that it will define macros whose starred and non-starred behaviour swapped compared to macros defined by the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` before the patch.

Comment: I feel as if that is going to lead to lots on potential confusion. Might be better to define a separate `\DeclareSwappedPairedDelimeter` so that the definitions are not dependent on where they occur in the file(s).