# print cited page range in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I have to print the actually cited page range of cited books in the bibliography. [image: example]
The suffix `[10--20]` should be compressed to `10 f.` or `10 ff.`, but in the bibliography printed as `p. 10--20`
I've got no clue how to achieve it, I searched for commands but without result. 
[compress page range](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23483/how-can-i-automatically-abbreviate-page-ranges-in-citations-biblatex/23518#23518) gives only an example how to compress page ranges from `10-19` to `10-9`

One possible pathway to the solution could be via this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ 
bibstyle=test, citestyle=test 
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{books.bib}
@BOOK{scrubs,
  author = {John Dorian},
  title = {How to endure girls names},
  year = {2009},
  edition = {8}
  publisher = {Cox publishing}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{books.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[10--20]{scrubs}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and my bbx-file

```
\newbibmacro*{begentry}{}
\newbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{p.}
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}



\newbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iffieldundef{volume}
      {}
      {\printfield{volume}%
           \printfield{part}%
           \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {}
       {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{volume}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  }


\newbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{publisher+location}{%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {}
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}



\newbibmacro*{p.}{%
  \printtext{p. }}
\endinput
```

and my cbx-file

```
% $Id: test.cbx,v 1.7 2011/11/13 19:09:07 lehman stable $

\ProvidesFile{test.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid $Id: verbose-inote.cbx,v 1.7 2011/11/13 19:09:07 lehman stable $]

\providebool{bbx:subentry}

\DeclareFieldFormat{entrysetcount}{\mknumalph{#1}}
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\endinput
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the pages you used from the book (to be printed in the bibliography) and the pages you are actually citing. For the former, use the `pages` field (described in the [biblatex manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), section 2.2.2), for the latter use the optional argument to `\cite`.

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{books.bib}
@BOOK{scrubs,
  author = {John Dorian},
  title = {How to endure girls names},
  year = {2009},
  edition = {8},
  publisher = {Cox publishing},
  pages={10--20}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{books.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[10f.]{scrubs}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: excerpt of compiled code]

Comment: Thank you. I thought of using it that way a couple of days ago and forgot it. It's not actually the solution I wanted, because I hoped to find one with Latex processing one information to two different results. Here I have to provide two informations (for citing and pages) The visible result is the same.

Comment: @ingo so you want _all_ pages you cited throughout the document to be shown in your bibliography where the pages field is usually printed?! Strictly speaking, they are two different pieces of information: one is the number of pages _relevant_ from the book you cited, the other is the pages you're actually quoting at that point (in essence the difference between the citation and the bibliography entry ...)

Comment: That's almost right. I only want to shown the page range of all the cites I used in my text to be shown in my bibliography. If there weren't concrete examples I wouldn't believe it, that this is actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to list all pages that you cited in the bibliography, you can collect them all in a macro and print that into your bibliography:

The following code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{books.bib}
@BOOK{scrubs,
  author = {John Dorian},
  title = {How to endure girls names},
  year = {2009},
  edition = {8},
  publisher = {Cox publishing},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkfirstpage{#1}\ifnumeral{#1}{}{\ifnumerals{#1}{f.}{}}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gappto\expandafter%
\csname pagelist@\csfield{fullhash}\endcsname%
{\printtext[pages]{#1}\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}}}

\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit*{\bibpagespunct}%
  \expandafter\csname pagelist@\strfield{fullhash}\endcsname%
  \newunit}
\makeatother

\bibliography{books.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[10--20]{scrubs} \cite[33]{scrubs}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: screenshot of compiled code]

which is, as far as I understand, what you're looking for.

The first point to observe is that

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkfirstpage{#1}%
  \ifnumeral{#1}{}{\ifnumerals{#1}{f.}{}}}
```

throws away all but the first page number specified and tests to see if a range of page numbers or a single page number was given (I found this slightly confusing at first: `\ifnumerals` checks if a number *or* range is provided, therefore the case "a single page is provided" is checked with `\ifnumeral` and if this is not the case, we check if `#1` is a range of numbers or something completely different).

While we have access to the `postnote` field, we store the cited page numbers in a macro. Every occuring page number is stored in the macro `\pagelist@<full hash>` where `<full hash>` is a hash generated by `biblatex` that is unique to the bibliography entry.

In fact, the cited page is stored together with its formatting information, ready to be printed in the bibliography: for each citation,

```
\printtext[pages]{#1}\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}
```

is appended to the macro. Note that the optional argument `[pages]` to `\printtext` adds the prefix "p." or "pp." to the number and `\setunit*` makes sure the punctuation works in accordance with `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker (i.e. there is a full stop before the list and no trailing comma at the end).

Up to this point, we have only influenced what happens when the `postnote` field is printed. The next step is to insert our macro into the bibliography.

In the `standard.bbx` style of `biblatex`, the `pages` field is printed in the course of the `bibmacro` `chapter+pages` (this should be adapted if you write your own bibliography driver or use a different style!). In this case, we simply replace the printing of the `pages` field with our macro.

There are some downsides to this approach:

1. There is no sorting. The page numbers are listed *in the order they are cited*.
2. There is no checking for duplicates.

Both problems are not easy to solve (as far as I know ...) as handling lists in LaTeX is difficult, to say the least, and hence the outcome can be very unsatisfying. Consider for example

```
\cite[10--20]{scrubs} \cite[33]{scrubs} \cite[11]{scrubs}, \cite[2--3]{scrubs}

\printbibliography
```

which results in

[image: screenshot of compiled code]

which is confusing to say the least!

Therefore, the above "solution" may be seen as a fun exercise for appending values to macros but I would definitely advise using the `pages` field instead. If you want to emphasize which parts of the book you *actually* cited, the `backref` option is, in my opinion, a much better approach.

Comment: I stay with the pages field. It's easier to use. Thanks!