# biblatex: automatically abbreviate year ranges

Tags: biblatex, sorting, date

For consistency's sake I need to abbreviate *all* number-ranges in my document.

While biblatex [can easily be made to abbreviate page ranges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23483/how-can-i-automatically-abbreviate-page-ranges-in-citations-biblatex) the equivalent command for the year ranges breaks compilation with `Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mylibrary.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
    Address = {Place},
    Author = {Name, Given},
    Title = {Some title of this publication},
    Date = {1769/1783}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{mylibrary.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkcomprange{#1}}

%%doesn't work:
%\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkcomprange{#1}}


%%works (just for comparison)
%\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\textbf{#1}}


\begin{document}
“some quote” from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(I tried to use

```
    Year = {1769--83}}
```

which *looks* right but biblatex warns

```
   WARN - year field '1769--83' in entry 'somebook1769' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

and indeed the order of publications in the bibliography for several works by the same author is not correct.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the functions are already there, so we only need to piece them together. Unfortunately, the date handling code in `biblatex` is a bit complex due to the many EDTF/ISO 8601 features that are supported.

The American date format used by the default language `english` needs special handling. So the number of lines needed to get this done essentially double.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkcomprange{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifcompyear}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{        test {\iffieldundef{#1month}}
              and     test {\iffieldundef{#1endmonth}}
              and not test {\iffieldundef{#1endyear}}
              and not test {\iffieldequalstr{#1endyear}{}}
              and     test {\iffieldsequal{#1dateera}{#1enddateera}}
              and test     {\iffieldint{#1year}}
              and test     {\iffieldint{#1endyear}}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\compyear}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\blx@compyear@tempa{\thefield{#1year}-\thefield{#1endyear}}%
  \expandafter\mkcomprange\expandafter{\blx@compyear@tempa}%
  \endgroup}

\renewrobustcmd*{\mkdaterangetrunc}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         % Such a season component can only come from an ISO8601 season which replaces
         % a normal month so if it exists, we know that a normal date print is ruled out
         \iffieldundef{#2season}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
              {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{}{#2day}}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2month}{#2day}}}
              {\ifcompyear{#2}
                 {}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
                  \iffieldsequal{#2dateera}{#2enddateera}{}
                    {\dateeraprint{#2year}}}}}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2season}}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}%
              \iffieldsequal{#2dateera}{#2enddateera}{}
                {\dateeraprint{#2year}}}}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
              {\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
              {\ifcompyear{#2}
                 {\dateeraprintpre{#2endyear}%
                  \compyear{#2}%
                  \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}
                 {\bibdaterangesep
                  \enddatecircaprint
                  \iffieldundef{#2season}
                    {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}
                    {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
                  \enddateuncertainprint
                  \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}}%
  \endgroup}

\renewrobustcmd*{\mkdaterangetruncextra}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         % Such a season component can only come from an ISO8601 season which replaces
         % a normal month so if it exists, we know that a normal date print is ruled out
         \iffieldundef{#2season}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
              {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{}{#2day}}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2month}{#2day}}}
              {\ifcompyear{#2}
                 {}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
                  \iffieldsequal{#2dateera}{#2enddateera}{}
                    {\dateeraprint{#2year}}}}}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2season}}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}%
              \iffieldsequal{#2dateera}{#2enddateera}{}
                {\dateeraprint{#2year}}}}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {\printfield{extradate}}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
              {\printfield{extradate}%
               \printtext{\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}}
              {\ifcompyear{#2}
                 {\dateeraprintpre{#2endyear}%
                  \compyear{#2}%
                  \printfield{extradate}%
                  \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}
                 {\printtext{%
                    \bibdaterangesep
                    \enddatecircaprint
                    \iffieldundef{#2season}
                      {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}
                      {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}}%
                    \printfield{extradate}%
                    \enddateuncertainprint
                    \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}}%
  \endgroup}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkdaterangecompyear}[1]{%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1season}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1month}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1day}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1hour}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1minute}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1second}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1timezone}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endseason}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endmonth}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endday}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endhour}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endminute}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endsecond}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endtimezone}%
  \ifdateyearsequal{#1}{#1end}
    {\blx@imc@clearfield{#1endyear}}
    {}%
  \mkdaterangetrunc{short}{#1}}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkdaterangecompyearextra}[1]{%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1season}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1month}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1day}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1hour}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1minute}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1second}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1timezone}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endseason}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endmonth}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endday}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endhour}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endminute}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endsecond}%
  \blx@imc@clearfield{#1endtimezone}%
  \ifdateyearsequal{#1}{#1end}
    {\blx@imc@clearfield{#1endyear}}
    {}%
  \mkdaterangetruncextra{short}{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
\protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@long#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         \iffieldundef{#2season}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2month}{#2day}}
             {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {}
                {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2year}}}}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2season}}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}%
              \dateeraprint{#2year}}}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
             {\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
             {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {\dateeraprintpre{#2endyear}%
                 \compyear{#2}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}
                {\bibdaterangesep
                 \enddatecircaprint
                 \iffieldundef{#2season}
                   {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
                     {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                       {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{}{#2endday}}
                       {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                     {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                   {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
                 \enddateuncertainprint
                 \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}}%
  \endgroup}%
\protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@short#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         \iffieldundef{#2season}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2month}{#2day}}
             {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {}
                {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2year}}}}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2season}}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}%
              \dateeraprint{#2year}}}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
              {\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
              {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {\dateeraprintpre{#2endyear}%
                 \compyear{#2}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}
                {\bibdaterangesep
                  \enddatecircaprint
                  \iffieldundef{#2season}
                    {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}
                    {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
                  \enddateuncertainprint
                  \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}}%
  \endngroup}%
\protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetruncextra@long#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         \iffieldundef{#2season}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2month}{#2day}}
             {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {}
                {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2year}}}}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2season}}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}%
              \dateeraprint{#2year}}}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {\printfield{extradate}}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
              {\printfield{extradate}%
               \mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
              {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {\dateeraprintpre{#2endyear}%
                 \compyear{#2}%
                 \printfield{extradate}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}
                {\bibdaterangesep
                  \enddatecircaprint
                  \iffieldundef{#2season}
                    {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
                      {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                         {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{}{#2endday}}
                         {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                      {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                    {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
                  \printfield{extradate}%
                  \enddateuncertainprint
                  \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}}%
  \endgroup}%
\protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetruncextra@short#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         \iffieldundef{#2season}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2month}{#2day}}
             {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {}
                {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2year}}}}
           {\ifdateyearsequal{#2}{#2end}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{}{#2season}}
             {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}%
              \dateeraprint{#2year}}}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {\printfield{extradate}}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
              {\printfield{extradate}%
            \mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
           {\ifcompyear{#2}
                {\dateeraprintpre{#2endyear}%
                 \compyear{#2}%
                 \printfield{extradate}%
                 \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}
                {\bibdaterangesep
               \enddatecircaprint
               \iffieldundef{#2season}
                 {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}
                 {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
               \printfield{extradate}%
               \enddateuncertainprint
               \dateeraprint{#2endyear}}}}}}%
  \endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labeldate=compyear}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
  address = {Place},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Some title of this publication},
  date    = {1769/1783},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\enquote{some quote} from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "1769–83"]

Comment: This is just stellar! Your huge effort is greatly appreciated! I hope this can be included into `biblatex` at some point.

Comment: My MWE being minimal I didn't mention that I am using `polyglossia` and `xelatex`. There seems to be a direct conflict between `polyglossia`'s english and your solution: It compiles all right but adds a space (quad?) before "Name". (There doesn't seem to be a problem with other languages.) If it is difficult to fix or you don't have the time right now, I should be able to switch to `babel`, though.

Comment: @Florian Oh, sorry I forgot a few `%`. Should be fixed in the edit just now. The issue can occur with both `polyglossia` and `babel`, but due to some deficiencies with `biblatex`'s `polyglossia` module (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464281/35864) you may only have noticed it with `polyglossia`. Generally I would advise to use `babel` if at all possible and to only use `polyglossia` if it gives better results. `polyglossia` development has effectively stalled and many posts suggesting `polyglossia` are outdated. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482396/35864.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot! It seems to work fine now! (I am gradually abandoning `polyglossia` but I have still quite some long-term projects using older code. Obviously it's about time to make an effort to cut the ties...)

Comment: sorry to bother again … [leading zeros in the second part of the range are suppressed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25374/6819) (I haven't found it  in the documentation). Even though I know some styles enforce it, I am generally not too happy about this. But for years it seems really odd to me: "2000--7". Is there a switch for the gobbling of leading zeros?

Comment: @Florian I had the same need you described a couple years ago, for some ranges to include a leading zero. The code on this Gist will supply a leading zero (albeit in a silly-seeming way): https://gist.github.com/jmclawson/3496659647bedbf27c4dd0c9c71181b9