# Convert all \subsection to \subsection*

Tags: sectioning, starred-version

I want all of my `\subsection` behave like `\subsection*` Instead of adding `*` everywhere, I like to add a few lines in the preamble. What should I do? Can I just `\renewcommand`?

Comment: I'd think find & replace (or `sed` for example) would work just fine...

Comment: Why not use 'Replace'? I think it is available in every editor - does it all automatically.

Comment: Replace is obviously a possibility. But my document consists of many sub .tex files, so it would not be so convenient. And it is possible that I change my mind in the future. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Write

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

in your preamble. This says to LaTeX that only first level sections should be numbered; `\subsection` is level 2.

As Gonzalo Medina points out, there's also the `tocdepth` counter that controls what section levels are included in the table of contents. LaTeX is happy to include also unnumbered section levels in the ToC, it's a matter of taste and of the document's nature how deep one should go.

Comment: And `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` if a ToC is to be generated.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to redefine it.  This uses the solution from [Swap definition of starred and non-starred command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/swap-definition-of-starred-and-non-starred-command):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection{\@ifstar{\oldsubsection}{\oldsubsection*}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\end{document}
```