# 'Floor' and 'ceiling' functions

Tags: symbols

Is there a convenient way to typeset the floor or ceiling of a number, without needing to separately code the left and right parts?  For example, is there some way to do `$\ceil{x}$` instead of `$\lceil x \rceil$`?

Comment: In case anyone else got here looking for mathjax notation, in mathjax, `\lceil` and `\rceil` are the appropriate markups.

Comment: For me, `$\lceil x \rceil$` was already the solution I was looking for ;)

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118173/47927

Answer (score 261, accepted):

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
```

The command `\ceil` will do; if called as `\ceil*{x}` it will add `\left` and `\right`; you can also call it as

```
\ceil[\big]{x} \ceil[\Big]{x} \ceil[\bigg]{x} \ceil[\Bigg]{x}
```

to state explicitly the size of the delimiters.

Comment: Even after more than 10 years of LaTeXing one still learns some new tricks!

Comment: Don't tell me! I learn new tricks even after 25 years!

Comment: @egreg Is there any way to switch the default sizing option, so that `\ceil{x}` will do what `\ceil*{x}` would normally do?

Comment: @jamaicanworm There is, I believe also on this site. But I won't tell you: use `\left` and `\right` only when they are *really* needed.

Comment: @jamaicanworm [Swap definition of starred and non-starred command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23178) discusses switching the starred with non-starred version.

Comment: To typeset the floor function, just replace "ceil" with "floor". This may be obvious, but it might save you the trouble of consulting documentation.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a simple [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) implementation of `\ceil`, similar to that provided by [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)' `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`:

[image: xparse implementation of \ceil]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\ceil}{s O{} m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1} % starred
    {\left\lceil#3\right\rceil} % \ceil*[..]{..}
    {#2\lceil#3#2\rceil} % \ceil[..]{..}
}
\begin{document}
\[\ceil[\big]{x} \quad \ceil[\Big]{x} \quad \ceil[\bigg]{x} \quad \ceil[\Bigg]{x} \quad \ceil*[\big]{\frac{1}{2}}\]
\end{document}
```

The optional argument is ignored in the starred version of `\ceil*[..]{..}`.

Comment: You could eliminate the `\IfNoValueTF {\lceil#3\rceil}` if you used `{s O{} m}`.  Then the second arg `#2` will be defined so only need `#2\lceil#3#2\rceil`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your command with a simple single line as follow:

```
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\lceil {#1} \rceil}
```

The above command definition tells that your command takes one input [1] and uses that input between the predefined commands `\lceil` and `\rceil` via `{#1}`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks :)