# Absolute Value Symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the "best LaTeX practices" for writing absolute value symbols?  Are there any packages which provide good methods?

Some options include `|x|` and `\mid x \mid`, but I'm not sure which is best...

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}...\(\lvert x\rvert\)`; `\mid` denotes a relation symbol and is wrong for the absolute value.

Comment: Should I do `$\usepackage{mathtools}...\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\vert}{\lvert}{\rvert}` as per your answer to a previous question?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42274/9757

Comment: It's a good possibility. It depends on how many absolute values you have in your document; for a couple I wouldn't bother. But `\vert` is not a good choice, as it's already defined.

Comment: Thanks!  Why do people not just use the keyboard `|` symbol?

Comment: You can actually use `|`, but in some situations a certain care is needed. For instance `\(|{-1}|=1\)` without the braces would come out wrong, while `\(\lvert-1\rvert=1\)` surely gives correct output.

Comment: Maybe this `\bigg\vert` Or any kind of combination of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg` and `\vert`.

Comment: I was anout to say to use the `physics` package, but when including a `\frac` command, it spits out an error ;(

Comment: The use of `mathtools` is a good idea, but use `\abs` for the name of the new delimiter, as in `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}`

Answer (score 246, accepted):

I have been using the code below using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the [`mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

Since I don't think I have a case where I don't want this to scale based on the parameter, I make use of [Swap definition of starred and non-starred command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/swap-definition-of-starred-and-non-starred-command) so that the normal use will automatically scale, and the starred version won't:

[image]

If you want it the other way around comment out the code between `\makeatother...\makeatletter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%

% Swap the definition of \abs* and \norm*, so that \abs
% and \norm resizes the size of the brackets, and the 
% starred version does not.
\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\Value}{\frac{1}{2}x^2}%
\begin{document}
    \[\abs{\Value}  \quad \norm{\Value}  \qquad\text{non-starred}  \]
    \[\abs*{\Value} \quad \norm*{\Value} \qquad\text{starred}\qquad\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg: Agreed.  But I have not encountered that with `\abs` yet. BTW, I like your "_always_ is generally wrong" :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  General point of interest:  why do you use `\dfrac` instead of plain `\frac`?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: I used `\dfrac` in this case to make a larger fraction in inline mode.  This is not normally recommended in inline mode as it breaks paragraph spacing. I will update the solution to remove that.

Comment: There's a reason why it's preferable to use the `*`-version for the automatic resizing macro: *always* using `\left` and `\right` is wrong, in general.

Comment: +1, even though I have to say that this answer is not very skim-reading friendly with the huge "starred"/"non-starred" picture and the remark somewhere in the text "BTW, normal behaviour is the other way around". The question OTOH is one that makes everything in this thread very prone to being skim-read.

Comment: If I could upvote for every time I've referenced this...

Comment: a definite advantage of using commands like `\abs` and `\norm` which no one seems to have mentioned: since the `|` symbol has special meaning in the `makeidx` context, trying to enter terminology using a bare `|` within `\index{...}` will result in (delayed) errors and a lot of hair pulling for someone not really familiar with that usage.  commands like the ones shown here (or even just bare `\vert`, `\Vert` or `\mid`) is a *lot* safer and worth becoming familiar with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Excellent point!

Comment: I do not understand your comment, @egreg about `*`. In my practice, I almost always need the automatic size changes of these delimiters. The great thing about the `mathtools` versions is that it's easy to change from one version to another.  In many cases, I use starred versions of environments and commands more often than unstarred ones.  For example, I usually use `equation*` or `align*` in final versions of a paper or book.

Comment: It seems that all `\abs` solutions here do not work with pandoc for now. Why isn't this basic math operator/function be implemented by default?

Answer (score 107):

Note if you just use `|` you get mathord spacing, which is different from the spacing you'd get from paired mathopen/mathclose delimiters or from `\left/\right` even if `\left/\right` doesn't stretch the symbol. Personally I prefer the left/right spacing from mathinner here (even if @egreg says I'm generally wrong:-)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

$  \log|x||y|b $

$  \log\left|x\right|\left|y\right|b $

$  \log\mathopen|x\mathclose|\mathopen|y\mathclose|b $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 88):

One can also use `commath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}
\[ \norm{a \vec{u}} = \abs{a} \, \norm{\vec{v}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for this one, as it includes the semantics and has a relatively short syntax.

Comment: The spacing is somehow bad when used as subscript. The `\abs{}` of [`physics`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics?lang=en) is the better choice in my opinion.

Comment: sorry the `commath` package is fundamentally broken and should be avoided, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner

Answer (score 56):

The [`physics`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics?lang=en) LaTeX package also implements `abs` and `norm`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
    \[ c = \abs{-c} \]
    \[ \vu{a} = \frac{\vb{a}}{\norm{\vb{a}}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution!

Answer (score 32):

A simple, LaTeX native way of doing this is by using the `\|` delimiter, with the standard `\left` and `\right` modifiers ([source](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/BracketsNorms.html)).

For example:

```
\left\| \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2 \right\|
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Also: using the `|` delimiter (without the preceding backslash) inserts a *single* vertical bar.

Comment: For fun try `\|+a\|`, as you can see this is wrong, and thus generally users should not just use `|...|` or `\|...\|` as they may accidentally come into situations where this is wrong. I'll leave it as an exercise why this happens. Plus in your example the fences does not need to be that tall.

Comment: With `\|+a\|` the spacing appears to be wrong, but with `\left\|+a\right\|` it appears to be fine.

Comment: Correct because one is left and the other is right. But `\left` and `\right` should only be added when actually needed (which is actually not often). My complain to your answer is that it is not good in general, for reasons that are explained in comments to other answers in this thread.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  %begin equation
\lVert w \rVert
%end equation
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For LyX users: maybe I have just overlooked how to do it correctly, but I couldn't find a way of doing this natively.

I thus used a 1x1-Matrix environment and set the kind to determinant. It might just be a hack, but it works fine in my usecase.

Comment: At least in the case of Lyx 2.1.4, I find that I can simply type \lvert and \rvert into my display formula and Lyx "does the right thing." In my specific case I want absolute value bars around a fraction, so I used \bigg\lvert on the one side and \bigg\rvert on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any package, use `\mid`.

Comment: `\vert` doesn't require any package either, and the spacing isn't as awful as with `\mid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect,commath}
\author{Nguyễn Văn Minh Hiếu}
\begin{document}
$\overrightarrow{AB}$\\
$\abs{\vv{AB}}$\\
$\abs[1]{\vv{a}}+\abs[1]{\vv{b}}=\abs[1]{\vv{c}}$\\
\end{document}
```