# What's the correct way to write norm?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols)

What is a correct way to write norm of a vector (or an operator)?

Is there a substantial difference between the following possibilities? Which of them do you recommend?

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
```