# Resizing a CD diagram in math mode

Tags: math-mode, diagrams

I have a problem, I try to resize a diagram, this is what I write

```
\[
\scalebox{1.4}{  
\begin{CD}  
    C @>\phi>> C'=\phi(C)\\  
    @V\textnormal{Dual}VV\\  
    C^{\perp}@>\phi>> C=\phi(C^{\perp})  
\end{CD}  
}  
\]
```

And it works, except that I get an error, something like missing `$` or extra `}`, can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, but not, i post the example after the people start tell me that i should put an example an no one answer my question... when i put the example nobody else try to help me.... so i don´t knwo what to do... sorry if i did wrong

Comment: @cmhughes my mistake, i copy the wrong example so you thing that was that same question, i was talking about another one

Comment: @Dimitri `\scalebox` switched back to text-mode and the `CD` (apparently) expects math-mode. `\[\scalebox{1.4}{$\begin{CD} … \end{CD}$}\]` probably would work. But we can only guess, if you do not post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/16595) so that we can see which class, which packages, etc you use. Which package provides the `CD` environment for example? It would be easier to us to help you if we could simply copy your code and can compile it without the need to setup everything.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks very much, this works now. I am new in this so i am not familiarize with MWE and those things yet

Comment: @Dimitri A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is a complete, minimal document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending in `\end{document}` that shows what you want to achieve or solve.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100393/15925 ?