# Tikzcd graph gives me: Typesetting problem in main.tex Too wide error

Tags: dimensions, tikz-cd

I made a graph which looks good in the pdf. But now latex keeps telling me it's too wide and I have no idea how to compress this thing.

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
                                                                            &F_{4}=G_{4} \arrow{dr} \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} \\
\triangle_{3,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{3,1}(G_{4}) \arrow{d} \arrow{dr}          &\triangle_{2,2}(F_{4})=\triangle_{2,2}(G_{4})    \arrow{dl} \arrow{dr}     \arrow{d}        &\triangle_{1,3}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,3}(G_{4}) \arrow{d} \arrow{dl}\\
\triangle_{2,1,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{2,1,1}(G_{4})  \arrow{dr}               & \triangle_{1,2,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,2,1}(G_{4})         \arrow{d}                        & \triangle_{1,1,2}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,1,2}(G_{4}) \arrow{dl}\\
                                                                            & \triangle_{1,1,1,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,1,1,1}(G_{4})
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a full MWE which is showing the error you are mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, you are using the documentclass `article`, I am not getting an error but a warning:

> Overfull \hbox (54.60153pt too wide)

This means that your graph will extend 54.6 points into your margin. Maybe you can live with this matter. But obviously it would be nice to reduce this overhang in order to stay in margins.

If your image is just to wide, you could reduce the column separation value `column sep=`. If you want to keep the size ratio of your graph, you may want to reduce both the column and the row separator (as can be seen in my third example).

If you want to scale the nodes as well (wouldn't recommend this), you may have a look on including externalized TikZ images or on the [answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138984).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
                                                                            &F_{4}=G_{4} \arrow{dr} \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} \\
\triangle_{3,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{3,1}(G_{4}) \arrow{d} \arrow{dr}          &\triangle_{2,2}(F_{4})=\triangle_{2,2}(G_{4})    \arrow{dl} \arrow{dr}     \arrow{d}        &\triangle_{1,3}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,3}(G_{4}) \arrow{d} \arrow{dl}\\
\triangle_{2,1,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{2,1,1}(G_{4})  \arrow{dr}               & \triangle_{1,2,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,2,1}(G_{4})         \arrow{d}                        & \triangle_{1,1,2}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,1,2}(G_{4}) \arrow{dl}\\
                                                                            & \triangle_{1,1,1,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,1,1,1}(G_{4})
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny] % or small, scriptsize...
& F_4=G_4 \arrow{dr} \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} \\
\triangle_{3,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{3,1}(G_4) \arrow{d} &\triangle_{2,2}(F_4)=\triangle_{2,2}(G_4) \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} & \triangle_{1,3}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,3}(G_4) \arrow{d} \arrow{dl}\\
\triangle_{2,1,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{2,1,1}(G_4) \arrow{dr} & \triangle_{1,2,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,2,1}(G_4) \arrow{d} \arrow[<-,crossing over]{ul} & \triangle_{1,1,2}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,1,2}(G_4) \arrow{dl} \arrow[<-,crossing over]{ul}\\
& \triangle_{1,1,1,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,1,1,1}(G_4)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, column sep=tiny] % or scriptsize...
& F_4=G_4 \arrow{dr} \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} \\
\triangle_{3,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{3,1}(G_4) \arrow{d} &\triangle_{2,2}(F_4)=\triangle_{2,2}(G_4) \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} & \triangle_{1,3}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,3}(G_4) \arrow{d} \arrow{dl}\\
\triangle_{2,1,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{2,1,1}(G_4) \arrow{dr} & \triangle_{1,2,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,2,1}(G_4) \arrow{d} \arrow[<-,crossing over]{ul} & \triangle_{1,1,2}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,1,2}(G_4) \arrow{dl} \arrow[<-,crossing over]{ul}\\
& \triangle_{1,1,1,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,1,1,1}(G_4)
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The last two images still are having an overhang of 18.6 pt. Personally, I could live with this. If you want to get rid of it, scale the font size (as mentioned by Torbjørn), use some scaling from the answer I linked above or try to rephrase your graph.

**Edit using xy-pic**

Here is the same code for the package `xy`. I just reduced the column separation size. But of course you may introduce an `\xymatrixrowsep{}` as well.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,pdf,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrixcolsep{0.03in}
\xymatrix{%
& F_4=G_4 \ar[dr] \ar[dl] \ar[d] \\
\triangle_{3,1}(F_4)=\triangle_{3,1}(G_4) \ar[d] \ar[dr] & \triangle_{2,2}(F_4)=\triangle_{2,2}(G_4) \ar[dl]|\hole \ar[dr]     \ar[d] & \triangle_{1,3}(F_4)=\triangle_{1,3}(G_4) \ar[d] \ar[dl]|\hole\\
\triangle_{2,1,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{2,1,1}(G_{4})  \ar[dr] & \triangle_{1,2,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,2,1}(G_{4}) \ar[d] & \triangle_{1,1,2}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,1,2}(G_{4}) \ar[dl]\\
& \triangle_{1,1,1,1}(F_{4})=\triangle_{1,1,1,1}(G_{4})
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reducing the font size is also an option to consider (add e.g. `font=\small`). Edit: Oh, and a little tip: `\usepackage{showframe}`.