# Adjusting the width of a displaymath environment

Tags: spacing, equations, margins, tikz-cd

I want to adjust the width of an `displaymath` environment whose contents (a `tikzcd` diagram rather than an actual equation) are too wide to fit in the margins. The obvious thing to do is to use the `adjustwidth` environment, but this doesn't work as well as I would like:  the vertical spacing of the result is sometimes quite ugly. (It seems to be some kind of conflict with `mathtools`, see below.)

It seems to me that the problem is in the implementation of `adjustwidth` using `list`. Perhaps there is an alternative / more direct way of adjusting the margins of part of a page that works better with `equation`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\sample}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.}

\begin{document}
\sample
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.5in}{-0.5in}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \\
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{adjustwidth}
\sample
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you make a real world example, as this isn't really meaningful? And, please, don't use the `minimal` class.

Comment: If this is for a printed article/book/thesis, I'd advise against scaling the font. Instead, I'd try to stretch/shrink the arrows based on the width of the page.

Comment: @egreg I replaced it with a real world example. Note the asymmetrical vertical spacing for the second diagram compared to the third diagram; adding `\vskip -1em` after `\begin{adjustwidth}` makes things look better.

Comment: is it possible that you have left a blank line before the second display?  that will disrupt the spacing above a display, but to be certain, we need to see the actual code for the problem area, presented as a compilable example.  another trick you might try is to insert on both sides of the diagram a negative horizontal space (the same width on both sides) to trick tex into thinking the display is narrower.

Comment: I like your idea with `\hspace`! It works well enough for my use case. As for blank lines, _I_ have not left any, but perhaps `mathtools` has...

Comment: The latest version of `tikz-cd` defines a `cramped` style that may help in this case.  So the first things I would try is `\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=scriptsize]` ... `\end{tikzcd}`; and if that doesn't work, I would try `\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, sep=small]` ... `\end{tikzcd}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to try is, of course, reducing the arrow lengths. If all else fails, use `\mathclap` that, however, requires `ampersand replacement`; or enclose the diagram in an `lrbox`.

I'll show all three possibilities.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newsavebox{\wideeqbox}

\newcommand{\sample}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
in reprehenderit in voluptate.}

\begin{document}
\sample
\[
\mathclap{
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \rar \&
\bullet \dar \\
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet \rar \&
\bullet
\end{tikzcd}
}
\]
\sample
\[
\begin{lrbox}{\wideeqbox}
$\begin{tikzcd}
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \\
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet
\end{tikzcd}$
\end{lrbox}
\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\wideeqbox}}
\]
\sample
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em,row sep=1.5em]
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \rar &
\bullet \dar \\
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet \rar &
\bullet
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\sample

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `lrbox` solution can be packaged into an environment:

```
\newsavebox{\wideeqbox}
\newenvironment{wideeq}
  {\begin{displaymath}\begin{lrbox}{\wideeqbox}$\displaystyle}
  {$\end{lrbox}\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\wideeqbox}}\end{displaymath}}
```

Then

```
text
\begin{wideeq}
\begin{tikzcd}
...
\end{tikzcd}
\end{wideeq}
text
```

will do. Any math mode material can be used.

Comment: I think your solution with `lrbox` seems most reasonable. Do you think it could be packaged into a new environment?

Comment: @ZhenLin Sure, I added it.

Comment: I think you missed a `\end{lrbox}` in your code, but otherwise it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it was missing. Fixed.