# Vertical alignment of vector magnitude bars

Tags: vertical-alignment, vector

I want to denote the magnitude of `\overrightarrow{AB}` but all the options I have found look wrong:

```
$|\overrightarrow{AB}|$
$\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|$
$\vert\overrightarrow{AB}\vert$
$\lvert\overrightarrow{AB}\rvert$
```

I don't know how to make the website latex the code snippets, but the first, third and fourth options are all the same --- the magnitude bars start too far below the letters and stop at the top of the letters.  The second option has the right top of the bars (in my opinion), but go cartoonishly far below the bottom of the letters.

Is there a way to have the magnitude bars go from the bottom of the letters to the top of the arrow?

Comment: Thank you for referring to the duplicate question.  There was a comment on it that linked to another question, which contained a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89325/too-long-short-pipe-absolute-value-in-math-mode-with-certain-letters) I am happy with.  In particular the solution called 'Method 2 fixed extent'.  It took a little fine tuning, but I got there.

Comment: This might also be of help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124464/47927