# commath and \ifinner

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, breqn

The `commath` package use the TeX command `\ifinner` to select between inline math mode and display math mode. Because of this, it fail to work properly with some display math environments.

In the `breq`n package, we find:

> The test `\ifinner` is unreliable for distinguishing whether we are in a displayed formula or an inline formula: (...) So we provide a more reliable test. But it might have been provided already by the amsmath package.

The more reliable test should be `\if@display` but only replace `\ifinner` with  `\if@display` in `commath.sty` not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no `\if@display` conditional. The `commath` package has many errors and I can't recommend using it.

Comment: Did you recommend some replacement for `commath`?

Comment: `commath` is just a collection of macros, some of them perhaps useful, but badly written in general. Define your own substitutes, which is not so difficult.

Comment: Try the `cool` package instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's see how `commath` should define its macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% Here start the definitions
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{D}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spx}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {^{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\pd[3][]{\frac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand\tpd[3][]{\tfrac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand\dpd[3][]{\dfrac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}

\newcommand{\md}[6]{\frac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}
\newcommand{\tmd}[6]{\tfrac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}
\newcommand{\dmd}[6]{\dfrac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}

\newcommand{\od}[3][]{\frac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tod}[3][]{\tfrac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand{\dod}[3][]{\dfrac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}

\newcommand{\genericdel}[4]{%
  \ifcase#3\relax
  \ifx#1.\else#1\fi#4\ifx#2.\else#2\fi\or
  \bigl#1#4\bigr#2\or
  \Bigl#1#4\Bigr#2\or
  \biggl#1#4\biggr#2\or
  \Biggl#1#4\Biggr#2\else
  \left#1#4\right#2\fi
}
\newcommand{\del}[2][-1]{\genericdel(){#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\set}[2][-1]{\genericdel\{\}{#1}{#2}}
\let\cbr\set
\newcommand{\sbr}[2][-1]{\genericdel[]{#1}{#2}}
\let\intoo\del
\let\intcc\sbr
\newcommand{\intoc}[2][-1]{\genericdel(]{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\intco}[2][-1]{\genericdel[){#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\eval}[2][-1]{\genericdel.|{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\envert}[2][-1]{\genericdel||{#1}{#2}}
\let\abs\envert
\newcommand{\sVert}[1][0]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
  \rvert\or\bigr|\or\Bigr|\or\biggr|\or\Biggr
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\enVert}[2][-1]{\genericdel\|\|{#1}{#2}}
\let\norm\enVert
\newcommand{\fullfunction}[5]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}}
  #1 \colon & #2 & {}\longrightarrow{} & #3 \\
            & #4 & {}\longmapsto{}     & #5
  \end{array}
}
%%% end of the definitions

\linespread{2} % just for this test file

\begin{document}

$f(x)\dif x\quad f(x)\Dif x$

$\pd{f}{x}\displaystyle\pd[2]{f}{x}$

$\tpd{f}{x}\displaystyle\tpd[2]{f}{x}$

$\dpd{f}{x}\displaystyle\dpd[2]{f}{x}$

$\od{f}{x}\displaystyle\od[2]{f}{x}$

$\tod{f}{x}\displaystyle\tod[2]{f}{x}$

$\dod{f}{x}\displaystyle\dod[2]{f}{x}$

$\md{f}{5}{x}{2}{y}{3}\displaystyle\md{f}{5}{x}{2}{y}{3}$

$\tmd{f}{5}{x}{2}{y}{3}\displaystyle\tmd{f}{5}{x}{2}{y}{3}$

$\dmd{f}{5}{x}{2}{y}{3}\displaystyle\dmd{f}{5}{x}{2}{y}{3}$

$\del{\dfrac{1}{2}}\del[0]{x}\del[1]{x}\del[2]{x}\del[3]{x}\del[4]{x}$

$\sbr{\dfrac{1}{2}}\sbr[0]{x}\sbr[1]{x}\sbr[2]{x}\sbr[3]{x}\sbr[4]{x}$

$\set{\dfrac{1}{2}}\set[0]{x}\set[1]{x}\set[2]{x}\set[3]{x}\set[4]{x}$

$\intoo{a,b}\intoo[0]{a,b}\intoo[1]{a,b}\intoo[2]{a,b}\intoo[3]{a,b}\intoo[4]{a,b}$

$\intcc{a,b}\intcc[0]{a,b}\intcc[1]{a,b}\intcc[2]{a,b}\intcc[3]{a,b}\intcc[4]{a,b}$

$\intoc{a,b}\intoc[0]{a,b}\intoc[1]{a,b}\intoc[2]{a,b}\intoc[3]{a,b}\intoc[4]{a,b}$

$\intco{a,b}\intco[0]{a,b}\intco[1]{a,b}\intco[2]{a,b}\intco[3]{a,b}\intco[4]{a,b}$

$
\eval{f(x)}_a^b
\eval[0]{f(x)}_a^b
\eval[1]{f(x)}_a^b
\eval[2]{f(x)}_a^b
\eval[3]{f(x)}_a^b
\eval[4]{f(x)}_a^b
$

$\abs{x}\abs[0]{x}\abs[1]{x}\abs[2]{x}\abs[3]{x}\abs[4]{x}$

$\norm{x}\norm[0]{x}\norm[1]{x}\norm[2]{x}\norm[3]{x}\norm[4]{x}$

\linespread{1}\selectfont % return to normal

$\fullfunction{f}{A}{B}{x}{y}$
\end{document}
```

I have omitted the `\...ref` macros that are better managed with `cleveref`.

As you see, it's only a collection of dubiously useful macros.

Main errors in `commath`: the definitions of `\dif` and `\Dif` are plainly wrong. The usage of `\ifinner` is completely wrong; what the author intends to do by `\ifinner` with `\tfrac` and `\dfrac` is already done (better) by the standard `\frac` macro.

The "delimiters" macros are wrong in that they use by default `\left` and `\right`, which is disputable; I've left them as in the original, but defining them in terms of a generic macro.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the rendering of \pd{f}{x} or \od{f}{x}, there seems to be a bigger horizontal space between \partial and f in the numerator, than there is between \partial and x in the denominator. Is that due to the "empty" superscript?

Comment: @Michael I added the check that the argument is empty

Comment: I'm supposed to avoid such comments, but anyway thanks.

Comment: There's a problem in the `\eval` (and in general, when someone uses `.` in `\genericdel`) in the “base” height. There should be a check to see if the `#1` or `#2` are equal to `.`, and, in that case, gobble it.

Comment: I think this should be released on CTAN in replacement of `commath`.

Comment: @HélitonMartins Actually, I'm not keen on packages that are just collections of macros, which are frequently just a cause of name conflicts.

Comment: @egreg Yeah, it makes sense. But, as a user, I usually prefer `\usepackage{anything}` than copy-pasting the same macros everywhere. In that respect, `commath` makes sense to me. Anyway, I'm gonna replace `commath.sty` code on my machine with yours, so thanks for that!