# Conditional branch with \ifinner and Spacing in higher derivative (2 independent questions)

Tags: spacing, macros, conditionals, typography, math-operators

I made some macros shown below, which outputs ordinary/partial derivative. I was checking whether they work as I expected, and found that `\dif{y}{x}` expands to `\tfrac{\difd y}{\difd x}` in `align` environment.
I want to use `\tfrac` only in sentences, not in any display math modes. How should I change the definition in order to expands `\dif{y}{x}` to `\dfrac{\difd y}{\difd x}` in `align` environment, `gather` environment and so on?

I have another question. I think higher derivatives written with my command (especially partial ones) make a little much space before f.
In terms of mathematical typography, which is proper: `\frac{〈operator〉^{#1}#2}{〈operator〉#3^{#1}}` or `\frac{〈operator〉^{#1}\!#2}{〈operator〉#3^{#1}}`?

[image: example of higher derivatives]

EDIT (June 13, 2015 at 23:28 JST):
The first question has been settled.

EDIT (June 15, 2015 at 14:21 JST):
As David Carlisle points out, my question was a duplicate of [commath and \ifinner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner) and `commath` package should not be used. Then, I have another question. In the linked page, there is a macro named `\spx`, the definition of which is in the below. Since we can see `{^{#1}}` in the definition, it seems to be an improved `^`. What is the difference between this `\spx` and `\^` and which should I use, "`\(p)dif@nth` and `\@(p)dif`" or "`\spx` without `\@ifnextchar`"?

**My macros**

```
% ----- differential operator -----
\def\difd@rm{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}\mathstrut}
\def\difd@it{\mathop{d\!}\mathstrut}
\def\makedifdrm{\let\difd=\difd@rm}
\def\makedifdit{\let\difd=\difd@it}
\makedifdit % default setting
%
% ----- ordinary derivative -----
\def\dif{\@ifnextchar[\dif@nth\@dif}
\def\dif@nth[#1]#2#3{
    \ifinner
    \tfrac{\difd^{#1}#2}{\difd#3^{#1}}
    \else
    \dfrac{\difd^{#1}#2}{\difd#3^{#1}}
    \fi
}
\def\@dif#1#2{
    \ifinner
    \tfrac{\difd#1}{\difd#2}
    \else
    \dfrac{\difd#1}{\difd#2}
    \fi
}
%
% ----- partial derivative -----
\def\pdif{\@ifnextchar[\pdif@nth\@pdif}
\def\pdif@nth[#1]#2#3{
    \ifinner
    \tfrac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial#3^{#1}}
    \else
    \dfrac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial#3^{#1}}
    \fi
}
\def\@pdif#1#2{
    \ifinner
    \tfrac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}
    \else
    \dfrac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}
    \fi
}
```

**Definition of `\spx` and its usage**

```
\newcommand{\spx}[1]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \expandafter\@gobble
    \else
        \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
    {^{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\pd[3][]{\frac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}
```

Comment: just use `\frac` !! the default is to switch styles, `\tfrac` is to force text style and `\dfrac` is to force display style. Not test is needed.

Comment: `\ifinner` is unrelated to the display/text style distinction. Are these macros based on the ones from `commath` which have similar tests?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I copied from `commath.sty` and arranged it. I suppose `\frac` in display math mode, in some cases, could be text style (though I cannot take an example immediately). I want to avoid that.

Comment: I would not copy any of the macros in there, it is telling that I recognised the style just from the error you are asking about in your question.

Comment: there is no case where `\ifinner` does anything useful here.

Comment: I just copied the macros without adequate knowledge of `\ifinner`'s function in `commath` package. I'm going to read the linked page and try to understand what `\ifinner` actually does.

Comment: The use of `\ifinner` in commath is simply an error.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it in another thread.

Comment: @egreg sorry, I made a new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive `\over` as used by `\frac` automatically switches styles. The `\tfrac` and `\dfrac` macros are for special cases to force text or display style. `\ifinner` does not test for text/display distinction so the solution is simple, replace all

```
\ifinner
\tfrac{..}{..}
\else
\dfrac{..}{..}
\fi
```

by

```
\frac{..}{..}
```

---

For your second question, I wouldn't use the negative spacing, certainly your image shows `\!` is too much, you can almost get away with it with `f` but other characters won't fit under the superscript so well.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your answer for the second quesiton. I tried `\(p)dif[2]{y}{x}` and realized the problem is a matter of the glyph of "f" itself rather than that of spacing.