# Angle brackets with commath and Asana Math too large (or small)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, luatex, unicode-math

I want to set bra-ket equations in my document, which uses Asana Math (with lualatex, fontspec and unicode-math). commath is also a requirement for certain stuff. However, in this specific combination, angle brackets are not properly scaled with some modifiers like `\big` etc.

Consider this MWE

```
%!TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
% math typesetting (differentials etc.)
\usepackage{commath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \bigl\langle x \big\vert H \big\vert y \bigr\rangle
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which produces this result

[image: Too large angle brackets]

The angle brackets are much too large compared to the equally set `\vert`. Furthermore, going through all sizes from `\big` to `\Bigg` produces some matching and some non-matching variants.

What works to avoid the problem:

- using other brackets
- deactivating commath
- switching from Asana Math to default math font

Unfortunately, neither is an option for me. `\big` is the smallest modifier and already too large. Skipping it produces too small angle brackets.

Is there any (decent) way, to get angle brackets between normal size and `\big` size with my package requirements?

Comment: Avoid using `commath`; it is very buggy. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner

Comment: You didn't like `\left\langle x \big\vert H \big\vert y \right\rangle`?

Comment: Using `\left` and `\right` produces the identical (wrong) result for me. The detection obviously wants to use `\big` brackets there.

Comment: @egreg: Okay, from what you write there it sounds as if I should rather consider dropping commath, right? I originally wanted it for the `\dif` macro (need to check if I use anything else). Is there a good alternative package for that?

Comment: The `\dif` command is wrongly defined. You're better served by `\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!d}` (the package has `\!` on the wrong side).

Comment: Okay, taking your definition of `\dif` makes commath dispensable. All good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `commath.sty` is loaded `\bigl` produces a much bigger size than when it's not loaded. Doing `\tracingall` and comparing differences essentially just shows

```
< \hbox(8.35597+2.93596)x4.22 []}
---
> \hbox(12.92+7.5)x4.55 []}
```

which accounts for the different heights, but not for the cause.

Since `commath` is *very* buggy, I suggest you not to load it; see [commath and \ifinner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner)

If you just need its `\dif` command, define it in the right way and forget about the package, which defines it in a very wrong way, that can be seen by trying `\dif(x+y)`:

```
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

(I'd prefer an italic ‘d’, but it's an opinion).