# \lmoustache and \rmoustache manifesting as weird cropped "tails"

Tags: math-mode, input-encodings

I was just working on my `LaTeX` skills so I don't forget, so I went on [this](https://mathvault.ca/latex-professional-typesetting-scientific-publishing-avoid-traditional-word-processors/) site and started replicating the most complex stuff I found. At first I thought it would be a piece of cake, but then I wrote this code and was absolutely perplexed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}

\[
\iiiint \limits_{\mathcal{Q}} f(w,x,y,z) \; \mathrm{d}w \; \mathrm{d}x \; \mathrm{d}y \; \mathrm{d}z \leq \oint_{\partial Q} f' \left( \max \left\{ \frac{\norm{w}}{|w^2 + x^2|} ; \frac{\norm{z}}{|y^2 + z^2|} ; \frac{\norm{w \oplus z}}{\norm{x \oplus y}} \right\} \right) \precapprox \biguplus_{\mathbb{Q} \Subset \bar{Q}} \left[ f^* \left( \frac{\lmoustache \mathbb{Q}(t)\rmoustache}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}} \right) \right]^{t=9}_{t=\alpha}
\]

\end{document}
```

At the first glance everything seems normal, but if you carefully look inspect the end of the line (the part with `Q(t)`) you figure out that the `\lmoustache` and `\rmoustache` are cropped out, disfigured. Here is a picture supporting my description.

[image]

I removed all of the non-vital packages so I made sure there was no redefinition issue or a clash of packages. Then, I tried to check if it wasn't an encoding problem by scaling `\lmoustache` and `\rmoustache` down with `\scalebox`. The result was the same, just a smaller "tail". So I am curious how to slove this problem and make my compilation identical to that included in the cited site.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use `commath`

Comment: What would you use to get a similar result?

Comment: As far as I can see, you're using just `\norm` from `commath`. There are much better ways for defining it, see the documentation of `mathtools`. By the way, you should do `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` and use `\diff x` rather than `\;\mathrm{d}x`

Comment: Thank you for additional information. They really are a treasure when writing a PhD. Any advice on the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the delimiters from another font family, I chose `stix`.

I also add some improvements, particularly `\diff` for the differential and omitting `commath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}

%% moustaches from STIX
\let\lmoustache\relax \let\rmoustache\relax
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{stixlargesymbols}{bold}{LS2}{stixex}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lmoustache}{\mathopen} {stixlargesymbols}{"E6}{stixlargesymbols}{"EC}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rmoustache}{\mathclose}{stixlargesymbols}{"E7}{stixlargesymbols}{"ED}

%% \abs and \norm
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

%% differential
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\iiiint_{\mathcal{Q}} f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z 
&\leq 
\oint_{\partial Q} f'
  \left(
    \max \left\{ \frac{\norm{w}}{\abs{w^2 + x^2}} ; 
    \frac{\norm{z}}{\abs{y^2 + z^2}} ;
    \frac{\norm{w \oplus z}}{\norm{x \oplus y}} \right\}
  \right)
\\
&\precapprox
\biguplus_{\mathbb{Q} \Subset \bar{Q}}
  \left[ f^* \left(
    \frac{\lmoustache \mathbb{Q}(t)\rmoustache}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}
  \right) \right]^{t=9}_{t=\alpha}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\left\lmoustache\frac{a}{b}\right\rmoustache
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

About not using `commath`, see

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135985/4427

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123408/4427

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265987/4427

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325341/4427

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297273/4427

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89470/4427

Comment: Wow, thank you. I wanted to ask how to accomodate the `moustache` height, but you answered before I could even pose my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice! But how did you figure out which codes to use (E6/E7/EC/ED)?

Comment: @Clément `texdoc stix2` has a table of codes.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot!  Oh, and searching around, I saw that unicode-math-table.tex also does.

Answer (score 4):

the moustache are not really fully defined symbols they are just re-constructed bits of large braces, so are only available in large sizes, not normal size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\lmoustache Q \rmoustache
\left\lmoustache Q \right\rmoustache
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am quite uncomfortable with Texstudio's tags being so misleading. All of my praise to you, kind sir.

Comment: @GregorPerčič I have no idea what a texstudio tag is I don't use that editor. some kind of help system?

Comment: Yes, it displays the most commonly used symbols and their `unicode` equivalent. That's why I think a fully displayed `moustache` and a mismatching command is a misledaing thing. By the way, which editor do you use?

Comment: I have always used emacs

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will surely consider using it (since it suffices for such a veteran as you are).