# Incompatibility between commath and babel packages

Tags: errors, babel, incompatibility, commath

When writing a semicolon in math mode while using `commath` and `babel`, like in the following code, the PDF does not compile and outputs a timeout error.

I reduced my preamble and my code as much as I could, in order to isolate the problem. Anyone knows what causes this issue and how to fix it ?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}

$:$

\end{document}
```

Comment: My guess would be that `commath` somehow makes the `:` active in math mode and that causes havoc with `babel-french`, which also wants to make `:` active.

Comment: I'd probably look into dropping `commath`: The active colon makes me a bit uneasy. (Similar) issues with `commath` and comments: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89467/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135944/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380799/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123407/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261265/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324998/35864