# stmaryrd & babel incompatibility

Tags: babel, babel-french, stmaryrd, commath

I am having a bug: when I want to use both stmaryrd for `\llbracket` and french babel in some `book` I am writing, compilation never ends. Happens on my local machine and on Overleaf.

Here is some MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

%General setup
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{import}
%Custom style
\renewcommand{\partname}{Partie}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Sommaire}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Thème}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\title{My title}
\date{Today}
\author{Kal} 


\begin{document}

\maketitle
 
\newpage 
 
\begin{center}\Large
\textit{Préambule}
\end{center}

\bigskip 
    
\begin{equation*}
\forall k \in \llbracket 1 : N \rrbracket, \: i_k = \frac{G_k}{\sum\limits_{l=1}^N G_l} i
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I tried everything, and the only thing I can tell you is that commenting the babel import on the MWE does the trick and gets it to compile. However, I cannot do this in the whole document. I am really stuck, especially without any error message...

Comment: the problem is the commath package, and if you search on the site you will find a number of questions reporting problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Ulrike, this is not a conflict between `stmaryrd` and `babel-french`, but between `commath` and `babel-french`. See
[Incompatibility between commath and babel packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540687)

The `commath` makes the colon active, this conflicts with `babel-french` also making it active.  As `commath` doesn't seem to be maintained (last update 2006), I could suggest to comment out lines 281-286 in `commath.sty`.  If `:=` needs to be patched in math mode (that's the *only purpose* of making the colon active), there are alternatives (`mathtools.sty` f.i.).

A cleaner solution would be to pick up the commands you really need in `commath.sty`, to add them to your preambule (or to a personal style file) and to drop the call to `commath.sty`.

B.t.w, I would suggest to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as recommended by `babel-french` and also `\usepackage{lmodern}` to get the Latin Modern fonts instead of the "cm-super" fonts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was miles away from even imagining that the problem could be the : and not a command such as \llbracket ! Hence I did not make enough test to conclude about this incompatibility by myself. Lesson learned on that ! Also thanks for your detailed explanation and advice, which I'll follow.