# Using superscipt in argument of \dpd of commath package

Tags: symbols

I am using the commath package to typeset derivatives and need to use a superscript in the argument supplied to \dpd. What I require is something like

```
\begin{equation}
    \dpd{}{X^{(j)}_0} f(X^{(j)}_0)
\end{equation}
```

but this does not compile. There is no problem with subscripts as

```
\begin{equation}
    \dpd{}{X_0} f(X^{(j)}_0)
\end{equation}
```

does compile. Does anyone know of a workaround?

(Note sure  about the tag used - perhaps someone can suggest something more appropriate?)

Comment: I realise one may use $\frac{\partial}{\partial X^{(j)}_0} f(X^{(j)}_0)$ but I would like to know if it can be done within the \dpd environment.

Comment: I have not used `commath` package and think it was because there were some issues with it. I haven't found where I thought I read a recommendation to _not_ use this package, but perhaps you should look at this question and the comments and answer: [commath and \ifinner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner). Just an FYI.

Comment: @Petter Grill I have noticed that the \pd (and \od) environment does a poor job of automatically determining whether a displayed or inline equation is required, but this can be overcome by specifying this manually as \tpd or \dpd etc.

Comment: really I wouldn't use commath, so many of its macros are incorrect.

Comment: @David Carlisle yeah, I see your point. I wish I had used a macro to define the derivatives - a lot quicker to change than going step by step through the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please observe additional parentheses in the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \dpd{}{{X^{(j)}_0}} f(X^{(j)}_0)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, this package seems to be abandoned. As we cannot expect correcting its bugs, I wouldn't recommend using its macros.

Comment: Do you know which is the best alternative?

Comment: @Freakalien It is easy to write your  own macros, remembering about potential double superscript, e.g. `\def\dpd#1#2{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}{#1}}{\mathrm{d}{#2}}}`.