# \eval does not scale its argument properly

Tags: scaling, commath

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14822/106612) a user suggested to use the `commath` package to separate presentation and content. I LOVE separating presentation and content, so I read the documentation and started using this package throughout my work.

Sadly, I noticed that one of the more frequently used macros - `\pd` (partial derivative) - produces very ugly result compared to plain old `\frac` with `\partial`:
[image: Top: \eval, bottom: \frac]

```
\begin{equation}
\eval{\pd{\hat{\boldsymbol{a}}_\text{c}}{\xi}}_{\xi = 0} =
42
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{a}}_\text{c}}{\partial \xi}\sVert[3]_{\xi = 0} =
42
\end{equation}
```

(Actually this example, although MWE, is not illustrative enough, so here's another couple: `\eval`

[image: \eval]

vs `\frac`

[image: \frac]

). I use updated TeXLive2016.

So, the questions are (1) am I doing something wrong, because there is no way this is intended typesetting style, and (2) if `commath` actually IS broken and unmaintained (hey, it's still at v0.3 which is 10 years old), can you suggest another similar package.

Comment: unfortunately commath is just completely broken, almost every definition in the package is incorrect.

Comment: Did you bother reading the comments on the answer you linked to?

Comment: [I wouldn't recommend commath in any case: it's just a collection of poorly written macros (see the definition of \pd to see what I mean).](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator/14822#comment40447_14822)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I'm a little bit oligophrenic since the brokenness of `commath` is indeed discussed under the very answer I linked to (deep thanks @cfr). I'll try my luck with [`cool`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cool/).

[EDIT] I tried `cool` and that's the stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The `\eval` macro puts its contents in the argument to `\mathinner`. On the other hand, `\pd` does `\tfrac` when `\ifinner` returns true and `\dfrac` when `\ifinner` returns false.

Now, here's the problem in the form of a simple plain TeX file:

```
$$
\mathinner{\ifinner a\else b\fi}
$$
\bye
```

If we run `pdftex` on it, the output shows “a” and not “b”. In other words, `\ifinner` returns true when a subformula in `\mathinner` is typeset.

This is the reason why you get a small fraction.

I'm sorry to say again that `commath` is irremediably broken. If you need to keep the syntax, you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135985/4427

An unabridged version, with only the macros for your code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spx}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {^{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\pd[3][]{\frac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}

\newcommand{\genericdel}[4]{%
  \ifcase#3\relax
  \ifx#1.\else#1\fi#4\ifx#2.\else#2\fi\or
  \bigl#1#4\bigr#2\or
  \Bigl#1#4\Bigr#2\or
  \biggl#1#4\biggr#2\or
  \Biggl#1#4\Biggr#2\else
  \left#1#4\right#2\fi
}

\newcommand{\eval}[2][-1]{\genericdel.|{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\sVert}[1][0]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
  \rvert\or\bigr|\or\Bigr|\or\biggr|\or\Biggr
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\eval{\pd{\hat{\boldsymbol{a}}_\text{c}}{\xi}}_{\xi = 0} =
42
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{a}}_\text{c}}{\partial \xi}\sVert[3]_{\xi = 0} =
42
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are incredible. You actually went and spent quite a bit of your time to give a great, detailed, illustrative answer to my obtuse question. Thanks a *lot*.