# How to properly insert Ɐ (2C6F) or any undefined unicode

Tags: math-mode, unicode

using xelatex I tried this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\Vol}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath{A}}}

\begin{document}
\Vol
\end{document}
```

I know there is `\forall` but that's obviously not the answer.
But the problem is when I try to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Vol}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath{A}}}
\begin{document}
$E_v=-\frac{\dif p}{\frac{\dif \Vol}{\Vol}}$
\end{document}
```

differential operator and volume get different size:

[image: differential operator and volume get different size.]

Comment: Don't use `commath`, it is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution is based on `\mathpalette` that allows the detection of the current math style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vol}{%
  \mathpalette\@Vol{}%
}
\newcommand*{\@Vol}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\m@th#1A$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$E_v=-\frac{\dif p}{\frac{\dif \Vol}{\Vol}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The following variant uses `\text` from package `amsmath` or `amstext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Vol}{%
  \text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\m@th A$}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$E_v=-\frac{\dif p}{\frac{\dif \Vol}{\Vol}}$
\end{document}
```

In both cases, `\m@th` ensures that `\mathsurround` is zero to avoid additional space around the math symbol, when math is set in the text box.

Answer (score 2):

A variant of Heiko’s solution, mainly to warn about not using `commath`; see

- [commath and \ifinner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner)
- [Spacing after derivative operator in the commath package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123407/spacing-after-derivative-operator-in-the-commath-package)
- [\eval does not scale its argument properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324998/eval-does-not-scale-its-argument-properly)

for some examples why.

I also add `\newunicodechar` so you can input the character directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\reverseletter}[1]{\mathpalette\reverse@letter{#1}}
\newcommand{\reverse@letter}[2]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Vol}{\reverseletter{A}}
\newunicodechar{Ɐ}{\Vol}

\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % much better than commath's

\begin{document}

$E_v=-\frac{\dif p}{\frac{\dif \Vol}{\Vol}}$

$E_v=-\frac{\dif p}{\frac{\dif Ɐ}{Ɐ}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]