# Math macro for typesetting partial derivative with variable placeholder for both numerator and denominator

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators, xparse

I'd like to type time-derivatives such as `$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = f(x,t) $` as well as spatial gradients such as `$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = k y $`

To make the code readable and to avoid typing `\partial` repeatedly, I found a macro `\pder` (which I have in my preamble) that uses the `xparse` package

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\pder}{ O{} O{} m }{\frac{\partial^{#2}#1}{\partial#3^{#2}}}
```

However, `\pder{t}{x}` produces outputs like

[image: time_derivative]

rather than the desired output produced by `\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}` which is

[image: correct_typeset_partial_time_derivative]

How can I declare a math macro that accepts variables for numerator and denominator but does not leave a space in between?

PS: I have no clue why Tex.SX does not render the typed content within $..$. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, please let me know and I shall fix it.

Comment: using `$` within the web page is mathjax syntax, which is not enabled on this site

Comment: That sounds a bit silly to me on the part of site deployment. This is a math-heavy site. In the absence of this feature, how can one effectively convey math-typesetting issues

Comment: @Krishna We're interested in TeX code, not in the approximate rendering made by MathJax.

Comment: It is because it is a TeX site that mathjax is disabled, we need to see tex output not javascript otherwise it just leads to confusion.

Comment: Khan Academies KaTeX supports true latex (well, a subset for now), but with a growing number of ligatures as the project matures and is starting to rival the approximate rendering by mathjax. Maybe we can look into it for this site?

Comment: @Krishna no that is also javascript this site is about tex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel: there already the `esdiff` package which eases typesetting derivatives in Leibniz' notation (partial or nonpartial). In addition, it can automatically determine the order of derivation for crossed derivatives, and takes care of the evaluation point:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}

 \begin{document}

\[ \diffp*{u}{t}{\mkern2mu t = 0}\qquad \diffp{u}{t x}\qquad \diffp{u}{{t^2}x} \]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about its existence!!

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are there more such nifty packages that relieve the burden of typing a math-heavy PhD thesis?

Comment: To my knowledge, there are `physics` and `commath` (they're rather physics-oriented) and a number of specialised  packages, not specifically made to simplify typing, but offering all-in-one solutions for specific constructions (e.g. `tikz-cd` for commutative diagrams). To be noted: the author of `esdiff` offers very nice (extensible) arrows for vectors in `esvect`.

Comment: @Bernard eek please don't recommend commath,

Comment: @David Carlisle: Actually, I only mentioned it, as I've never used it. Does it have bugs?

Comment: @Bernard how could I put it politely.... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner/135985#comment307327_135944

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I see… Furthermore, for derivatives,  esdiff is simpler to use.

Comment: @Bernard I just discovered the amazing ```diffcoeff``` package. The author covers every imaginable scenario in typesetting derivatives & lists other competing packages & their capabilities. Page 14 of the [manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/diffcoeff/diffcoeff.pdf), : "esdiff comes closest but failed when it came
to combining algebraic and numeric orders of differentation in a mixed partial
derivative. Also the need to em-brace variables in a mixed partial derivative in
esdiff was another (small) count against it".  There is also a ```diffcoeffx``` package.

Comment: @Krishna: I've taken a look at this package, which I seem to have overlooked when it was out. Very, very interesting indeed! I've installed it, and I'll test it more thoroughly in the coming days.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. I am presently using it for my PhD thesis.   I am a newbie in typography to detect issues deftly and so, please let me know if you find any issues with it.

Answer (score 5):

your `\pder` only takes one mandatory argument so you have `\pder{t}`  and then `{x}` later with unused brace group

define it with two arguments

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\pder}{ O{} O{} m m}%
  {\frac{\partial^{#2}#1#4}{\partial#3^{#2}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It can count the differentiations.

```
\documentclass[17pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{pdiff@total}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\linefrac{mm}
 {\left.#1\middle\slash{#2}\right.}

\NewDocumentCommand\pdiff{s o >{\SplitList{,}} m}%
 {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\let\@tempa\linefrac}{\let\@tempa\frac}%
  \setcounter{pdiff@total}{0}%
  \ProcessList{#3}{\pdiff@c}%
  \@tempa%
   {\partial \ifnum\thepdiff@total >1\relax ^{\arabic{pdiff@total}} \fi%
     \IfValueT{#2}{#2}}%
   {\ProcessList{#3}{\pdiff@vars}}}

\NewDocumentCommand\pdiff@c{> { \SplitArgument { 1 } { * } } m}{\@pdiff@c#1}

\NewDocumentCommand\@pdiff@c{m G{1}}{\addtocounter{pdiff@total}{#2}}

\NewDocumentCommand\pdiff@vars{> { \SplitArgument { 1 } { * } } m}{\@pdiff@vars#1}

\NewDocumentCommand\@pdiff@vars{m g}{\mathinner{\partial #1 \IfValueT{#2}{^ {#2}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \pdiff{x} \quad \pdiff[f(x)]{x*2,y*95,z*4} \quad \pdiff*[f(\vec r)]{\vec r*5}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Partial differentiation]