# Aligned equation doesnt align properly

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

[image]
Hi there. I try to simply align an equation but either way I try to do it, it doesnt look nice. In the first case there is no space behind the equal sign (clearly I can make some space there but I dont think this is the preferred way) and in the second case the 'p's are not aligned. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,commath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 &p((p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}(\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2+r_1^pr_2^{2q}-4\abs{z_{n+1}}^2(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}+2r_1^{p-1}r_2^{2q}(z_1+\overline{z}_1))\\
 =&p(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}((\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2-4\abs{z_{n+1}})
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 &\phantom{=}p((p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}(\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2+r_1^pr_2^{2q}-4\abs{z_{n+1}}^2(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}+2r_1^{p-1}r_2^{2q}(z_1+\overline{z}_1))\\
 &=p(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}((\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2-4\abs{z_{n+1}})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of these codes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}%,commath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 &p((p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}(\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2+r_1^pr_2^{2q}-4\abs{z_{n+1}}^2(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}+2r_1^{p-1}r_2^{2q}(z_1+\overline{z}_1))\\
={}&p(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}((\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2-4\abs{z_{n+1}})
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 &\phantom{{}={}}p((p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}(\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2+r_1^pr_2^{2q}-4\abs{z_{n+1}}^2(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}+2r_1^{p-1}r_2^{2q}(z_1+\overline{z}_1))\\
 &=p(p-1)r_1^{p-2}r_2^{2q}((\overline{z}_1-z_1)^2-4\abs{z_{n+1}})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This also saves the commath package I only used for abs.

Comment: Sadly I use the commath package for $\mathbb{1}$ also...:(

Comment: @LukeMathwalker I would beware loading the `commath` package at all  (it does not define `\mathbb` though)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right! I use the $\norm$ command from commath. Can one express the norm like Bernard did?

Comment: @LukeMathwalker you mean with || instead of |? just use `\lVert` instead of `lvert`, the definitions in commath are mostly wrong unfortunately. See multiple comments on this site eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner#comment307327_135944

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I had trouble with commath, too. The \lVert works perfectly! Thanks a lot.