# Fractional alignment

Tags: fractions, commath

So I have this basic code:

But the fractional alignment looks awful, any tips to fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs, eufrak}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{commath}
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}


\begin{document}

Let $h$ be a linear mapping of $V_1$ into $V_2$. Let
\[
h^0 = \frac{1}{\abs G} \sum_{t\in G} (\rho_t^2)^{-1} h \rho_t^1
\]
where $\abs G$ is the order of $G$. Then
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item If $\rho^1$ and $\rho^2$ are not isomorphic then we have $h^0=0$
\item If $V_1 = V_2$ and $\rho^1 = \rho^2$, $h^0$ is a scalar multiple of the identity, the scalar being $\frac{1}{n} Tr(h)$ where $n = \dim(V_1)$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

as you notice, it looks awful.

Comment: I mean, can the |G| be pushed a little to the right? since the vertical "bars" and not aligned with the horizontal fractional line?

Comment: You can always add space to it: `\,\abs G`.

Comment: aha, cheers pal :)

Comment: I'll close this question since its trivial. I wasn't thinking aha

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it deserves closure. This is a good question and my solution is only a workaround - it is not 100% centered. Maybe some TeXperts out there will provide a good answer.

Comment: @JouleV I agree, the question shouldn't be closed. It's definitely a bug (feature?) in `commath`.

Comment: `\frac{1}{|G|}` does not experience the same problem.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135985/4427, if you really want to use `commath` macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `commath` package provides a highly questionable implementation of `\abs`. Don't load this package unless you absolutely have to. (Aside: You do *not* have to for the example at hand.)

Instead of loading this package, I suggest you

- load the `mathtools` package instead of the `amsmath` package. The `mathtools` package is, for all intents and purposes, a superset of the `amsmath` package; and
- issue the instruction

  ```
  \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
  ```

  in the preamble. This sets up a proper implementation of `\abs{...}`. If you need to auto-size the vertical bars, simply use `\abs*{...}`.

---

*Addendum": More about how `commath` implements `\envert` (`\abs` is just an alias for `\envert`): If `\envert{<arg>}` is invoked *without* an optional sizing argument (a whole number between `0` and `4`), the following code gets executed:

```
 \!\left\lvert#2\right\rvert
```

It's the `\!` ("negative thinspace") instruction that messes up the symmetry of the full expression. Either write `\abs[0]{<arg>}` to execute `\lvert#2\rvert` or, more safely, don't load `commath` at all and go for a cleaner definition of `\abs`. The definitions of `\abs[1]{...}` thru `\abs[4]{...}` are also messed up, by the way, as are the definitions of `\norm` and `\norm[1]` thru `\norm]4]`. While it's *possible*, in principle, to correct the faulty definitions of `\envert`, `\abs`, `\enVert`, and `\norm`, one is better off going for a setup that avoids these complications...

Comment: So I should remove the amsath package and insert the mathtools package? would this affect the remaining document consisting of 40-50 pages? if not then I'll change it since you have much more experience.

Comment: @Maths - The `mathtools` package automatically loads the `amsmath` package, while taking great care not to mess with the operational details of the macros.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the output of

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{commath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\begin{document}

Let $h$ be a linear mapping of $V_1$ into $V_2$. Let
\[
h^0 = \frac{1}{\abs G} \sum_{t\in G} (\rho_t^2)^{-1} h \rho_t^1
\]
where $\abs G$ is the order of $G$. Then
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item If $\rho^1$ and $\rho^2$ are not isomorphic then we have $h^0=0$
\item If $V_1 = V_2$ and $\rho^1 = \rho^2$, $h^0$ is a scalar multiple of the identity,
      the scalar being $\frac{1}{n} \Tr(h)$ where $n = \dim(V_1)$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

with the output of

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
% begin definitions for a "better commath"

\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{D}}

\newcommand{\spx}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {^{#1}}%
}

\newcommand\pd[3][]{\frac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand\tpd[3][]{\tfrac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand\dpd[3][]{\dfrac{\partial\spx{#1}#2}{\partial#3\spx{#1}}}

\newcommand{\md}[6]{\frac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}
\newcommand{\tmd}[6]{\tfrac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}
\newcommand{\dmd}[6]{\dfrac{\partial\spx{#2}#1}{\partial#3\spx{#4}\partial#5\spx{#6}}}

\newcommand{\od}[3][]{\frac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tod}[3][]{\tfrac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}
\newcommand{\dod}[3][]{\dfrac{\dif\spx{#1}#2}{\dif#3\spx{#1}}}

\newcommand{\genericdel}[4]{%
  \ifcase#3\relax
  \ifx#1.\else#1\fi#4\ifx#2.\else#2\fi\or
  \bigl#1#4\bigr#2\or
  \Bigl#1#4\Bigr#2\or
  \biggl#1#4\biggr#2\or
  \Biggl#1#4\Biggr#2\else
  \left#1#4\right#2\fi
}
\newcommand{\del}[2][-1]{\genericdel(){#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\set}[2][-1]{\genericdel\{\}{#1}{#2}}
\let\cbr\set
\newcommand{\sbr}[2][-1]{\genericdel[]{#1}{#2}}
\let\intoo\del
\let\intcc\sbr
\newcommand{\intoc}[2][-1]{\genericdel(]{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\intco}[2][-1]{\genericdel[){#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\eval}[2][-1]{\genericdel.|{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\envert}[2][-1]{\genericdel||{#1}{#2}}
\let\abs\envert
\newcommand{\sVert}[1][0]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
  \rvert\or\bigr|\or\Bigr|\or\biggr|\or\Biggr
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\enVert}[2][-1]{\genericdel\|\|{#1}{#2}}
\let\norm\enVert
\newcommand{\fullfunction}[5]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}r@{}c@{}l@{}}
  #1 \colon & #2 & {}\longrightarrow{} & #3 \\
            & #4 & {}\longmapsto{}     & #5
  \end{array}
}
%%% end of the definitions
\makeatother


\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\begin{document}

Let $h$ be a linear mapping of $V_1$ into $V_2$. Let
\[
h^0 = \frac{1}{\abs G} \sum_{t\in G} (\rho_t^2)^{-1} h \rho_t^1
\]
where $\abs G$ is the order of $G$. Then
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item If $\rho^1$ and $\rho^2$ are not isomorphic then we have $h^0=0$
\item If $V_1 = V_2$ and $\rho^1 = \rho^2$, $h^0$ is a scalar multiple of the identity, 
      the scalar being $\frac{1}{n} \Tr(h)$ where $n = \dim(V_1)$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The code has already been presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135985/4427 and provides a full replacement of `commath`, avoiding all its weaknesses. If you're tied to `commath` because you use its macros and features in other places, this can save you. Otherwise define `\abs` with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` as suggested by Mico.

For instance, you can notice the reduced space between “where” and “|*G*|” in the `commath` version.

[image]

You should define anyway an operator name for “Tr”.

If you decide to go for this, save the part between

```
% begin definitions for a "better commath"
```

and

```
% end of the definitions
```

in a file called `bettercommath.sty` in the working directory and do `\usepackage{bettercommath}`.