# What is the correct way to type partial derivative in a parameter using \pd in commath package?

Tags: parameters, commath

I'm using *\pd{ }{ }* in the commath package to type the partial derivative which saves lots of efforts than typing *\frac{\partial }{\partial }*. However when I want to have a pair of parameters around the partial derivatives, say

```
\begin{equation}
\left(\pd{(f\circ g)}{x_{2i-1}}\right)
\end{equation}
```

the fraction just shrinks automatically, giving a result like this:

[image]

This is simply too ugly if I at the same time have a partial derivative at the normal size, for example

```
\begin{equation}
\pd{(f\circ g)}{z_i}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\pd{(f\circ g)}{x_{2i-1}}-\sqrt{-1}\pd{(f\circ g)}{x_{2i}}}\right)
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I tried the command *\del[ ]{ }*, which is the command in commath package that gives parameters in custom sizes, to generate my parameters, but the partial derivative still shrinks.

Is there any solution to this situation, without abandoning the usage of *\pd{ }{ }*?

I thanks in advance for any possible help.

Comment: before using the commath package you might want to search this site for answers refering to it, it has many issues. The behaviour you show is due to the fact that almost every definition in the package is based on a misunderstanding of `\mathinner`

Comment: egreg gives a set of definitions to replace that package, including a better `\pd`  here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135944/commath-and-ifinner/135985#135985

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! But it seems that those definitions disable the package href, I get errors saying that commands like *\propref{ }* are not defined. Do you have any clue of that?

Comment: see egreg's comment in that post: I have omitted the \...ref macros that are better managed with cleveref.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. It took me some efforts to find out how to use cleveref for *\newtcbtheorem*, but everything works fine now so I'm really happy.

Comment: glad you got it working.