# Relational Operator spacing problem with alignat

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

I have not asked a really embarrassing question in a while, so thought it was time :-). I am stumped as to why the spacing around the `=` on the third line is incorrect:

[image]

### Notes:

- I realize I am cheating a bit on the second line, but I don't mind that the equation starts a bit on the left.
- The absolute value is from [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols), but is *not* relevant to this problem.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%

%% ----- Not relevant for this example
%% Swap the definition of \abs* and \norm*, so that \abs
%% and \norm resizes the size of the brackets, and the 
%% starred version does not.
%\makeatletter
%\let\oldabs\abs
%\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
 \abs{E_T}
             &&                  {}\le \frac{K (b-a)^3}{12 n^2} &&= 0.005 \\
             &&  \frac{0.2487 (\pi)^3}{12 n^2}                  &&= 0.005 \\
    \implies &&                                            n^2  &&=128.52 \\
             &&                                            n    &&\approx 11.34
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `alignat` with 5 alignments you are using an `rl`-style alignment and, using your third row, this results in

```
       r & l &   r & l & r
\implies &   & n^2 &   & r
```

That is, both `n^2` and `=128.52` are `r`ight-aligned. Using `&&&` as the last set of alignments works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
 \abs{E_T}
             &&                  {}\le \frac{K (b-a)^3}{12 n^2} &&&= 0.005 \\
             &&  \frac{0.2487 (\pi)^3}{12 n^2}                  &&&= 0.005 \\
    \implies &&                                            n^2  &&&=128.52 \\
             &&                                            n    &&&\approx 11.34
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then why is that _not_ a problem in the last line?

Comment: The last line contains 6 "characters" (`\approx`, and `11.34`), just like the first two (`=` and `0.005`), so they line up using a `r`ight alignment.

Answer (score 2):

So much less hair pulling with a TABstack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%

%% ----- Not relevant for this example
%% Swap the definition of \abs* and \norm*, so that \abs
%% and \norm resizes the size of the brackets, and the 
%% starred version does not.
%\makeatletter
%\let\oldabs\abs
%\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}

\begin{document}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\tabularShortstack{rrl}{
 \abs{E_T}
             &                  {}\le \dfrac{K (b-a)^3}{12 n^2} =& 0.005 \\
             &  \dfrac{0.2487 (\pi)^3}{12 n^2}                  =& 0.005 \\
    \implies &                                            n^2  =&128.52 \\
             &                                            n    \approx& 11.34
}
\end{document}
```

[image]