# Uniform delimiter size

Tags: delimiters

In my preamble I have the following

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\makeatletter
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother
```

without really knowing how it works. But it does work great in most cases. But the following looks really bad

```
\norm{a} - \norm{b_{t|t}}
```

because the sizes of the delimiters are different. I therefore want to control their size manually, as in \big, \Big, etc...

Anybody know a smart way?

Comment: `\norm[\big]{…}`, for instance.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle From what I can tell by commenting it out, that seems to be what takes care of the automatic resizing.

Comment: @Bernard Tried, didn't work

Comment: @Patrick no, you define `\norm` then you save that definition as `\oldnorm` then you define `\norm` to be `oldnorm` so get back to where you were.

Comment: Apart from David Carlisle's comment: `\norm*` is supposed to be `\oldnorm` and `\norm` should expand to `\oldnorm*`... what is the starred version of the command at all? Is it automatically defined by `\DeclaredPairedDelimiter`? I am asking, because I have never used that command before

Comment: @Patrick: Sorry, I didn't notice you interverted `\norm` and `\norm*`: it's `\norm*[\big]{…}` you have to write.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've noticed, and I thought it was for enabling the "star" functionality. But really, when I only have the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` line in my preamble, then the automatic resizing functionality disappears.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See here for source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols

Comment: @Patrick: Thanks for the link, you should have provided the link in your original post perhaps ;-)

Comment: @Patrick: Personnaly, I think it's better to enable `\big` by default, but that requires twisting again the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good example why I usually discourage using `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately.

With `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}` you are defining the macro `\norm` that can be used in the following ways:

```
\norm{x}
\norm[\big]{x}
\norm[\Big]{x}
\norm[\bigg]{x}
\norm[\Bigg]{x}
\norm*{x}
```

The simple call does nothing to the size of the delimiters, the following ones with the optional argument specify the size “manually”, the last one tells TeX to use “automatic” sizing.

The trick you're using tells TeX that if you call `\norm{x}`, `\oldnorm*{x}` is executed and, when `\norm*{x}` is found, `\oldnorm{x}` is actually executed.

Here's how you *could* do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\makeatletter
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

(1) $\norm{a} - \norm{b_{t|t}}$

\bigskip

(2) $\norm*[\big]{a} - \norm*[\big]{b_{t|t}}$

\bigskip

(3) $\norm*{a} - \norm*{b_{t|t}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have no doubt whatsoever that (3) is the only correct way. The trick you're using with `\oldnorm` is simply useless: just remove it and type

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%

\begin{document}

(3) $\norm{a} - \norm{b_{t|t}}$

\end{document}
```

using the optional argument or the *-form only when they are really necessary.

This input will give the form (3) above.

Comment: My personal taste would make me choose version 2: version 3 seems too small  when you have letters with ascenders or descenders — not to speak of subscripts, and I think that within one  expression, all `\Vert`s should have, as much as is reasonable, the same height.

Comment: They have the same height; the version with `\big` around `a` would also need some horizontal space.

Comment: I agree they have the same height. Maybe adding .5mu on both sides with \big would be necessary indeed. But my opinion is that it should be \big by default: this is the most common case.