# Scaling absolute values

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

How I make in Latex the modulus, or absolute value, match the size of the expression within? I want to know what are the sizes available.

Example:

```
$$\mid\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}\mid
  = \frac{T^2 dg}{4\pi^2}$$
```

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question, I have no clue what it is you're asking

Comment: @daleif I wanna the signal `\mid`but biggest. How I make this? What are the sizes that I can choose?

Comment: What is **signal** in this context? Please provide an example

Comment: @daleif `$$\mid\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}\mid = \frac{T^2 dg}{4\pi^2}$$`in this context I wanna the `\mid` biggest to the partial derivation fit here.

Comment: Is `$$\left|\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}\right| = \frac{T^2 dg}{4\pi^2}$$` a solution to your question?

Comment: Check question http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that to add a MWE!  Also, you have asked a number of questions and some of these have received several, often extensive answers. Please consider accepting answers to some of your existing questions. You can do this by clicking on the greyed-out tick at the top left of the answer you want to accept. Generally, this should be the answer which most helped you.This helps other users identify useful answers and is the local way of saying 'thank you' to people who've assisted you.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks for help. Now it's working :)

Comment: It might also be an idea to check the context of the symbols you want to use, `\mid` is clearly not the correct symbol here as it does not scale (as it is not a fence). I even see users using `||x||` for norms which is also wrong. You might want to look up the definition of `\abs` in the `mathtools` package (it is an example of the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro)

Comment: Don't use `$$` for display maths if you are using LaTeX unless your system is at least 20 years out of date.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You might as well post that as an answer :-)

Comment: I did some fairly heavy editing of the question. I hope it did preserve the meaning.

Comment: @Johannes_B Okay, done.

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols).

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you load the `mathtools` package and define a macro called `\abs` as follows:

```
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

Then, in the body of the document, you'd write

```
\[
\abs*{\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}} = \frac{T^2 dg}{4\pi^2}
\]
```

The `*` ("star" or "asterisk") symbol after `\abs` indicates to LaTeX that the delimiter symbols (here: plain vertical bars) should be scaled vertically to the height and depth of the macro's argument.

Here's a screenshot to compare the look of the auto-sized fences (which happens to corresponds to `\bigg`) and of the look that results from choosing `\Big` manually. Speaking for myself, I have slight preference for look produced by the manually-chosen size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

auto-sized (\texttt{\textbackslash bigg}):
\[
\abs*{\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}} = \frac{T^2 dg}{4\pi^2}
\]

\bigskip
using \texttt{\textbackslash Big} directly:
\[
\abs[\Big]{\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}} = \frac{T^2 dg}{4\pi^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer. Note to self: Don't forget the star!

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
\[\left|\frac{\partial I}{\partial M}\right|
  = \frac{T^2 dg}{4\pi^2}\]
```

instead. Note that `\mid` is a relation symbol, and not appropriate here. It produces different spacing, for one.

The `\left`…`\right` construction can be used with all kinds of parentheses, brackets, and the like.

(Incidentally, replaced `$$` by [proper math delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).)

Comment: Please, no `$$`

Comment: Usage of `$$...$$` in LaTeX should be discouraged

Comment: Thanks for answering, though i agree with egreg that `$$  should be avoided. So i am still  holding back my upvote for a while :-)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen The usual reference to [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) suffices

Comment: Meta question: [Often referenced questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/)

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I edited the question again, and removed all my comments from this thread.