# Shortcuts for \lvert and \rvert? (with amsmath)

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I often use the absolute value symbol and write `\lvert x \rvert`.

But, can I somehow define something shorter like `\abs{x}`?

I want to use the `amsmath`-package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I want to use amsmath, the answers in the link uses a couple of other packages.

Comment: OK, I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: Note that `mathtools` as suggested in [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols) extends `amsmath`. In fact it loads `amsmath` itself. So you could argue that a `mathtools` solution also uses `amsmath`.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite strange you refuse loading of other packages: packages good are, says Yoda.

However, if you don't want to use abstract methods and prefer do all the work by hand, you need not even load `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\abs}{\@ifstar\star@abs\normal@abs}
\newcommand{\star@abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\newcommand{\normal@abs}[2][]{\mathopen{#1|}#2\mathclose{#1|}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$|\sin x|$ (wrong)

$\abs{\sin x}$ (right)

$\abs[\big]{\sin x}$
$\abs[\Big]{\sin x}$
$\abs[\bigg]{\sin x}$
$\abs[\Bigg]{\sin x}$
$\displaystyle\abs*{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$

\bigskip

$\abs[\big]{\sin x}_1^2$
$\abs[\Big]{\sin x}_1^2$
$\displaystyle\abs*{\frac{\sin x}{x}}_1^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't simply define a new command?

To auto-scale the bars, just use `\left` and `\right`, here some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}
\begin{document}
\[
\abs{x} \abs{\frac{y}{z}} \abs{w_{i}^{k}} \abs{\sum_{j=1}^{N}{X_{j}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! Is it also possible to auto-scale the bars with this command?

Comment: @JDoeDoe You're welcome! See my renewed answer.