# Difference between symbols for absolute value?

Tags: symbols

I know all of the following are used for showing the absolute value:

- `$\lvert x \rvert$`
- `$| x |$`
- `$\mid x \mid$`

I myself think that there is another one `\abs`; but I can't use this last one.

> What is the difference between them?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43008/4301).

Comment: The first is right, the second one can produce unexpected results, the last one is wrong.

Comment: @egreg ; (+1) Clear and concise, thank you my dear egreg.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You ask for the differences and here's an analysis for them.

First let's get rid of the last case: `\mid` is a relation symbol like `=` or `<` and TeX adds spaces around it that disqualify the command from being used for the absolute value.

The other two seem good, but the first one is better as it doesn't need precautions. The fact is that `|` is considered an ordinary symbol, whereas `\lvert` is an opening (like `[`) and `\rvert` is a closing (like `]`).

Let's compare some cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{lllll}
\text{good} &
  \lvert x\rvert\le 1 & \lvert-1\rvert=1 &
  \lvert\sin x\rvert & \log\lvert x-1\rvert \\[3ex]
\text{so and so} &
  |x|\leq 1 & |-1|=1 & |\sin x| & \log|x-1| \\[3ex]
\text{wrong} &
  \mid x\mid \leq 1 & \mid -1\mid =1 &
  \mid \sin x\mid  & \log\mid x-1\mid
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

You can see in the picture that `\lvert` and `\rvert` produces the right spacing in all cases, whereas `|...|` doesn't. Not to speak about `\mid`.

Using `|` would force you to input

```
|{-1}|
|{\sin x}|
\log\!|x-1|
```

[image]

You can *define* `\abs` as suggested in answers to [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols) but I recommend ***not*** to follow the suggestion of making `\left` and `\right` automatic, because it will most of the time choose a wrong size.

Comment: Is the spacing for log |x-1| in the first line considered correct? Personally, I find the version in the second line a lot better-looking (for that last formula only).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I consider the absolute value just like a parenthesized expression, so the top is right, but I wouldn't turn down consistent usage like in the second line.

Comment: Does "so and so" mean "acceptable"?

Comment: @Ooker It means that in some cases it's right, in others it's wrong; precisely, the first is right, the last might be acceptable (see another comment), the middle ones are plainly wrong.

Comment: Can TeX be complied like programming languages? For example in your example can I use a loop to print the `sin, log` three times with different cases?

Comment: @Ooker Yes, it wouldn't be difficult, but overkill for this example.