# Better-looking absolute signs?

Tags: math-mode, typography

There are already several questions about absolute signs, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols?noredirect=1&lq=1). My question is different in that I'm not satisfied with the typesetting of the absolute sign offered by any of the options I know about. Consider the following MWE, which illustrates the problem for the letter "G":

```
\documentclass[crop,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\myslash{\char`\\}
\begin{document}
\texttt{|G|}: $|G|$

\texttt{\myslash left G\myslash right}: $\left|G\right|$

\texttt{\myslash lvert G\myslash rvert}: $\lvert G\rvert$

\texttt{\myslash abs\{G\}}: $\abs{G}$
\end{document}
```

All four options produce absolute signs that go too far below the baseline (for my taste):

[image]

With a new command:

```
\documentclass[crop,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\myht}
\newlength{\mydp} 

\newcommand{\myabs}[1]{%
  \settoheight{\myht}{#1}%
  \settodepth{\mydp}{#1}%
  \tikz[anchor=base, baseline=0pt] \draw[line cap=round] (0pt,-\mydp-0.2pt) -- (0pt,\myht+0.3pt);%  
  $\mkern0.6mu #1\mkern1.0mu$%
  \tikz[anchor=base, baseline=0pt] \draw[line cap=round] (0pt,-\mydp-0.2pt) -- (0pt,\myht+0.3pt);%
}

\begin{document}

\myabs{G} = 2

\myabs{g} = 3

\end{document}
```

I get what I think are better-looking absolute signs:

[image]

Of course, one can quibble about some of the spacing between the absolute signs and the letters as well as the distances above and below the letters; I did not try to tune these yet.

However, this is clearly not good enough because when you typeset a scalar product, we have two absolute values side-by-side.

[image]

The only solution I can see (other than using symbols in the dot product that have similar height and depths) is to allow a user to influence the typesetting of the absolute signs, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[crop,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newlength{\myht}
\newlength{\mydp} 

\newcommand{\myabs}[3]{%
  \settoheight{\myht}{#2}%
  \settodepth{\mydp}{#3}%
  \tikz[anchor=base, baseline=0pt] \draw[line cap=round] (0pt,-\mydp-0.2pt) -- (0pt,\myht+0.3pt);%  
  \ensuremath{\mkern0.6mu {#1}\mkern1.0mu}%
  \tikz[anchor=base, baseline=0pt] \draw[line cap=round] (0pt,-\mydp-0.2pt) -- (0pt,\myht+0.3pt);%
  \ensuremath{\mkern2.0mu}%final space
}

\begin{document}

\myabs{G}{G}{g}\myabs{g}{G}{g}

\end{document}
```

I'm interested in getting feedback on the new command, both from a typesetting point of view as well as from an implementation point of view.

Comment: a generally shorter | might be fine, that's just a matter of the font design, but moving the | down for g would be really weird. Having a default | that works for G and g is of course what leads to the relatively deep | that is the default cm design.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I agree that moving the | for the g looks a little weird, but so does moving it up so it works for both G and g, in my opinion. In retrospect, it seems a bit odd that the absolute signs do not adapt to their "content" in the way the square-root sign does.

Comment: they do adapt if used with \left \right, although generally using fixed sizes rather than \left\right s recommended (not just here but for () as well)

Comment: personally of the suggestions on offer I'd go with the default | it is tall enough for G and deep enough for g. but using a font with a shorter | would also work, I don't think anything that makes G and g have different | would be usable.