# writing equation of absolute value in latex format

Tags: equations

[image: Here can you please share the code to write the equation in latex.]

How to write the equation in latex mode described in the below image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you. If you need help starting search for the `cases` environment.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols) help?

Comment: You would want to use a `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` block, except that your example is typeset in `\textstyle` rather than `\displaystyle`.

Comment: You’d wrap the text in the end within a `\textnormal`, probably align them, and have a `\sum_{t=1}^{K-1}` and a few `\frac` expressions.

Answer (score 5):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
I_{\mathrm{avg}} =
    \begin{dcases}
    1   & \text{ if } 0 < \delta < T_c, \text{ without ICI},    \\
    \frac{2T_u+3T_c}{3(T_u+T_c)} + \sum_{l=1}^{K-1}\frac{T_u}{(\pi l)^2(T_u+T_c)}
        & condition
    \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

- the writing of the second condition I left to you
- solution consider how such math structures are usually written
- math environment `dcases` is defined in the `mathtools` package, which is enhanced of the `amsmath` package defined by *American Mathematics Association*, so it is considered as standard way of writing advanced mathematics
- `amsmath` define `cases`, which in comparison to `dcases` left math inside cases structure in inline mode (as is written in the text)
- for basic how to write math in LaTeX you can learn from some introductory text about LaTeX and writing mathematics, for example in the [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) and in the [wiki Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

Comment: I will write "condition" in text mode. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, I left this to OP (fro practice that he write the second condition himself on the way as is written first condition) ... but so far no response from him :-(. Well, today is Sunday :-)

Comment:  Naturally....I'm agree with you....good Sunday from the hot Sicily.

Comment: @Sebastiano, we have mix of high humidity, very short showers and moderate hot day :-). I'm a bit jealous on your weather ...

Comment: We reached 38 degrees this afternoon and now there is a scirocco wind that is certainly good for my cervical :-(