# How can I stop TexStudio flagging math symbols in a preamble declaration as 'outside math environment'

Tags: texstudio

Putting the below commands in the preamble of a document causes TexStudio to wrongly flag "math command outside math env" (as illustrated)

[image]

The declaration I found on the list at [absolute value symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/absolute-value-symbols). Is there any way to prevent TexStudio doing this?

Note: This is not the question of how to make TexStudio recognise the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command which is answered by editing the .cwl file

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your question was very clear, I misunderstood the other one `:-)`

Comment: No problem  at all

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:

I just realized that the highlighting had already worked before I added that line to my test `.cwl`.
Then I checked github and saw that [a similar edit](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/commit/9e7114c28f3d55e9f127eb18c9d007a18cb83fff) to what I proposed has already been to `mathtools.cwl` since that question was asked.

So, a better answer would probably be: update TeXstudio (if you haven't already in past months).

---

You can mark arguments in `.cwl` files as math-environment-like with the `%formula`-suffix, so you could redefine `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` using:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{delim%cmd}{left%formula}{right%formula}#d
```

Then the code copied from the question you linked would look like this:

[image]