# Same size for equation over multiple lines with norm

Tags: equations, align

I want to have an equation written over multiple lines but without the sizes varying too much. An example would be

```
\begin{align*}
||f||&=||(t\mapsto\int_0^t g(s)ds)||+||A||\\
     &\leq a+b
\end{align*}
```

The problem then is:
-The norm signs are too small. This can be changed by using \left, \right and \middle but then the left hand side is of a different size
-Or integral sign is very small if I use textstyle to compress it's size

A solution which could look nice would be something like

```
\begin{align*}
||f||&=\left|\middle|\middle(t\mapsto\textstyle{\int_0^t} g(s)ds\middle)\middle|\middle|+\middle|\middle|A|\right|\\
     &\leq a+b
\end{align*}
```

However it still looks strange as the left hand side is still small and I don't know how this could be changed. Are there any recommendations how to write such equations aesthetically?

Comment: Apart from the fact that typing norms with `||` is wrong (see e.g.https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43009/82917) why would you want the norm to have the same size on both sides of the equation?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think it looks unpleasant otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Defining `\norm` properly (e.g. with `mathtools`) is the first step.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\|}{\|}

\begin{document}

You seem to want this:
\begin{align*}
\norm[\Big]{f}&= \norm[\Big]{\Bigl(t\mapsto\textstyle\int_0^t g(s) \, ds\Bigr)} + \norm[\Big]{A}\\
     &\leq a+b .
\end{align*}
IMNSHO this is \emph{far} better:
\begin{align*}
\norm{f}&= \norm[\Big]{\Bigl(t\mapsto\textstyle\int_0^t g(s) \, ds\Bigr)} + \norm{A}\\
     &\leq a+b .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you think the first version looks more pleasant, then we have quite a different taste `:-)`

Small comments:

- I've added a small space `\,` before the differential.
- `\textstyle` does not take an argument. By writing `\textstyle{\int_0^t}` you just switch to `\textstyle` for the rest of the current group, and putting `\int_0^t` in braces changes the integral from an operator to a ordinary symbol, which results in wrong spacing. I just removed the braces, as `\textstyle` does no harm in what follows. Alternatively you could use `\mathop{\textstyle\int_0^t}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yours does look better!