# Absolute Value Symbols in Section

Tags: symbols

I try to write absolute value symbols and norm symbols in section. The command \norm* and \abs* in package physics works not well. So I use the solution in [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43009/279748). But when I put this command in section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}%
\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
%
\let\oldnorm\norm
\def\norm{\@ifstar{\oldnorm}{\oldnorm*}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{$\norm{T}$}
\end{document}
```

it report error:

```
Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 

Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
<to be read again>
```

If there any method to modify the solution in [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43009/279748) such that I can use command \norm, \abs in section title?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue.

Comment: Remove the code from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother`. You don't want to type `$\norm{T}+\norm{\hat{T}}$` and get [this output (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxnkU.png)

Comment: @egreg I need large norm and abs in my main body. So I want to preserve these code.

Comment: @sakurajyan Just use `\abs*` or `\norm*` when you need automatic sizing, but bear in mind that such method may produce humongous delimiters like in the example I showed.

Comment: If there are some methods to reverse the command `\abs` and `\abs*`? I use physics package before, so I write a lot of Tex codes using `\abs` for automatic sizing.