# How to write absolute value symbol in subscript of a subscript?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I want to indicate `|D|` as a subscript of a subscript, but its spacing changes on the subscript where it becomes more distant.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
    \phantom{} \\
    $d_{\left|D\right|}$ \\
    \(C_{H_{d_{\left|D\right|}}}^{j}\)
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

Here I observe that on the subscript of a subscript on the second line, more space is added in between `|` and `D`. Is it possible to use same spacing used on the first example on the subscript?

Comment: Note that your example has compilation errors. There is a missing `}`

Comment: Just curious: Why do you employ `\left` and `\right` in these formulas?

Comment: @Mico there is no specific reason :-) I have tried all examples in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43048/127048 , looked like `\left/\right` was recommended

Comment: @daleif thanks fixed it

Comment: don't use left right when not  needed: it almost always adds unwanted horizontal space

Comment: @alper - The *only* reasoh why using `\left` and `\right` was acceptable -- note that  using `\left` and `\right` wasn't really *recomended* --  is because, for once, the extra whitespace that `\left` and `\right` insert just happened to be desirable for the use case at hand. I'd say that this is a classic exception that proves the rule...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Computer Modern fonts at small size (5pt, in this setting) have wider sidebearings around characters, when compared to 7pt or 10pt:

```
$DDD$

$\scriptstyle DDD$

$\scriptscriptstyle DDD$
```

produces

[image]

On the other hand, mixing Computer Modern math with Times in text is not the best typographic strategy.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$DDD$

$\scriptstyle DDD$

$\scriptscriptstyle DDD$

$d_{|D|}$

\(C_{H_{d_{\lvert D\rvert}}}^{j}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\left` and `\right` do no good to your formulas.

Comment: Why did you use `newtxtext,newtxmath`?

Comment: @alper IEEEtran uses Times for text; this way we have Times also fir math

Comment: Thanks , in the journal template I am using has `IEEEtran` as well, than should I use `newtxtext,newtxmath` too? which makes all the symbols I am using bolder

Comment: @alper I’d do it: Computer Modern math is visually clashing with Times in text.

Comment: Thanks I will definetly use `\usepackage{newtxmath}` its much easier to read with it; but I am not sure for `\usepackage{newtxtext}` since it affects fonts in listing and section titles