# How can I shift text under underbrace in yaxis?

Tags: math-mode, underbrace

In some cases, text under `underbrace` look distant. Hence, I want to shift the text under `underbrace` in y-axis.

Using `\usepackage{newtxmath}` (based on [How to write absolute value symbol in subscript of a subscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657751/how-to-write-absolute-value-symbol-in-subscript-of-a-subscript)) causes arrow to look more like a straight line and generates more space in between `underbrace` and its label.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\newcommand{\function}{\mathrm}
\newcommand{\require}[1]{\function{require(#1)}}
\begin{document}
    \phantom{} \\
    \(\underbrace{b_{D}}_{a}\)
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Here if possible, I want to shift `a` little closer to tip of the underbrace (shift to north) till it has a cramped "look".

wanted output example:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's the use case for creating a rather cramped "look"?

Comment: I have a equation in one-column, I just wanted to save some space. I have start using `\usepackage{newtxmath}` based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657756/127048 and the underbrach looks much more horizontal line, hence that have more space in between the arrow and its label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$
\underbrace{b_{D}}_{a} 
\underset{\raisebox{-1.55ex}{$\scriptstyle a$}}{\smash[b]{\underbrace{b_{D}}_{}}}
\underbrace{b_{D}}_{[C]} 
\underset{\raisebox{-1.95ex}{$\scriptstyle [C]$}}{\smash[b]{\underbrace{b_{D}}_{}}}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! what does `\smash` do?

Comment: @alper - Try it without `\smash[b]` and you'll find out. :-)

Comment: its much complex than I assume :) I was hoping only `yaxis=1mm` would be enough

Comment: can we also create newline inside the `raisebox` I have tried \newline but it did not help

Comment: @alper - Giive `\substack` a try. E.g., replace `\raisebox{-1.55ex}{$\scriptstyle a$}` with `\raisebox{-2ex}{\scriptsize$\substack{ uuu \\ vvv }$}`.