# Cause DeclarePairedDelimiter to switch starred and nonstarred versions

Tags: delimiters, mathtools, starred-version, robust-commands

I've made lots of use of the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23214/17916), which shows how to switch the starred and nonstarred versions of a paired delimiter command (causing the regular version to automatically size the delimiters).

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\makeatletter
\let\oldabs\abs
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\oldabs}{\oldabs*}}
\makeatother
```

But now in the pre header that I include in nearly every document, I've got several of these commands stacked up, and for each of them I've got another two lines switching the versions.

Is there good/nice way to alter `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` itself, so that it switches the two to begin with? (Which also means, would this break any dependencies?)

Comment: Why would you want it?

Comment: Would this redefinition not causing troubles with the optional argument of the non-starred variant?

Comment: @egreg: I've been looking for something like this too. I usually define several delimiters such as `\paren`, and I tend to use `(` and `)` for parentheses that shouldn't be resized, `\paren` for those that should, and (for example) `\paren*[\bigg]` for when they need to be manually resized. Given that I sometimes use up to seven delimiters, a shortcut would be nice.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm thinking the starred version would then accept the optional argument as Arun says. I edited the question to clarify that it wouldn't be 'good' if this breaks some dependency in some popular package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy: just abstract the redefinition.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WronglyDeclarePairedDelimiter}[3]{%
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifstar{\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname}
            {\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname*}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

After this, the declaration

```
\WronglyDeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

will define the command `\abs` to do the wrong thing you want.

When you'll realize why this is wrong, you'll just remove `Wrongly` and you'll be on the right way again. `;-)`

A “better” procedure, that uses the same syntax as the original command (but `\abs` by itself will either use the automatic or the optional argument version), so you don't need the absurd `\abs*[\big]{a}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WronglyDeclarePairedDelimiter}[3]{%
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifstar{\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname}
            {\@ifnextchar[{\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname}
                          {\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname*}%
            }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\WronglyDeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{|}{|}

\begin{document}

$\abs{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\abs[\Big]{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\abs*{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm ("easy") :-) but it's not the 70s anymore and I find it horrific that I have to waste so much time learning (and using) a whole new programming language just because it's the traditional way to produce documents in my field, when software could easily take care of the details these days, and let me focus on the content.

Comment: I'm trying to guess why it's wrong and if the "better" way handling the optional parameter fixes the wrongness (but my brain doesn't want any more TEX today). I tested it and both versions will accept the option now, though I can't see why. Is there a reason you switched to `{|}`? I thought the `\lvert` `\rvert` were supposed to handle some kind of spacing.

Comment: @TravisBemrose There's no need to use `\lvert` and `\rvert`, because the `\abs` macro takes care of the spacing automatically. The main fact is that automatic resizing works only in fewer cases than you may expect, because it usually produces too large fences. Or not what you may want: for instance `\left|\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\right|` will produce equal sized fences for the inner and the outer parts. Whereas `\abs[\big]{\abs{a}-\abs{b}}` will do the right thing (I mean, the correct `\abs`).

Comment: lol. Sometimes I'm not satisfied with the automatic sizing, but it's because it's too small and I override it with larger sizes. I'm guessing `RIGHT` gets interpreted as `\right`, but why is it followed with the new command's name `#1`, and why is there no `LEFT`?

Comment: @TravisBemrose `RIGHT` is just a string for making sure we don't clobber any existing command. It could be `FOO` or whatever. It's just like using `\oldabs`, but safer.

Comment: Then I'd better change it or I'll get confused. Ok, I think I see what's happening now.  We're defining `\RIGHTabs` and `\abs`. The first has a starred version that automatically resizes. The second command checks for stars and optional characters and calls the right version of the first command. OMG, is `RIGHT` a pun on `Wrongly`? `:-D` I can probably work my way through replacing `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\innerp[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1,#2}` now. (While putting this in my pre file, I realized it would only let me fix about 2/3 of my commands.) This is robust, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A trial version, without warranties, by switching the two variants internally. (The code is 'stolen' from `mathtools.sty` ;-))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand*\DeclarePairedDelimiter[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{
    \MT_delim_default_inner_wrappers:n{#1}
    \@namedef{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star:}##1
      %{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left#2 ##1 \aftergroup\egroup\right #3}%
      { \@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star_wrapper:nnn}%
           {\left#2}{##1}{\right#3} }%
    \@xp\@xp\@xp
      \newcommand
        \@xp\csname MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar:\endcsname
        [2][\\@gobble]
        {
          %\mathopen{\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 l} #2} ##2
          %\mathclose{\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 r} #3}}
          \@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar_wrapper:nnn}%
             {\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 l} #2}
             {##2}
             {\@nameuse {\MH_cs_to_str:N ##1 r} #3}
        }
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{
      \@ifstar
        {\@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar:}}
        {\@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star:}}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}



\begin{document}
$\abs{-5}$

$\abs*[\Bigg]{-5}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess, a pure `expl3` answer would be nicer.  This would look more coherent and save you all the `\@xp` stuff.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Tell the designer of `mathtools` -- I 'stole' the code ;-)

Comment: I suspected something like this (renewing the command and rewriting everything in an opposite manner) would work, but I'll leave the question open for a while since I'm hoping someone knows a more robust way to do it. (I.e. less likely to need a warranty, and less fragile - a stray key press while I have my pre header open won't make a change that's impossible for me to track down later when it breaks). :)

Comment: @TravisBemrose: Patching is another possibility, but my solution was in a bit of a hurry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To have this info in the same place and save others effort, following egreg's answer above, I got this working for the `X` version of `\NewPairedDelimiterX`. I kept his example below to make it easier to look back and forth between the two.

**Declaration:**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Tells DeclarePairedDelimiter to create functions that are automatically sized.
% Starred version is not automatically sized. Both version allow an overriding input.
% Auto sizing:  \abs{x}
% Override:     \abs[\big]{x}
% Not sized:    \abs*{x}
% Override:     \abs*[\big]{x}
%
% Defines two commands, for example: PAIREDabs, abs
% abs checks for a star or options and then calles the right version of PAIREDabs
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\NewPairedDelimiter}[3]{%
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname PAIRED\string#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifstar{\csname PAIRED\string#1\endcsname}
            {\@ifnextchar[{\csname PAIRED\string#1\endcsname}
                          {\csname PAIRED\string#1\endcsname*}%
            }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\NewPairedDelimiterX}[4]{%
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\csname PAIREDX\string#1\endcsname[2]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifstar{\csname PAIREDX\string#1\endcsname}
            {\@ifnextchar[{\csname PAIREDX\string#1\endcsname}
                          {\csname PAIREDX\string#1\endcsname*}%
            }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

**Definition:**

```
\NewPairedDelimiterX{\innerp}{\langle}{\rangle}{#1,#2}
```

**Use:**

```
$\innerp{ax}{y}$
```