# Peculiarities in \norm* from physics.sty

Tags: mathtools, physics

I am a heavy user of the physics package.  Unfortunately, the `\norm` command seems to have some quirks associated with it.  According to the documentation the starred version is meant to result in a norm whose sized is fixed.  However, consider the following MWE

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
 \norm{A^k}_2 \quad \norm*{A^k}_2 \quad
 \frac{1}{\norm{A^k}_{\mathrlap{2}}} \quad \frac{1}{\norm*{A^k}_{\mathrlap{2}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

where we can see that extra space is added between the `||` and the subscript `2` when the starred version is used.  This behavior also appears to prevent one from using `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` from swallowing up the subscript in the `*` case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Analysis

Let's see what `physics.sty` does. First, the definition of `\norm`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\norm{ l m }{\braces#1{\lVert}{\rVert}{#2}} % Norm
```

The `l` argument type collects everything up to (and excluding) the first `{`. Now let's look at `\braces`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\braces{}{{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi\@braces}
```

I see no reason for this `\ifnum`; anyway, it means we need to look at `\@braces`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\@braces{ s t\big t\Big t\bigg t\Bigg m m m }
{ % General braces with automatic and manual sizing
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\left#6\smash{#8}\right#7\vphantom{#8}}
        {
                \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\bigl#6{#8}\bigr#7}{
                        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{\Bigl#6{#8}\Bigr#7}{
                                \IfBooleanTF{#4}{\biggl#6{#8}\biggr#7}{
                                        \IfBooleanTF{#5}{\Biggl#6{#8}\Biggr#7}{\left#6{#8}\right#7}
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        \ifnum\z@=`{\fi}
}
```

Wow! One of the ugliest macro definitions I have ever seen. Anyway, this shows what happens when you call `\norm*{A^k}_{2}`: it gets translated into

```
{% <-- from the \ifnum in \braces
 \left\lVert\smash{A^k}\right\rVert\vphantom{A^k}
}% <-- from the \ifnum in \@braces
```

which is just silly. Some notes, now.

1. What I said about “no reason” now turns into “it's wrong”.
2. Where's the problem in saying `#6#8#7` instead of using `\left` and `\right` whose final job is just to add ***unwanted*** horizontal space?
3. Where's the advantage in typing `\norm\big{x}` over `\norm[\big]{x}` à la `mathtools`?

### Possible solutions in order of personal preference

1. Avoid `physics.sty`.
2. Ask the author of `physics.sty` to clean up the package code.
3. Add

   ```
   \usepackage{mleftright}
   \mleftright
   ```

   to your preamble.

### Comments

I recommend ***NOT*** using automatic sizing unless you know precisely that it's OK. Which, as shown by the output of `\norm{A^k}_2`, is not this case. Please, note the “not” in boldface italic uppercase.

The `physics` package is a prime example of how to abuse `xparse`. As far as I can see, it's a collection of macros that can easily be defined in the document preamble as needed, maybe with the help of `mathtools` (not with automatic sizing by default, of course).

Finally: your idea of `\mathrlap`ping the subscript is not so good. But you're the final judge on it.

Answer (score 6):

I can offer no particular insights into the hows and whys of the macro definitions of the `physics` package. However, using the `mathtools` package (which you're already loading), it's straightforward to come up with a replacement definition of `\norm` and `\norm*` that meets your formatting objectives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathrlap' and '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macros

\makeatletter  
%% Switch meanings of starred and unstarred macros
%% (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278398/5001)
\newcommand{\XDeclarePairedDelimiter}[3]{%  "X" for "exchange"
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \newcommand#1{%
    \@ifstar{\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname}
            {\@ifnextchar[{\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname}
                          {\csname RIGHT\string#1\endcsname*}%
}}}
\makeatother
\let\norm\relax % undefine existing "\norm" macro
\XDeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\[
 \norm{A^k}_2    \quad 
 \norm*{A^k}_2   \quad
 \frac{1}{\norm{A^k}_{\mathrlap{2}}} \quad 
 \frac{1}{\norm*{A^k}_{\mathrlap{2}}}
\]
\end{document}
```