# Use of mathtools

Tags: mathtools

I have defined the `\abs`as described in the Mathtools Users Guide 3.6. But I would like to habe the stared-version as default (=`\abs`). I looked further and found on 3..6.1 (as I thought) a way to do this. But I failed: Changing {star}
and {nostar} doesn't make any difference. Am I wrong with my thinking?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Example from Mathtools-Manual 3.6.1
%\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
%   \reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper{\abs}{star}{#1#2#3}
%   \reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper{\abs}{nostar}{\mathinner{#1#2#3}}
% MY try:
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
    \reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper{\abs}{nostar}{#1#2#3}
    \reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper{\abs}{star}{\mathinner{#1#2#3}}
%
\begin{document}
%
\[
    \abs{\frac{\pi}{2}} \quad  \quad \abs*{\frac{\pi}{2}} 
\]
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you see the posting [Swap definition of starred and non-starred command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23178/5001)?

Comment: Trust me: you don't want to use automatic sizing by default.

Comment: @ Mico, no, but now. Thanks for the link.
@egreg: can you explain this to me?

Comment: @Ulrich Most of the times, the automatic sizing chooses too big fences than necessary.

Comment: @egrep: i.e. \abs{x} is ok but \abs*{x} maybe wrong (I guess you have a better example)? So your recommondation is to use use the stared-version only in displayed math environments?

Comment: @Ulrich not there I'd also use the normal one or manual scalled. Use only auto scale when you really need it. `\abs*{\sum_i} ` does not look very good, the fences are too big. There are many other examples. Once you have edited enough manuscripts you'll know the hazards of auto scaling.