# A macro defining macro to swap starred and nonstarred \DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: macros

In the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/swap-definition-of-starred-and-non-starred-command) a method of swapping the starred and non-starred versions of the macros from `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` is presented. For example, for the `\abs` function we could use

```
\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\tmp@abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\def\abs{\@ifstar{\tmp@abs}{\tmp@abs*}}
\makeatother
```

This is a nice solution, because the results from `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` are much better than `\left` and `\right` (especially when it comes to spacing), and often the starred version is more desirable than the non-starred so it's best to have it as the default.

Is there a way to combine the above method into a macro that does the swapping automatically? It's not too big a deal in this case, only two lines of code per definition, but it's often considered best practice to define a function or macro to encapsulate processes that are done multiple times. In this case I would think that a suitable macro would look something like:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\DeclarePairedDelimiterSwapped[3]{
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\tmp@delim{#2}{#3}
    \def{#1}{\@ifstar{\tmp@delim}{\tmp@delim*}}
}
\makeatletter

\DeclarePairedDelimiterSwapped\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

I could then go on to define lots of delimiters, one line each. However, the above code produces an error, and in hindsight it was obviously not going to work because `\abs` is taken as an input and not defined. How can I fix my definition of `\DeclarePairedDelimiterSwapped` so that it actually defines commands? Alternatively, let me know if this is not an easy fix.

Comment: Trust me: you don't want to swap. Using indiscriminately autosizing delimiters is a good road to bad math typography.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. But should you? Look at `\abs{\hat{f}}` and judge for yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclarePairedDelimiterSwapped}{mmm}
 {% first define \DeclarePairedDelimiter on a different command
  \exp_args:Nc \DeclarePairedDelimiter { eddy @ \cs_to_str:N #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  % now define your swapped command
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{som}
   {
    \IfBooleanTF { ##1 }
     {% * is used, ignore the optional argument
      \use:c { eddy @ \cs_to_str:N #1 } { ##3 }
     }
     {% no *
      \IfNoValueTF { ##2 }
       {% no optional argument
        \use:c { eddy @ \cs_to_str:N #1 } * { ##3 }
       }
       {% optional argument
        \use:c { eddy @ \cs_to_str:N #1 } [ ##2 ] { ##3 }
       }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclarePairedDelimiterSwapped{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\[
\abs{\frac{1}{2}} % auto sizing
\quad
\abs{\hat{f}} % auto sizing
\quad
\abs*{\hat{f}} % no auto sizing
\quad
\abs[\big]{1} % big size
\quad
\abs[\Big]{\frac{1}{2}} % Big size
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is just one of the reasons why the autosizing feature should be used with great care and not used indiscriminately.

Now that you know, use the plain `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and add `*` *only* when really needed (that is, very rarely).