# Macro for \left( and \right)

Tags: math-mode, macros

I know there has been discussion about this topic, but I haven't seen a working solution.
Is it possible to define a macro within LaTeX, such that inside math mode, `(` would produce `\left(` and `)` would produce `\right)`?

I know it is possible to define a different macro, say `\lparen`, but it has the disadvantage of not being as visually clear, and also not as simple, as `(`. I would like to override the `(` command only in math mode. This issue is pretty annoying when writing a lot of math.

Comment: In general it would be a bad idea: `\left(\sum_{\substack{i,j\\i<j}} ...\right)`, just look stupid. Though `nath` is able to handle most of it.

Comment: @daleif: Agreed. But `(\sum_{\substack{i,j\\i<j}} ...)` does not look good either.

Comment: never said I would not scale the fences. I usually imply the following rule: Scale the fences to such a degree that the reader has a clear distinction of what they are fencing in, but not to such a degree that the fences dominate the expression.

Comment: [`\Big`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Brackets_and_Parentheses#Reference_guide) instead of `\left` and `\right` would perhaps be appropriate here, so you've got a point. Another example where replacing all `(` with `\left(` and all `)` with `\right)` completely fails is when you have a multi-line expression, split in for example in the `array` environment, and you want to fence the entire expression. If you try this with `\left(` and `\right)` you will generate an error, but using plain parenthesis or (e.g.) `\Big(` and `\Big)` works.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

without using `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begingroup
  \catcode`(\active \xdef({\left\string(}  % ( is defined as \left(
  \catcode`)\active \xdef){\right\string)} % ) is defined as \right)
\endgroup
\mathcode`(="8000 \mathcode`)="8000        % active in mathmode

\begin{document}
\[ 
   (\frac{(3-\frac{1}{x})^2}{(\frac4x-1)x}) 
\]    
\end{document}
```

[image]

and if you are using package `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{%
    \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\[\relax
    \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
    \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
  }%
  \ht\Mathstrutbox@\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@\dp\z@}
\makeatother
\begingroup
  \catcode`(\active \xdef({\left\string(}
  \catcode`)\active \xdef){\right\string)}
\endgroup
\mathcode`(="8000 \mathcode`)="8000
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 f(x) &= (\frac{(3-\frac{1}{x})^2}{(\frac4x-1)x}-1)x^2 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Herbert, I really like this solution. I haven't run it yet (I just stumbled into this thread), but looking at the image provided, I noticed something that struck me as odd. Do you know why there is extra space between the "f" and the "(" in "f(x)"?

Comment: @Todd, this is the tribute to `\left` which is used by default. If you don't want the space use `f\!(x) &=` in the above example

Comment: Is there any danger in using either Herbert's or Werner's solution in a custom package? Joe

Comment: @Joe: See my answer.

Comment: @Herbert great! But for me this isn't working with LuaLaTex

Comment: @someonr: it works for me also with `lualatex`

Comment: @Herbert Sry. The problem is caused by `fontspec` which I only used if compiling with `LuaLaTex`

Comment: To fix the unwanted space before the left parenthesis, I redefined \left and \right (before the code provided in this answer) per this answer to another question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610

Comment: The spacing in `f(x)` seems to be fixed by using the `mleftright` package and replacing `\left` with `\mleft` and `\right` with `\mright` in the code above. This is in the same vein as @Devin's comment.

Comment: Thanks! I've been using this for a while. As a note to users, in case it's not obvious: mixed brackets like $[a,b)$ might need the assertion `\left[a,b\right)` to properly function.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev do you know if it is possible to do the same for square brackets and curly brackets? that is to create macro for `\left[` - `\right]` and for `\left\{` - `\right\}`? I tried replacing all the `(` and `)` with `[` and `]`, and it worked, but I got 2 errors from overleaf saying that "Bad mathchar (32768) A mathchar number must be between 0 and 32767."

Answer (score 23):

I strongly advise against automatically replacing `(` and `)` with  `\left(` and `right)`. This has a serious drawback when formulas have to be squeezed in order to fit them into a line. The problem is that the stuff between `\left(` and `right)` is set with natural spacing, whereas the top level math list is subject to stretching and shrinking (see [*E-TeX: Guidelines for Future TeX Extensions*](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-3/tb29mitt.pdf) by Frank Mittelbach, Section 11). See yourself:

[image: comparison]

In the first line, the space around the first `+` is shrunk to 0, whereas the space around the second `+` is set to the natural width. In the second line, both `+`'s are treated in the same way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=4.715cm
\begin{document}
$a+\left(b+c\right)$ doesn't look good \par
$a+(b+c)$ doesn't\llap{\rule[0.6ex]{1.1em}{0.7pt}\hskip0.1em} look good
\end{document}
```

Let me point out that the above does *not* apply to AMS environments like `align` or `gather` since in those the spaces are *always* set to their natural width.

Comment: Note that even the `mleftright` does not solve the squeezing issue; it fixes only the immediate spacing around the delimiters.

Answer (score 21):

Have a look at the `nath` package. It does automatic scaling of all delimiters. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}
\[ ( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i ) \]
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks. it does work, but I heard there are compatibility problems with other packages. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, nath is incompatible with some packages. One of the biggest "incompatibilities" is that everybody assumes you will be using amsmath :-) However, I used it for my dissertation and I liked it a lot.

Comment: See also: [math mode - Incompatibilities with and alternatives to nath - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104532/incompatibilities-with-and-alternatives-to-nath?noredirect=1&lq=1) for notes on using `nath`.

Answer (score 15):

You can redefine the category codes for `(` and `)` to be `\active`. And then, condition on whether or not you're in math mode via `\ifmmode...\else...\fi`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\lparen{(}% left parenthesis (
\catcode`(=\active
\newcommand{(}{\ifmmode\left\lparen\else\lparen\fi}
\def\rparen{)}% right parenthesis )
\catcode`)=\active
\newcommand{)}{\ifmmode\right\rparen\else\rparen\fi}

\begin{document}
This is some regular (bracketed) stuff in text mode. Here is some stuff in $(xyz)$ text style math mode. Here is some display style math stuff:
\[
  (\sum_{i=1}^n i)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it compatible with amsmath? I guess Herberts' solution goes on the same lines

Comment: @Werner -- the trouble here is that the parens are really too big. quoting from the maple press style book (1931), p.152: "In mathematical expressions, braces, brackets and parentheses must be just large enough to enclose the widest part of the material between them without counting the superior or inferior exponents of such expressions." (here, "widest" means "tallest from top to bottom".) that's why knuth provided additional sizes, \big, \Big, etc., to fine tune expressions where `\left` and `\right` produce too large delimiters. programming would have been possible, but too "expensive".

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's a valuable resource, thanks.

Comment: @Werner is it possible to do the same for square brackets and curly brackets?

Answer (score 6):

I learned that making your file too "special" has its minus - in particular when you want to collaborate. Therefore, your source should be as simple as possible. In order to make the typing quicker, I got to know `YASNIPPET` for emacs; you can find similar tools, namely snippets, for other editors as well. For example in order to type

```
\( \left( x^2 \right) \)
```

I type:

```
m[TAB] pare[TAB]x^2[TAB][TAB]
```

`yasnippet` takes care of what I need according to the snippets I defined. This way I get a standard .tex file, easily entered. If you want further details, let me know.

Comment: There is a sense in what you're saying. I am using it especiallyt for myself, but there may be times when I'd want to export my code. Is this snippet working only on mac? I am working on a windows machine

Comment: This is a mode of emacs and thus cross platform. In order to work with my solution you'll have to install emacs+yasnippet. Together with AUCTeX and latexmk you get the perfect environment in my mind. It takes a little while to get used to, but worth it. *Note* the idea of snippets exists in other editors as well.