# Why doesn't TeX/LaTeX interpret multi-letter sequences as functions / parentheses as \left/\right in math mode by default?

Tags: math-mode

I am in constant search for an alternative to LaTeX, but it seems I am stuck for it for a long time, and I am trying to see the bright side of it.

The other day one thought struck me, I think, LaTeX is missing many reasonable defaults, especially math environment. For example, it is very unlikely that you have three variables named `l`, `o` and `g` at the same time, and you are writing product of those three variables in that order. But still you have to write `\log` to indicate you meant the function `log()`. In other words, when someone writes `log`, they (almost) always mean the `log` function.

Same is true for parentheses and braces, in math environment when one uses a parenthesis again they most probably mean a `\left(`. I know, I can introduce my own `\(` commands but again they are not by default.

Because I am using LaTeX mostly for math typesetting, I am only aware of those kind of non-defaults. My question is why are the things are not designed such that these most basic, fundamental things are not handled by default? I read that Knuth is considered math typesetting specialist, he should have noticed these burdens while he is using TeX in my opinion.

Comment: In programming languages where the string `log` is interpreted as "the logarithmic function", you probably have to say `l*o*g` to denote the product of three variables. Generally `(` should *not* be `\left(`; if you're used to this, you're on a wrong direction.

Comment: Why should TeX go through all the trouble to check if a character sequence like "l" "o" "g" correspond to some "default"? Do you know how much more complex this would make a compiler? TeX is from the early 80s where computer resources where limited. What's the big problem to add a simple `\\` in front of it? I'm really sometimes shocked about the laziness of some modern computer users.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Totally agree with you about complexity, but I don't think it is laziness, just a normal frustration when one is learning things. It is natural to try to wonder why things don't just work as you would expect, and I think it is an important part of learning to try to understand why.

Comment: This seems more like a rant than a genuine question.

Comment: Do you program?  If so, you might be familiar with the computer's tendency to "do what I say" rather than "do what I mean".  You're the one who has to be smart on behalf of your electronic slave.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: That tiny little ``\`` introduces mental friction for me. When there are many of them the code looks far from elegant and hard to grasp at once.

Comment: @Martin I disagree that a compiler shouldn’t make the effort to provide such a default if it were really meaningful. Math *could* conceivably be parsed this way (but yes, it would be way less efficient). But TeX’ way of consistently parsing math is simply superior. For instance, nimcap’s request is not good because it doesn’t scale and limits generality (two important design principles in computer languages, cf. Eric Lippert).

Comment: The TeX SE is a very friendly crowd, but you are likely to be treated as hostile when you frame your question argumentatively.  If you're interested in why TeX's parser requires backslashes, that's a good question.  But you've presumed that your feature request is "basic" and "fundamental" and so "reasonable" that it should already be implemented, and that puts everyone on the defensive.

Comment: egreg, just out of curiosity, where do you really need `(` more often than `\left(`?

Comment: @Joey: As is explained in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12793), there are more differences between `(` and `\left(` than one might think. nimcap: See also [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58641) which explains why automatic replacement of `(` with `\left(` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well, to answer your question. The behaviour is reasonable, because it is **consistent**. I use, besides `\log`, the functions `\det`, `\tr`, `\tg`, `\inv`, `\abs`, etc. If you made the "most-used" ones "backslash-less", then you don't know which ones have backslash and which don't. As well, some of us generate automated LaTeX codes and such exceptions would change our work to a true hell.

For parentheses, you get into serious troubles with things like `[0,1[` for semi-open intervals, or even `[0,1)` for that.

Remember, LaTeX is **good** because it is **consistent** hence **predictable**, once you learn the basics.

Comment: Word has no problem parsing `[0, 1)` the correct way, though you need a `\right` to get the same effect with `[0, 1[`. Still, an actual opening-closing pair is trivial (once you have Unicode, of course, which TeX didn't know anything about until recently). And you still need `\operatorname{foo}` for those that LaTeX doesn't have an own command.

Comment: @Joey `\operatorname` is not a good command for general use, better put `\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}` in the preamble.

Comment: @tohecz You are right when there is a symbol used several times; however, occasionally there is a unique occurrence and then I prefer `\operatorname`. Actually `\DeclareMathOperator` invokes `\operatorname`.

Answer (score 17):

When designing something for general purpose use it does not make sense to assume that you want `log` to be upright roman, as opposed to the default italics that are used in math mode.  If that were the case, then someone else would need a method to specify the product of `l`, `o`, and `g`.  There are also just way too many functions and new ones are added now and then.

It is more important to have defined rules and be consistent rather than having too many special cases.  While you **probably** mean `left(` when you write `(`, **probaably** is not enough to assume that is what you mean. Again, this assumption would necessitate having to say something like `\paren` when one just wanted a regular `(`, and someone else would complain that why can't a `(` just be a `(`.

Basically it comes down to specify what you really mean, so as to minimize confusion when `TeX` does its job.

Answer (score 17):

Playing devil's advocate, the opposite could also be expected down the line: What if you actually had three variables `l`, `o` and `g` that you want separated and (La)TeX required you use use them as `\separate{l}\separate{o}\separate{g}`? Of course, I'm exaggerating the use of some "really special" function `\separate`. The same goes for not *always* wanting `\left(` when you type `(`, for whatever reason.

As such, nothing is assumed, giving the end user freedom over manipulation down to the highest detail.

The [`nath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nath) is an example that might be in favour of your "assume some basic defaults" notion. As stated in the package description on CTAN,

> [`nath`] delivers a particular context-dependent presentation on the
>   basis of a rather coarse context-independent notation. Highlighted
>   features [include]: depending on the context, the command `\frac`
>   produces either built-up or case or solidus fractions, with
>   parentheses added whenever required for preservation of the
>   mathematical meaning; delimiters adapt their size to the material
>   enclosed, rendering `\left` and `\right` almost obsolete.

So, it provides some "assumptions" in your mathematical use so you don't have to worry or think about it anymore. But it may not always be perfect, and what then?

Comment: You could just use `l o g`, similar to what the `eqn` preprocessor for `troff` uses.

Comment: btw: my two cents: I don't like the output of `$$(\sum_{i=1}^n x^i)$$ and $$(\int\limits_{i=1}^n x^i)$$` with the `nath` package, I would prefer some horizontal space and a bit larger parentheses :-/ To get a professional output, you have to put a bit more effort to the code, and **LaTeX is about being professional**.

Comment: @Aditya: As mentioned, I used some exaggeration to illustrate the alternative viewpoint...

Comment: @tohecz: Agreed. I have not used [`nath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nath) since I prefer making my own decisions on delimiter (and other) usage, spacing, etc.

Comment: @tohecz: Nath goes to considerable efforts to make sure that the parenthesis are **smaller**. In  `\left\sum_{i=1}^n x^i \right)`, the parenthesis are too large and look ugly.

Comment: Nobody should use `\left(` often, let alone always! Aditya's comment shows a reason why.

Comment: @egreg: I can't agree. You get good results in a lot of cases, as far as what I've met.

Comment: @Aditya: I know and of course I don't use `\left` with `\sum` and `\int`. I just wanted to say that making non-consistent "defaults" is a lot a matter of *ense of the typesetter, and not a matter of "good standards".

Comment: @tohecz See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610/4427), for example.

Comment: @egreg: ok guys, you've caught me, I wasn't aware of this solution to that problem.

Answer (score 14):

With ConTeXt MkIV, you can use the `calcmath` module to use such shortcuts. For example:

```
\usemodule[calcmath]

\starttext                                                                 
\calcmath{log(x/(1+x))}
\stoptext
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In the initial `TEXDR.AFT` that Knuth wrote to describe the new system he was proposing, he did not use back slashes for “keywords”, but relied on them being “*chosen so that match English words, since they can appear intermixed with normal text*.” In the next draft, `TEX.ONE` slash was introduced as an escape character “*to indicate control mode rather than text mode*”, this change was not explained (though the next draft has a note to forget the first the first draft if you have seen it), presumably he found the idea of reserved keywords not so good, but at least we know he didn’t overlook it :)

Comment: In a language used for typesetting, reserved words should never appear as ones that a user would like to typeset; or one has to confine the "strings to be typeset" mostly like Postscript does.

Comment: +1, This is the only answer here that actually addresses the question historically. It is worth noting that Bell Labs's `eqn` (which predates TeX (the CACM article is dated June 1976) and which definitely had an influence in TeX's design) actually allows you to use such keywords like `sup` and `sin` without any backslashes.

Answer (score 6):

There are several good answers here already, but it's worth adding that some of Donald Knuth's thoughts on this are set out in an [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1979-14598-1) that appeared in the Bulletin of the AMS in 1979.

Comment: cool reading material!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be manually redefined with enough effort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
    cmdname_blacklist={relax=1, undefined_cs=1}
    function preprocessFormula(formula, before, after)
        tex.print(before .. (
            formula:gsub('%a+', function(s)
            if #s>1 and not cmdname_blacklist[token.create(s).cmdname] then
                    return '\\'..s..' '
                else
                    return s
                end
            end)) .. after)
    end
\end{luacode*}

\makeatletter

\def\@preprocessFormulaAdvanced#1#2#3{\directlua{preprocessFormula(
"\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}",
"\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}",
"\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#3}}"
)}}
\def\@preprocessFormula#1{\@preprocessFormulaAdvanced{#1}{}{}}

\NewCommandCopy\oldOpenBracket\[
\NewCommandCopy\oldOpenParen\(
\def\[#1\]{\oldOpenBracket\@preprocessFormula{#1}\]}
\def\(#1\){\oldOpenParen\@preprocessFormula{#1}\)}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \NewEnvironmentCopy {mm} {  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680717/250119
    \expandafter \NewCommandCopy \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname#2\endcsname
    \expandafter \NewCommandCopy \csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname end#2\endcsname
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewEnvironmentCopy{oldalign*}{align*}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{align*}{b}{%
    \@preprocessFormulaAdvanced{#1}%
    {\begin{oldalign*}}%
    {\end{oldalign*}}%
}{}

% redefine the dollar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60395/250119
\catcode`$=\active
\protected\def${\@ifnextchar$\@doubledollar\@singledollar}
\def\@doubledollar$#1$${\[#1\]}
\def\@singledollar#1${\(#1\)}

\makeatother

\begin{align*}
    sum_{x=1}^{10} x^2 &> int_{x=1}^9 x^2 \, dx
\end{align*}

$a+b=b+a$

$$a-b ne b-a$$

\[a-b ne b-a\]

$sin x+cos y=tan theta$

$Pr[x=a wedge y=b]$

$undefined multiple characters$

\end{document}
```

Basically for each multi-letter word it checks whether the control sequence is "defined" and replace it with the control sequence.

[image: output]

For `\left( ... \right)` it's a bit more complicated to implement, but in theory it's also implementable, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31529/250119 for an example.

Comment: Note that normally `$$... $$` is not recommended: [math mode - Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)