# Can I redefine the dollar

Tags: math-mode

I want to capture the math mode through a redefinition of the `$`. I thought about something like

```
\def$#1${here was a formula}
% to test
$x+y=z$
```

I would expect "here was a formula" as output. Is it possible ?

**EDIT** : egreg's solution works for me :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\catcode`\$=\active
\gdef$#1${Formula(\detokenize{#1})}
\begin{document}

voila le calcul $3+4=5$

\end{document}
```

But i would like also to redefine the double dollar `$$ ...$$`. If i define additionally :

```
\gdef$$#1$${centered-Formula(\detokenize{#1})}
```

then the following works :

```
voila un calcul centré $$x+y=z$$
```

but I can't use the single dollar anymore: `$3+4=5$` fails now to compile.

Question : how can I have both `$...$` and `$$...$$` available ?

Comment: Possible, but slightly dangerous: ``\catcode`$=\active`` and then `\protected\def$#1${foo}`

Comment: Why do you want this? There may be an easier way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Seamus: I actually did it in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4939) (because I prefer `$...$` to `\(...\)`).

Comment: @egreg. I know, I can put the `\catcode` in a group, and this will have no effect outside. But if i don't, how can I cancel the effect of '\catcode`$=\active' later on in the document ? And for which reason did you put a `\protected` ?

Comment: @nicolasroy It's still not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Well, my question about how to cancel the effect, was just a subsidiary question, because to frightened me with "dangerous". But your answer is perfect for me. What i want to do : i want to export a tex document into some xml file. For this, i need to capture the maths formulas, a make `\write` of the `\detokenize` of the content of the math environment. With your `catcode` trick, it works.

Comment: I wish I could do that before exchanging euros for dollars, just to raise the exchange rate a bit. If anybody has hints, let me know!

Comment: @nicolasroy In case you edit your question in this way, it's better to add a comment to the accepted answer, in order to ping the author.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can, but there's no guarantee that it will work in all situations:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\gdef$#1${...}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=\active}
```

For `$$...$$`, with even less guarantees:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\catcode`$=\active
\makeatletter
\protected\def${\@ifnextchar$\@doubledollar\@singledollar}
\def\@doubledollar$#1$${centeredFormula(\detokenize{#1})}
\def\@singledollar#1${Formula(\detokenize{#1})}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a+b=b+a$

$$a-b\ne b-a$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as the other answer's solution, but implemented in expl3:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\char_set_catcode_active:N $
\cs_new:Npn $ { \peek_charcode:NTF $ {\loic_doubledollar:w} {\loic_singledollar:w} }
\cs_new:Npn \loic_doubledollar:w $ #1 $ $ {
    Formula(\detokenize{#1}):
    \c_math_toggle_token \c_math_toggle_token #1
    \c_math_toggle_token \c_math_toggle_token
}
\cs_new:Npn \loic_singledollar:w #1 $ {
    Formula(\detokenize{#1}):
    \c_math_toggle_token #1 \c_math_toggle_token
}
\char_set_catcode_math_toggle:N $
\AtBeginDocument{
    \char_set_catcode_active:N $
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$a+b=b+a$
$$a-b\ne b-a$$
\end{document}
```

---

### Extra: handle `\[`, `\begin{align*}` etc.

**Unfortunately, `align*` environment uses `align` under the hood, so it's dangerous to redefine `align`.**
Similarly, [redefining `equation*` breaks `\[... \]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554551/250119).

Nevertheless, it's not recommended to use `$$...$$` in LaTeX, `\[...\]` is more recommended, refer to [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/250119) .

Furthermore, it may be desirable to redefine several other math environments such as `\begin{tikzcd}..\end{tikzcd}`, `\begin{align*}..\end{align*}`, etc.

A full list can be found in `texdoc amsldoc` (plus the deprecated `eqnarray`, and the environments `\begin{math}`, `\begin{displaymath}`):

[image: amsldoc extract]

This is an example of redefining `\[...\]` and `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`: (`\(...\)` is not handled)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% ======== redefine $...$
\char_set_catcode_active:N $
\cs_new:Npn $ #1 $ {
    Formula(\detokenize{#1}):
    \c_math_toggle_token #1 \c_math_toggle_token
}
\char_set_catcode_other:N $
\AtBeginDocument{ \char_set_catcode_active:N \$ }
% ======== redefine \[...\]
\cs_new_eq:NN \lois__old_open_square_bracket: \[
\cs_gset:Npn \[ #1 \] {
    Formula(\detokenize{#1}):
    \lois__old_open_square_bracket: #1 \]
}
% ======== redefine align*
\ProvideDocumentCommand \NewEnvironmentCopy {mm} {  % lines taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680717/250119, can be deleted if LaTeX version is new enough
    \expandafter \NewCommandCopy \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname#2\endcsname
    \expandafter \NewCommandCopy \csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname end#2\endcsname }
\ProvideDocumentCommand \RenewEnvironmentCopy {mm} {
    \expandafter \RenewCommandCopy \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname#2\endcsname
    \expandafter \RenewCommandCopy \csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname end#2\endcsname }

\NewEnvironmentCopy{old-align*}{align*} % backup the old definition

%do nothing: fine -- \RenewDocumentEnvironment{align*}{}{\csname old-align*\endcsname}{\csname endold-align*\endcsname}
%insert something at the start of the environment: fine -- \RenewDocumentEnvironment{align*}{}{\csname old-align*\endcsname xxx}{\csname endold-align*\endcsname}
% this may appear to work well, but will silently use wrong spacing! -- \RenewDocumentEnvironment{align*}{}{\csname old-align*\endcsname}{xxx\csname endold-align*\endcsname}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{align*}{b}{Formula: \begin{old-align*}#1\end{old-align*}}{}
% ======== done
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
123
$a+b=b+a$
\[a-b\ne b-a\]
and
\begin{align*}
  123 &=456 \\
  456 &=123
\end{align*}
\begin{old-align*}
  xxx123 &=456 \\
  456 &=123
\end{old-align*}

\end{document}
```

---

### Alternative solution that is flaky and not recommended

You may think of using `\everymath` to automatically insert the command whenever `$` is used automatically.
Nevertheless, this will break a lot of things that uses math mode under the hood e.g. `\textsuperscript`, `\underline`, `\(...\)`, etc.

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\quark_new:N \qmymathpreserve  % variable name does not conform to expl3 recommendation!
\cs_set:Npn \my_token_if_eq_meaning:nNTF #1 {\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1}  % (remove braces around #1.) (note that this will not work properly when #1 is empty.)
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_token_if_eq_meaning:nNTF {xNTF}
\cs_new:Npn \mymathprocessor #1 $ {
  \my_token_if_eq_meaning:xNTF {\tl_head:n {#1}} \qmymathpreserve {
    \tl_tail:n {#1} $  % preserve the old behavior
  } {
    $  % close the math environment first...
    #1 ~  % then print as text  (put ~ here because space at the start of a line doesn't work)
    $\qmymathpreserve a^2$  % add another math formula for demonstration
  }
}
\everymath{\mymathprocessor}
\ExplSyntaxOff

$this is actually text$

$\qmymathpreserve a^2+b^2$
```

As you can tell, the following code

```
$\qmymathpreserve formula$
```

will render as a "normal" math formula, while the following code

```
$formula$
```

will preprocess the formula with the processor. In this case the processor is expandable.

You can even add additional text outside a math environment, as demonstrated by the example above (but you still an empty math formula).

Note that `\tl_head:n` will return empty if the input is empty, which breaks `\my_token_if_eq_meaning:nNTF`.

For `$$...$$` use `\everydisplay`.

Note: even if the formula is closed immediately, there is still an empty math formula, which is a larger problem in display mode.

Comment: There's also another option of using regex replace on the source code... using either Lua callback, external program or some package I've recently written.

Comment: See also [comments - Remove everything that is in math mode - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89622/remove-everything-that-is-in-math-mode) for a solution that handles more cases (amsmath environment etc.)