# Remove everything that is in math mode

Tags: math-mode, comments

The package comment.sty allows one to typeset

```
\begin{comment}
stuff that will be suppressed from output file
\end{comment}
```

or

```
\begin{myCustomEnv}
stuff that will be suppressed from output file
\end{myCustomEnv}
```

One can even suppress the contents of already defined environments, for instance `{proof}`.

In this spirit, I would like to suppress everything that is in math mode, whatever the way it starts: `$`, `\(`, `$$`, `\begin{displaymath}`, etc.
The output should be as if the contents of everything that is in math mode was not in the source file.

Can this be done?

Comment: A script in `python` or `perl` or `awk` could preprocess the `TeX` source and remove all math. You'd have to be a little careful to detect escaped `$` signs inside math mode.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, but that would change the *input*; it sounds like the OP only wants to change the *output* with the flick of a switch in the preamble

Comment: @cmhughes The script output would go to `nomath.tex` for subsequent compilation, leaving the original input document whole. I'll upvote a wizardly answer that uses just `TeX` in the preamble.

Comment: How do you want to treat text material that appears in a math mode environment?

Comment: @jrouquie Why do you need this ?

Comment: I needed this 7 years ago, I don't need this anymore ;-)

Answer (score 18):

There are a few very different ways to enter and to exit math mode:

1. TeX math shift character, catcode 3, typically `$`
2. LaTeX macros `\(<math>\)` and `\[<math>\]`
3. LaTeX environments `math` and `displaymath`
4. `amsmath` environments
5. Not directly in the source: macros that were defined with the original catcode of `$` cannot be hidden with the described methods.

## 1. TeX math shift

An easy redefintion of `$` (catcode 13, active) solves this.

```
\catcode`$=\active
\makeatletter
\def${%                        % TeX math shift (not anymore)
    \@ifnextchar${\killB}{\killA}%
}
\makeatother
\def\killA#1${\ignorespaces}   % TeX inline math
\def\killB$#1$${\ignorespaces} % TeX display math
```

The macro `\killA` kills inline math (`$<math>$`) with removing any spaces that comes after the last `$`. Without `\ignorespaces`, something like `Text $ f(x) $ text` would be typset as `Text␣␣text`. (This would be disallowed by “The output should be as if the contents of everything that is in math mode was not in the source file.”)

## 2. LaTeX macros `\(<math>\)` and `\[<math>\]`

A TeX re-definition of those macros suffice:

```
\def\(#1\){\ignorespaces} % LaTeX inline math
\def\[#1\]{\ignorespaces} % LaTeX display math
```

Without the white-space problem (see above), the following would work too:

```
\let\[\iffalse
\let\]\fi
\let\(\iffalse
\let\)\fi
```

## 3. LaTeX environments `math` and `displaymath`

The LaTeX environments `math` and `displaymath` use internally `$` and `\[` and `\]`, but the solutions above do not work here (they do more harm instead).

But with the help of the `environ` package we can simply redefine those environments:

```
\def\killMe#1{%                % for math environments
    \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax
    \NewEnviron{#1}{}%
    }

\killMe{displaymath}
\killMe{math}
```

The first two lines of the `\killMe` macro let `\<environment>` and `\end<environment>` to `\relax` so that `\NewEnviron` thinks they aren’t already defined. `\NewEnviron` automatically inserts a `\ignorespaces` in the `\end` part of the environment.

## 4. `amsmath` environments

The `amsmath` package provides a few environments that are “silenced” in the same way with the `\killMe` macro. For example:

```
\killMe{align}
\killMe{align*}
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\def\killMe#1{%                      for math environments
    \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax
    \NewEnviron{#1}{}%
}

    \def\(#1\){\ignorespaces}%        LaTeX inline math
    \def\[#1\]{\ignorespaces}%        LaTeX display math

%   \let\[\iffalse
%   \let\]\fi
%   \let\(\iffalse
%   \let\)\fi

    \catcode`$=\active
    \makeatletter
    \def${%                            TeX math shift
        \@ifnextchar${\killB}{\killA}%
    }%
    \makeatother
    \def\killA#1${\ignorespaces}%     TeX inline math
    \def\killB$#1$${\ignorespaces}%   TeX display math

    \killMe{align}%
    \killMe{align*}%
    \killMe{displaymath}%              displaymath relies on \[ and \] and cannot live
    %                                  without the right definition of \[ and \]
    \killMe{math}%      %              math relies on $ as math shift character and would work
    %                                  although $ is active and redefined


\begin{document}
H%
$ i^n TeX $
e%
\( i^n LaTeX \)
l%
$$ o^ut TeX $$
l%
\[ o^ut LaTeX \]
o
\begin{align}
 f(x) & = x^2
\end{align}
W%
\begin{align*}
 f(x) & = x^2
\end{align*}
o%
\begin{displaymath}
 f(x) = x^2 (displaymath)
\end{displaymath}
r%
\begin{math}
    2^3 (math)
\end{math}
ld!

Text $ f(x) $ text
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: In more complicated documents (e.g., if I use `pgfplots`) I get parameter stack overflow with the `catcode` definition.  I fixed it by changing `\@ifnextchar${\killB}{\killA}%` to simply `\killA` but I assume there is a feature I am missing the original author intended.

Comment: @ZaydH I am pretty sure the point of the `\@ifnextchar` is so that it can handle displaymath that is delimited by `$$ ... $$`.

Answer (score 16):

I would also suggest to go for some external solution that drops the math material from the file and writes a new one. One reason for it is that LaTeX internally uses math in many places which are not obvious at all (and not necessarily real math) the `\LaTeXe` logo for example.

Anyway just for the fun of it here is a solution within LaTeX (totally unsupported and not necessarily complete, perhaps one has to disable much more):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\nomath{%
\font\dummyft@=dummy \relax
   \count@\sixt@@n
   \loop
    \ifnum\count@ >\z@
     \advance\count@\m@ne
     \global\textfont\count@\dummyft@
     \global\scriptfont\count@\dummyft@
     \global\scriptscriptfont\count@\dummyft@
    \repeat
   \global\let\mathversion\@gobble
   \frozen@everymath={}
   \frozen@everydisplay={}
  \let\boldmath\relax
  \let\unboldmath\relax
  \let\mv@normal\@empty
  \let\mv@bold\@empty
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test1: $x$

test2:
\[ a=b\]

test3: \LaTeX{} and $a=b$ but see:  \LaTeXe

\begin{itemize} \item test4 $a=b$ \end{itemize}

test5:  \parbox[c]{1cm}{now what? $a=b$}

\bigskip

\nomath \ldots{} and again \ldots

test1: $x$

test2:
\[ a=b\]

test3: \LaTeX{} and $a=b$ but see:  \LaTeXe

\begin{itemize} \item test4 $a=b$ \end{itemize}

test5:  \parbox[c]{1cm}{now what? $a=b$}
\end{document}
```

But for the sample document it seems to do suppress all math successfully (more or less). Note, that I did really nasty stuff like changing `\frozen@everymath`, which is frozen for a reason, but there you go.

Also note the deficiencies in the resulting output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

(I know that the OP has said in the comments that they no longer need this, but it has found its way back to the front page of the site and I missed it first time round.)

Some time ago I wrote a program for grepping through maths bits in a LaTeX document. It's not perfect, but it goes a bit beyond a simple script.

You can find it (and its limitations) at https://github.com/loopspace/mathgrep

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to create math-free output from a `LaTeX` file by stripping all math code from that file. Don't forget to keep an unchanged copy of the original file!

Edit the `LaTeX` file using the replacement function with `Regular Expressions` in an editor such as `Kate`. The Regular Expression

```
\$((.|\n)(?!\$))*(.|\n)\$
```

finds inline math but compensates for greed, that is, it leaves the words `and` and `implies` untouched in the `LaTeX` code

```
$x=y$ and $y=z$ implies $x=z$.
```

(In other editors, the simpler Regular Expression `\$.+?\$` may work.)

To find other math environments like `equation*`, just replace the first `\$` with `\\begin\{equation\*\}`, and the second and third `\$` with `\\end\{equation\*\}`.

Comment: Hmm, did the OP ask about how to suppress the *output* of all math material, or how to delete all math material from the *input file”?

Comment: Well, no one said that the original input file should be discarded. As soon as there is a math-free output, one forgets the edited input file.

Comment: I think it would be prudent to mention explicitly that if someone were to engage in a destructive edit along the lines suggested in your answer, they should save a copy of the unmodified tex file first. This may be blindingly obvious to many, but I suspect it's not obvious to everybody.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot correctly match nested delimiters such as `\[ ... \]` and `\( ... \)`.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no need to find nested delimiters here.