# Redefining inline math, so it always proceeded by a non breaking space (~)

Tags: line-breaking, inline, tilde

I don't like when inline math is typeset at the beginning of a new line. Is there a way to redefine the dollar sign so that

```
Text text $i$. Text, $i$ text $i$ text.
```

is automatically translated to

```
Text text~$i$. Text,~$i$ text~$i$ text.
```

PS: I don't care about what would happen with inline math at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: you could do something in luatex, probably anything to do this in pdftex would be too fragile and break things.

Comment: it would be much easier if you used the `\(....\)` syntax

Comment: If you know some TeX you can adapt solutions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59980/250119  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89622/250119